# Selecting a single word in ereaders

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ebook, accessibility

ebook readers let user select only a single word in the most PDF documents. However, when I try to select a word in a PDF generated with `pdflatex` (and also with `latex`), the ereader (i.e. sony prs600) selects the entire sentence between the 2 punctuation marks.

The same problem was also discussed in the following two links:

1. [Force pdflatex to create one box per word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168448/force-pdflatex-to-create-one-box-per-word)
2. [Selection in PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620876/selection-in-pdf-files)

These discussions are a little bit old. Therefore, I wanted to learn if recently any new progress has been made about this problem. It seems creating tagged PDFs is a solution for this. Does any recent TeX release have this tagging property?

Furthermore, I noticed that any PDF viewer (e.g. evince, adobe etc.) can select a single word for any document generated with `pdflatex`. Does anyone have any idea about why the ebook readers need tagged PDFs to select a single word in the whole documents?

Comment: Which font encoding are you using? does it behave any differently with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Changing the font encoding does not change the behavior.

Comment: It's said that [ConTeXt can create tagged PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579/5763).

Comment: I know that PDFs must be tagged so that they can be reflowed. However, I am still not convinced that tagging is necessary for selecting the individual words. It seems there are some problems (or rather incompatibilities) with pdflatex's the handling of white space characters. I still believe that there should be some quick and dirty fix for this problem which does not require tagging.

Comment: Looking at this after a time, I suspect it's really about e-readers rather than TeX. As such, I'm closing as off-topic.