# Creating accessible PDFs using Latex?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, accessibility

I am working at a governmental office and we are required to only produce accessible PDF files. In practice that means that generated PDFs have to pass Adobe's accessibility checker or the "PDF Accessibility Checker".

Since I have to write lots of technical documentation, I would really like to use Tex.

Is there any kind of workflow/tutorial on how to create accessible PDFs? The only thing I could find were this presentation (in German: http://www.dante.de/events/Archiv/dante2012/Programm/Vortraege/vortrag-partosch.pdf ) which references a thesis by Babette Schalitz, but these links are offline. Also, the presentation does not include any kind of tutorial on actually create a PDF.

Is this a lost cause?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62207/from-latex-to-pdf-a?rq=1

Comment: Related Question: [LaTeX accessibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/latex-accessibility).

Comment: related [How to create tagged PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579)

Comment: And another one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124291/revisiting-producing-structured-pdfs-from-latex. Do we work for the same government office?

Answer (score 2):

Ross Moore discussed this some time ago - see his [paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95moore.pdf).  I would suggest asking him about the new developments in this area.