# How to get the Image alternative text on PDF document alternative text field through the latex code

Tags: accessibility

I have mentioned my MWE below. I will try to get the alternative text output for each figures. So, i am using the `pdfcomment` package and my TeX code is used to `pdftooltip{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}{Alternative Text}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\section{PDF comment alt text not working on PDF accessbility alternative text}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\pdftooltip{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}{Alternative Text}
\caption{Sample Figure Cation.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The alternative text is working good through mouse over action.

But, the PDF accessibility is not supported because the alternative text to be reflected in the form field text. My requirement is the text to be filled alternative text field.

I check this action through Adobe Professional 11 for the following method

```
Accessibility - Add Tags to Document -> Touch Up Reading Order
```

I have attached the image screenshots for your clear understanding.

**Alternative text field is empty:**
[image: Alternative text field is empty]

**Form text field contains the text:**
[image]

Could, you please advise how to get the text in alternative text field through latex code.

Comment: pdfcomment adds annotation widgets, not alternative text. One can add alternative text for example with the accsupp  package, but it doesn't look as if adobe pro recognize this. I have no idea and can find no reference in which form the alternative text must be added here (apart from tagging the whole document directly).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer accsupp package is not support to fill PDF document alternative text filed through LaTeX engine. If any other package to support this option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can tagged PDFs be created that support Universal Accessibility and reflowing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579/how-can-tagged-pdfs-be-created-that-support-universal-accessibility-and-reflowin)