# What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?

Tags: conversion, unit-of-measure

How can one determine the length of the different units (measured `1ex`, `1em`, `1in`, `1pt`, `1bp`, `1dd`, `1pc`) in `mm`?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Here is a variant on Herbert's answer, using `\dimexpr` instead (inspired from the thread [\ifnum for real numbers](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/7e812e5d6e67fcc5) of comp.text.tex), which allows to do conversions in a purely expandable way. The syntax is `\convertto{mm}{1pt}` to convert `1pt` in `mm`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother
```

The results are not quite the same as with the [printlen](http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen) package, probably due to the fact that `\dimexpr` performs arithmetic slightly differently from TeX. Here's a table showing all the converted lengths (I omitted `sp` to avoid arithmetic overflows):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
%http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/7e812e5d6e67fcc5
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you do not do: `\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1\ #1}` or `\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1\relax\ #1}` to include the unit in the expanded output?

Comment: Of course, the results for ex and em depend on the current font ..

Comment: It's interesting to note that TeX adopts a quasi-decimal metric system.

Comment: @gboffi It's a consequence of the internal representation of dimensions in TeX. Everything is, at its lowest level an integer (portable floating point arithmetic wasn't standardized until 1985, well after TeX82's release, so Knuth had to implement his algorithms *ex nihilo*) and dimensions are represented in integer quantities of sp = 1/65536pt.  This, plus the conversions to decimal end up with mild rounding errors that can show up in anything other than the conversions between sp, pt and pc (and possibly ex/em depending on their values)

Answer (score 60):

### incipit (2017)

The precise rules how TeX inputs a dimension expressed in a certain unit are commented in these two posts:

- [Why pdf file cannot be reproduced?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338297/why-pdf-file-cannot-be-reproduced/338510#338510)
- [What value TeX uses as its minimal unit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231269/what-value-tex-uses-as-its-minimal-unit/231281#231281)

The underlying thing is that internally all dimensions are integer multiples of `sp` unit, hence there must be some conversion done. A few salient points:

- the set of those internal dimensions obtainable from a specification in `cm` has non empty symmetric difference with the set of those dimensions obtainable from a dimension with `in` as unit. This is important if one intents to use `\ifdim` tests. This is a core TeX aspect and will not be changed by any higher level interface for testing dimension equality.
- when expressing a dimension in a given unit `<unit>`, the granularity is `1/65536<unit>` and using more than five digits after the decimal mark can bring only a one-shot change. But it is hard to guess the borderline: nothing can change beyond 17 decimal digits, but the result obtained from 17 decimal digits is not necessarily the same as the one obtained from *rounding* these 17 decimal digits to only 5 decimal digits. As this might surprise people I am providing here some examples you can try out:

  - 0.22222pt (from 2/9) gives 14563sp but 0.22222222222222222pt gives 14564sp. *One must use 0.22223pt to get also 14654sp.*
  - 1.53333pt (from 23/15) gives 100488sp but 1.53333333333333333pt gives 100489sp. *One must use 1.53334pt to get also 100489sp.*

  Yes, using 0.66667pt is the correct choice, but this is a bit an accidental fact as the two examples above show: sometimes one should round in the opposite direction to get what the full specification with 17digits would have given. (unfortunately it appears I have lost a file where I had tested these things but I remember that my testing revealed that counter-intuitive rounding was needed in roughly `10%` of the tested cases, built-up using small fractions like the above ones).

The bigger the dimension unit, the less precise the inner representation. Hence using `in` is a less precise input method than using `cm` which is less precise than using `pt`. For example using `em` typically means you ave a `10sp` granularity, and there is no way to go below that, even with using 17 decimal digits in the expression of the dimension using with `em` unit. Using `pt` ensures the minimal `1sp` granularity.

Regarding the Didot point, there is a more-detailed examination in a section of the [xint](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) manual.

(end of 2017 added contents)

---

Here is another type of table. It gives the exact irreducible conversion factors between units (`em` and `ex` are the special font dependent cases; for them I use `\dimexpr` but this seems not to be a too good idea, it would perhaps be better to get them from the the suitable `\fontdimen` parameters).

After the exact table I also give a table with values rounded to five decimal places.

*Update:* Following a suggestion done in a comment, the tables first. There seems to be something fishy with the `em`: it seems to be exactly `10pt+1sp` and not the more intuitively reasonable `10pt`. I would have guessed it should be exactly `10pt` in that case with the default CM fonts. But I just tested with `\the\fontdimen6\font` and it also gave to my surprise `10.00002pt`, (compiled with pdftex).

*Update:* before turning off the internet for a while, I checked the `em` for bold, slanted and teletype: respectively `11.5pt-4sp`, `10pt+1sp` and `10.5pt-7sp`. Perhaps some font expert could explain what is the mechanism? perhaps an underlying conversion from big points at some stage in the font creation process?

*Update:* I have played a bit with continued fractions, and a good approximation to `1dd` is `107/100pt` which is clear also from the decimal expansion in the second table, and a very good fraction approximation to `1dd` in millimeters is `44/117` (the previous centered convergent is `3/8=0.375` which is already quite good compared to the exact `0.3760650274...` value of `1dd` in `mm`).

[image: Exact conversion table]

[image: Rounded to 5 places]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintfrac} 
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/xint
% This code was compiled with the version 1.06a of the xint
% bundle dated 2013/05/09, which should appear soon on CTAN.
% The current CTAN version 1.06 should be also OK for this.

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hmargin=.5cm]{geometry}

% Conversions to the basic dimension, chosen to be the centimeter
% Base dimension: 1cm
\def\onecm {1}
\def\onemm {1/10}
\def\onein {2.54}
%% \def\onept {\xintMul {1/72.27}{\onein}}
%% simpler:
\def\onept {2.54/72.27}
%% \def\onebp {\xintMul {1/72}{\onein}}
%% simpler:
\def\onebp {2.54/72}
\def\onepc {\xintMul {12}{\onept}}
\def\oneex {\xintMul {\the\numexpr\dimexpr 1ex\relax\relax}{\onesp}}
\def\oneem {\xintMul {\the\numexpr\dimexpr 1em\relax\relax}{\onesp}} 
\def\onedd {\xintMul {1238/1157}{\onept}} 
% 1157 dd = 1238 pt I take this conversion factor from the TeXBook 
% Wikipedia has other conversion factors, but of course here we
% have to do it the TeX way.
\def\onecc {\xintMul {12}{\onedd}}
\def\onesp {\xintMul {1/65536}{\onept}}


% Routines with delimited arguments, the good old TeX way
% (completely expandable)
\makeatletter

% exact conversion to an irreducible fraction:
% example: \convertexactly 126.2772pt\to {bp}
% and `pt' may be a macro expanding to it.
% idem for {bp} which may be a macro expanding to bp
\def\convertexactly #1\to #2%
    {\xintIrr{\convertexactly@ #1\to {#2}}}%

% Variant with rounding at a number of decimal places
% given by first argument.
\def\convertwithrounding #1#2\to #3%
    {\xintRound {#1}{\convertexactly@ #2\to {#3}}}%

% routines doing the job:

\def\convertexactly@ #1\to
{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \convertexactly@a
    \xintReverseOrder {#1}\Z
}%
\def\convertexactly@a #1%
{%
    \ifcat\noexpand #1\relax
       \expandafter \convertexactly@b
    \else
       \expandafter \convertexactly@c
    \fi #1%
}%
\def\convertexactly@b #1#2\Z #3%
{%
    \xintdiv {\xintMul {\xintReverseOrder{#2}}{\csname one#1\endcsname}}
             {\csname one#3\endcsname}%
}%
\def\convertexactly@c #1#2#3\Z #4%
{%
    \xintdiv {\xintMul {\xintReverseOrder{#3}}{\csname one#2#1\endcsname}}
             {\csname one#4\endcsname}%
}%

\makeatother

\def\bigstrut {\vbox to 24pt{}\vbox to 12pt{}}%

\begin{document}

Testing:

72.27pt is exactly \convertexactly 72.27pt\to {bp}bp

1/2.54in is exactly \convertexactly 1/2.54in\to {mm}mm

10pt is exactly (for this font) \convertexactly 10pt\to {ex}ex, 
or approximately \convertwithrounding{20}10pt\to {ex}ex

10pt is exactly (for this font) \convertexactly 10pt\to {em}em, 
or approximately \convertwithrounding{20}10pt\to {em}em

1em is exactly (for this font) \convertexactly
1em\to {pt}pt, or approximately
\convertwithrounding{20}1em\to {pt}pt. 

And indeed
\verb+\the\dimexpr 1em\relax+ gives \the\dimexpr 1em\relax{} and
\verb+\the\fontdimen6\font+ gives \the\fontdimen6\font

1ex is exactly (for this font) \convertexactly 1ex\to {pt}pt, or approximately
\convertwithrounding{20}1ex\to {pt}pt. 

And indeed
\verb+\the\dimexpr 1ex\relax+ gives \the\dimexpr 1ex\relax.

\def\tableentry{$\displaystyle\xintFrac{\convertexactly 1\colunit\to\rowunit}$\bigstrut}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\clearpage

\def\tableentry{\convertwithrounding {5}1\colunit\to\rowunit}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\tableentry}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: testing the conversion macro]

Actually the two *approximations*, given with `20` places after the decimal mark, for `1em` and `1ex`, are exact, the denominators are powers of 2, the complete decimal expansion only has zeros after those shown. I still do not quite understand why `1em` turns out to be `655361sp` and not `655360sp=10pt` in the case of the CM font. This `10pt+1sp` is strange.

Comment: +1, neat! Two suggestions: Use the `parskip` package to get some space between the “sentences”. Put the picture first in your answer so that it’s closer to your remarks; unlike in most other answers, the output seems more important than the code here.

Comment: Sorry. What is the exact range in `pt`?

Comment: @kissmyarmpit sorry for delay. The maximal input for a dimension expressed in pt is ``16383.99999237060546874pt``. Anything bigger creates a dimension too large error. This corresponds to ``1073741823sp`` (``2^30-1``). In fact the minimal spec which gives this maximal allowed value is ``16383.99997711181640625pt``. Anything smaller gives at most ``2^30-2 sp``.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit using five decimal digits, both `16383.99998pt` and `16383.99999pt` give the maximal dimension, but not `16383.99997pt`. And `\the\maxdimen` outputs `16383.99998pt`. But as I said `16383.99999pt` is still acceptable (try  `\the\dimexpr 16383.99999pt\relax`.) but not `16383.999993pt`.

Answer (score 47):

[image]

And TeX's nice arithmetic can be seen .. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\parindent=0pt

\newlength\Length \Length=1cm
\begin{document}

\tabular{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
\mbox{--- 1cm ---}

\uselengthunit{cm}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{bp}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{sp}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{pc}\printlength{\Length}\
& 
\mbox{--- 1em ---}
\Length=1em
\uselengthunit{cm}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{bp}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{sp}\printlength{\Length}\
\uselengthunit{pc}\printlength{\Length}
\endtabular
\end{document}
```

Comment: Heh! I like how the centimeter didn't come out right...

Comment: 1ex is supposed to be the height of 'x', and 1em is supposed to the width of 'm' -- so they should vary with the font and font size. Do they?

Comment: @frabjous: 1em is the width of M and sure they vary

Comment: Thanks, Herbert. That's an important thing to note for the question asked.

Comment: @frabjous: This isn't quite right for fonts with narrow M's, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29

Comment: @Caramdir: It is _never_ correct. It is only _nearly_ the width of a M, see aditional answer.

Answer (score 25):

- An [inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch) is 25.4 mm.
- For TeX, 1 pt is 1/72.27 in, which is 0.351459804 mm.
- For most other software, 1 pt is 1/72 in, which is 0.352777778 mm. Also called Postscript Point, in TeX this is called a big point (bp).
- ex and em are not a fixed length, as they depend on the fontsize. (See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex).)

Edit: Herberts answer shows you how to find the length of 1 ex and 1em in your document.

Comment: You have a small typo here. 1 TeX point is 1/72.27 inch (not 1/72.72 inch). BTW I think it is not widely known that Google's calculator supports both points. Exemplary searches: `1 TeX point - 1/72.27 inch`, `1 PS point - 1/72 inch`, both obviously returning 0.

Comment: @przemoc: Indeed, you're right, thanks. I don't think I'll edit the post though, that'll bring the question to the top of the list again, and the correct value is in the accepted answer anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't care about such small detail as moving your answer to the top, because keeping the mistake is definitely bad. Moreover, Ctrl+F on 1/72.27 returns only my comment, which is pretty bad, because it is formal definition of point in TeX and should be clearly mentioned somewhere, i.e. in the main text of answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @przemoc: That is a good point, I'll fix it.

Comment: I’ve just recherched point sizes and history, because I have found conflicting information about the Teχ point. It is in fact 1/72.27 of the modern (25.4 mm) inch, or 800/803 of the PostScript point (1/72 inch).

Comment: @mirabilos Yes, isn't that what's written in my answer? (Excepting the 800/803 fraction.)

Comment: I was just confirming this by independent research, so people who are looking for the exact answer have more data points, as some answers were confused by what inch to use (1/72 or 1/72.27 of what). Additionally, your mm conversion is inexact (0.3̅5̅1̅4̅5̅9̅8̅0̅ mm for pt(Teχ) and 0.3527̅ mm for pt(PostScript) is exact), which may be confusing. The fun thing is that pt(Teχ) was defined in terms (1/72th) of older inch (and then its printers’ version, not survey), which led to being 1/72.27th of the international standard inch, and pt(PostScript) was defined in terms of standard inch.

Answer (score 20):

The same as Philippe Goutet's, but using the `fp` module of LaTeX3; however the syntax of the `\convertto` command is different:

```
\convertto{1in}{pt}
```

returns `72.26999`, just the number. With `\convertto*{1in}{pt}` we'd get `72.26999pt`, with the unit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertto}{smm}
 {
  \egreg_convertto:nn {#2}{#3}
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{#2}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \egreg_convertto:nn #1 #2
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( \dim_to_decimal:n { #1 } / \dim_to_decimal:n {1#2} , 5 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Both `\convertto` and `\convertto*` can be used in an expandable context.

[image]

The same table but with `siunitx` (with the already built one for comparison). One needs to prepare the body of the table beforehand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,array}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l_egreg_convertto_body_tl

\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq
 {
  pt, mm, cm, ex, em,  bp, dd, pc, in
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_convertto_maketable:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq { \egreg_convertto:nn { 1####1 } { ##1 } }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_convertto_body_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq { & } & \exp_not:n { \textbf{##1} \\ }
     }
   }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq { {\exp_not:N \textbf{1\,##1}} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketable}{}
 {
  \__egreg_convertto_maketable:
  \begin{tabular}{*{\seq_count:N \g_egreg_convertto_units_seq}{S[table-format=2.5]}l}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_convertto_temp_seq { & } \\
  \l_egreg_convertto_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertto}{smm}
 {
  \egreg_convertto:nn {#2}{#3}
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{#2}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \egreg_convertto:nn #1 #2
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( \dim_to_decimal:n { #1 } / \dim_to_decimal:n {1#2} , 5 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\maketable
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\convertto{1\colunit}{\rowunit}}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that TeX's memory you used is more important. For Philippe :777 strings out of 493481
 10679 string characters out of 3140965
 67406 words of memory out of 3000000

 For you  7172 strings out of 493481
 128969 string characters out of 3140965
 174995 words of memory out of 3000000

Comment: @AlainMatthes Loading `expl3` on top of LaTeX2e has a big impact. If I load `xparse` over Philippe's macros I get  7166 strings out of 493481, 128879 string characters out of 3140966, 175547 words of memory out of 3000000. LaTeX3 will surely consume more memory than LaTeX2e, at the advantage of a cleaner approach.

Comment: @AlainMatthes There's a reason that the LaTeX3 approach didn't fly at all when it was first developed (early 1990s). As egreg says, there is a cost to having a more structured approach, but the idea is that you enhance code readability and logic.

Comment: Not sure what is happening. I copied the code for your answer into a MacTeX2016 (updated a few days ago) TeXShop file. The first row and first column are fine, but all other entries are incorrect. For example, Column 2 Row 2 is 8.09555 and Column 2 Row 9 is 205.62699. Did I neglect something?

Comment: @sgmoye Yes, some internals in `expl3` have changed. Updated.

Comment: Is there a way to use S column type from `siunitx` to produce the table with dec-sep aligned values? :)

Comment: @lcnittl Done; the main part of the answer was to define `\convertto`, though.

Comment: @egreg That's awesome! Thanks a lot! I've tried a brute attempt before, but without redefined `\convertto` it did not work :)

Answer (score 8):

My posting just crossed the other ones. Best to view it, in action.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\temp

\def\alength#1#2{
\temp#1
\nointerlineskip \baselineskip=2pt
\vbox{\hbox{\hskip-29pt\texttt{\textcolor{#2}{#1=\the\temp}}}
\hbox{\vtop{\color{#2}\hrule width 130pt\vspace{#1}\hrule width 130pt}}%
\vspace{0.9cm}}
}

\alength{1cm}{blue}
\alength{1pc}{red}
\alength{1mm}{orange}
\alength{1cc}{red}
\alength{1dd}{red}
\alength{100000sp}{purple}
\alength{1in}{black}
\alength{1bp}{brown}
\alength{1em}{black}
\alength{1ex}{black}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is better if you put all in one base line to make a comparison.

Comment: @xport The base is the relationship to points! I tried to give something to visualize the length (with the exception of the sp, which is smaller than the visible wavelength and hence I scaled that  by100K. Unit conversion tables are normally done like this.

Comment: Thanks Yiannis Lazarides, but how to calc result in mm?
1pc=x mm
1pt=x mm
1ex=x mm
1em=x mm

Answer (score 5):

Some more examples with 1em

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\newsavebox\CBox
\newlength\Length \Length=1em
\begin{document}

\sbox\CBox{M}
\the\wd\CBox : \the\Length

\tiny\Length=1em
\sbox\CBox{M}
\the\wd\CBox : \the\Length

\Huge\Length=1em
\sbox\CBox{M}
\the\wd\CBox : \the\Length

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in other answers, the `e-TeX` `\numexpr` and `dimexpr` allow easy comparisons of dimensions, through conversions to integers. In particular applying `\number` to a `\dimexpr` expression returns the internal representation of the dimension in scaled points: there are 65536 scaled points in one pt. Using this we can see some funny effect of the internal truncations done by `TeX`:

[image: big points]

We see that `100bp` are represented in an exact manner internally (exact meaning that the ratio `72.27/72` is exactly verified). The next to last line should read rather `100bp/100pt`, and not `1bp/1pt`, to illustrate that this exact ratio is obtained only for dimensions which are integer multiples of `100bp`. As we can see indeed, it is not possible to represent exactly `10bp` as an integer number of `sp`. We see that truncation, rather than rounding is used. Indeed `10bp` would be more accurately represented by `657818sp` and `1bp` would be more accurately equated to `65782sp`.

The code for producing the above:

```
1bp=\number\dimexpr 1bp\relax sp

10bp=\number\dimexpr 10bp\relax sp

100bp=\number\dimexpr 100bp\relax sp

1000bp=\number\dimexpr 1000bp\relax sp

10000bp=\number\dimexpr 10000bp\relax sp


1pt=\number\dimexpr 1pt\relax sp

10pt=\number\dimexpr 10pt\relax sp

100pt=\number\dimexpr 100pt\relax sp

1000pt=\number\dimexpr 1000pt\relax sp

10000pt=\number\dimexpr 10000pt\relax sp

\bye
```

The last lines were done with `\input xintfrac.sty` (package [xint](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) ) and

```
1bp/1pt=\xintIrr{\number\dimexpr 100bp\relax/\number\dimexpr 100pt\relax }

72.27/72=\xintIrr{72.27/72}

\bye
```

To get the `e-TeX` extensions the executable `etex` (or `pdftex` which is what I actually used) rather than `tex` must be used.

Answer (score 1):

A package [texdimens](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdimens) appears to reply to this question, i.e. to express a dimension originally in a given unit in `mm` units.  From its documentation:

> Utilities and documentation related to TeX dimensional units, usable:
>
> - with Plain TeX: `\input texdimens`
> - with LaTeX: `\usepackage{texdimens}`
>
> [...]
>
> `\texdimenmm{<dim. expr.>}`
>
> Produces a decimal (with up to five decimal places) `D` such that
> `Dmm` represents the dimension exactly if possible. If not possible it
> will either be the closest from below or from above, but it is not
> known in advance which one (and it is not known if the other choice
> would have been closer).
>
> `\texdimenmmdown{<dim. expr.>}`
>
> Produces a decimal (with up to five decimal places) `D` such that
> `Dmm` represents the dimension exactly if possible. If not possible it
> will be largest representable dimension smaller than the original one.
>
> `\texdimenmmup{<dim. expr.>}`
>
> Produces a decimal (with up to five decimal places) `D` such that
> `Dmm` represents the dimension exactly if possible. If not possible it
> will be smallest representable dimension larger than the original one.
>
> If input is `\maxdimen`, then `Dmm` virtually represents
> `\maxdimen+2sp` and will trigger on use "Dimension too large".

The documentation contains ample details which appear complicated such as

> `\texdimenbothcminpt{<dim. expr.>}`
>
> Produces a decimal (with up to five decimal places) `D` such that
> `Dpt` is the largest dimension not exceeding the original one (in
> absolute value) and exactly representable both in the `in` and `cm`
> units.  It thus represents the same dimension as the one determined by
> `\texdimenbothcmin` and `\texdimenbothincm`.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel provides `\dim_to_decimal_in_mm:n` as well as `\dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { ex, em, in, pt, bp, sp, dd, pc, cc, cm }
  { 1 #1 ~ = ~ \dim_to_decimal_in_mm:n { 1 #1 } mm \par }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image: units]

More generally, there is `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {⟨dim expr1⟩} {⟨dim expr2⟩}` which converts `⟨dim expr1⟩` in terms of `⟨dim expr2⟩`. Note the precision here is limited to 5 decimal places so you can get unexpected results like `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{1cm}{1mm}` producing 10.00005.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely satisfied with the macro `convertto` because I have no control over the number of digits after the decimal separator and I always have to use the decimal point as the decimal separator, as is common in the USA. In many other countries, however, the decimal comma is used, which is made possible by the siunitx package. My macro `ConvertTo` has an optional parameter for the number of digits after the decimal separator and uses the  package fp for calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[locale = DE,detect-all]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\ConvertTo[3][2]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #3}{\number\dimexpr 1#2}\relax%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}\SI\res{#2}}

\begin{document}
\newdimen\mylength\mylength=5440pt
\convertto{cm}{\mylength}\ cm, \ConvertTo{cm}{\mylength}, 
\ConvertTo[6]{cm}{\mylength}, \ConvertTo[0]{bp}{\mylength}.
\end{document}
```

Output: 191.19421 cm, 191,19 cm, 191,194 216 cm, 5420 bp.

Remark: If you're a pedantic mathematician like me, you'll notice that the result for cm is only correct up to the third digit after the decimal point. The next macro calculates more precisely, see my answer to [How to print a length accurately and with user-controlled rounding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123278/how-to-print-a-length-accurately-and-with-user-controlled-rounding/609003#609003)

```
\newcommand{\ScaledPointsInPoint}{\number \dimexpr 1pt \relax}
\newcommand*{\FPSizeCm}[2][2]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #2\relax}{\ScaledPointsInPoint}%
\FPdiv\res{\res}{72.27}%
\FPmul\res{2.54}{\res}%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}%
\SI\res{\cm}}
```

This macro is more precise, because TeX obviously converts all lengths internally first into points and then into scaled points. So it is better to first convert back from scaled point to point and then to inch, cm, mm, etc. This is more accurate than converting directly into these units as the macros `convertto` and `ConvertTo` do.

Comment: This just adds needless complexity, though. If you need accuracy, you don't use TeX to calculate as it is inherently inaccurate when calculating dimensions (and, hence, when calculating with non-integers).

Answer (score 0):

Even though knowing the conversion factor to more than e.g. 5 decimal digits is not meaningful (because TeX has rounding error), this is the exact fraction used by TeX.

[image: image from tex.pdf]

See `texdoc tex`. So, for example, 1in = (7227/100)pt.

See also: [Why six \noexpand in a row?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/why-six-noexpand-in-a-row) (I'm not sure what the "additional units" are in etex, but it probably isn't a physical unit)

Comment: [texdimens](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdimens)

Comment: @user691586 This looks like it can answer this question, and it is not covered by an answer here. Maybe you would want to post an answer?

Comment: ok will transfer to an answer