# Problem with unexact font sizes in memoir

Tags: memoir

I have to typeset a thesis and although nobody knows why I have to set it in `12pt` with one and a half line spacing, I have to do it.
The strange thing is that in the resulting PDF file the font looks smaller, and when I measure the font's size in the PDF file I get the result of: 11.96pt.
What could cause that?

Here the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newcommand*{\setasuspacing}[1]{%
\let\AsuSpacing#1
\AsuSpacing}
\setasuspacing{\OnehalfSpacing}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test, nothing else – Don't wast you time reading this! It has to have two lines}
\section{Don't wast you time reading this! It has to have two lines. It has to have two lines}
\Blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\section{Test124}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Test2}
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem has already been treated before; there are 72.27 pt to an inch, while the measure in the PDF file refers to Postscript points (72 to an inch). I wouldn't bother. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/globally-redefining-1-pt-to-1-72-in-postscript-point-and-other-similar-changes

Comment: You might check your print settings; your viewer might be reducing the page size to fit, when it should not need to scale the paper if you used the correct papersize in LaTeX.