# geometry package - paperwidth and paperheight aren't accurate

Tags: geometry, paper-size

recognize this simple example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=612.0pt, paperheight=792.0pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

I compiled it with pdflatex. Additionally I wrote this small Java-Programm (using the iText library):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("example.pdf");
Rectangle psize = reader.getPageSize(1);
System.out.println(psize.getHeight());
System.out.println(psize.getWidth());
```

The result:

```
Height: 789.041
Width: 609.714
```

Why is the paperwidth and paperheight different to the tex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Thx for your info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the unit is different. 1 point for TeX is 1/72.27 in, while many other programs use a PostScript point, which is 1/72 in. This is called a big point (`bp`) in TeX.

See also [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm/)

Comment: I'm using TeX for some years now. I never heard about the unit bp. With bp the program returns the expected geometry. Thanks!

Comment: Besides a huge log file, are there other drawbacks of using pdf figures in "pt" and latex uses "bp"?

Comment: @strauberry I don't really see how this relates to the size of the log file. And I don't see how it is a drawback either, any more than specifying the size of the figures in centimeters or inches is a drawback -- it is a different unit, so you need to make sure to calculate the correct size.