# Weird pdflatex log output

Tags: floats

my pdf generation works like `pdflatex biber pdflatex pdflatex`. In the context of final PDF generation, I checked the log file and stumbled upon several weird entries:

```
<graphics/measurementOverview.pdf, id=2875, 384.43625pt x 196.23312pt>
```

The weird thing about this is the dimension: I checked the text width (using `\the\textwidth`) to be 383.0pt. So I created all my pdf figures on exactly 383.0pt. Besides, I include figures like that:

```
\newcommand\figureFrame[3][ht]{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/#2}
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#2}
    \end{figure}
}
```

As you can see, also there is the text width of 383.0pt used. So why the hell prints the pdflatex run this strange dimension of 384.43625pt? This happens for nearly all my figures... thank you!

Comment: Same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30767, you're using the wrong type of point.

Comment: `384.43625 * 72/72.27=383`; the unit used in the message are what TeX calls `bp`; it would indeed better if the info message used `bp`, but it's generated by the `xpdf` library.