# Convert coordinates from picture to textpos

Tags: graphics

I am trying to convert some code from using the picture environment to textpos for a titlepage but I have run into problems getting the text to align.The coordinates are given in points.

the original text is placed with

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,583.5){\fontsize{20 pt}{22pt}\tyk \OPGAVE}}
```

where the t-coordinate is given form the bottom of a (A4) page presumably with the lower left corner at the coordinates.

And the new text:

```
\begin{textblock}{200}[0,1](50,258.5)
     \noindent\fontsize{20 pt}{22 pt} \tyk \OPGAVE 
\end{textblock}
```

where the y coordinates is given from the top of the page. I calculated the new y coordinates by y_new = 842-583.5=258.5, since the vertical dimension of a A4 page is 842 points.

[image: Picture of the malaligned tex]

The red text is the original.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 297/2.54*72.27 = 845.05, so an A4 page is a bit more than 845pt high. In TeX a point is 1/72.27 inches, whereas a PostScript point (called a big point, `bp`, in TeX) is 1/72 inches .

Comment: See e.g. [geometry package - paperwidth and paperheight aren't accurate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30769) and [Why does a TeX point differ from a Desktop Publishing point?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200934)

Comment: Did my comment solve your problem? I'm not able to reproduce it exactly myself.

Comment: Great. I'll vote to close as duplicate then.