# Curved arrows on top of every node

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I'm a beginner of latex and tikz.  I want to have curved arrows on top of each node as in [tikx example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/).

Following is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]


  \node (n1) at (9,8) {1};
  \node (n2) at (6,7) {2};
  \node (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
  \node (n4) at (6,3) {4};
  \node (n5) at (9,2)  {5};
  \node (n6) at (12,3)  {6};
  \node (n7) at (13,5)  {7};
  \node (n8) at (12,7)  {8};


  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n3/n4,n4/n5,n5/n6,n6/n7,n7/n8,n8/n1,n1/n3,n1/n4,n1/n5,n1/n6,n1/n7,n2/n4,n2/n5,n2/n6,n2/n7,n2/n8,n3/n5,n3/n6,n3/n7,n3/n8,n4/n6,n4/n7,n4/n8,n5/n7,n5/n8,n6/n8}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How to draw curved arrows on top of every node?

Comment: Interesting question. I suggest trying to apply the angle calculating approach from [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/coordinates-a-b-compute-b-a-and-angle-between-x-and-b-a).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]


  \node (n1) at (9,8) {1} edge [in=100,out=80,loop] ();
  \node (n2) at (6,7) {2} edge [in=150,out=130,loop] ();
  \node (n3) at (5,5)  {3} edge [in=190,out=170,loop] ();
  \node (n4) at (6,3) {4} edge [in=240,out=220,loop] ();
  \node (n5) at (9,2)  {5} edge [in=280,out=260,loop] ();
  \node (n6) at (12,3)  {6} edge [in=330,out=310,loop] ();
  \node (n7) at (13,5)  {7} edge [in=10,out=350,loop] ();
  \node (n8) at (12,7)  {8} edge [in=60,out=40,loop] ();


  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n3/n4,n4/n5,n5/n6,n6/n7,n7/n8,n8/n1,n1/n3,n1/n4,n1/n5,n1/n6,n1/n7,n2/n4,n2/n5,n2/n6,n2/n7,n2/n8,n3/n5,n3/n6,n3/n7,n3/n8,n4/n6,n4/n7,n4/n8,n5/n7,n5/n8,n6/n8}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now what if there is another node added? What if there are `n` more nodes added in a similar equidistributed manner?

Comment: @jlv I want to live a simple life ;)

Comment: @Harish Kumar Thanks very much. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage But the arrows are not all on top of the nodes. Many are below them... (I wondered why you wanted them on top but, heck, that's what you said!)

Comment: @cfr obviously gravity points inward :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy with circular placement things get pretty simplified with foreach loops for `n>4` nodes. Then you need to tweak the loop drawing which is also possible but I got a little bored :P

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\def\myn{9}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\myn}{\node[circle,fill=blue!20,inner sep=1pt] (n\x) at ({(\x-1)*360/\myn+90}:2cm) {\x};}
\foreach \x[evaluate={\xi=(\x-1)*360/\myn+90+360/\myn;\xo=\xi-360/(0.5*\myn)}] in {1,...,\myn}{
\foreach \y in {\x,...,\myn}{\ifnum\x=\y\path (n\x)edge [in=\xi,out=\xo,loop] ();\else\draw[-](n\x) -- (n\y);\fi}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For `n=9`

[image]

For `n=40`.... (I really don't know why)

[image]

Comment: My eyes hurt so much! `:)` Thank you sir! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]


  \node (n1) at (9,8) {1};
  \node (n2) at (6,7) {2};
  \node (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
  \node (n4) at (6,3) {4};
  \node (n5) at (9,2)  {5};
  \node (n6) at (12,3)  {6};
  \node (n7) at (13,5)  {7};
  \node (n8) at (12,7)  {8};


  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n3/n4,n4/n5,n5/n6,n6/n7,n7/n8,n8/n1,n1/n3,n1/n4,n1/n5,n1/n6,n1/n7,n2/n4,n2/n5,n2/n6,n2/n7,n2/n8,n3/n5,n3/n6,n3/n7,n3/n8,n4/n6,n4/n7,n4/n8,n5/n7,n5/n8,n6/n8}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);

  \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      \draw [->] (n\i.north west) [out=45, in=135] to (n\i.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: network with curved arrows]