# Angle and distance between two points in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle

Given two `(A)` and `(B)` 2-D points in `tikzpicture` environment, I need to collect both angle of the line `(A)-(B)` with respect to the `vector(1,0)` and the half of its distance in two variables, say `\Aab` and `\Dab` respectively. **SOLVED** (see [Coordinates A, B: compute |B-A| and angle between +x and (B-A)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/coordinates-a-b-compute-b-a-and-angle-between-x-and-b-a?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getLengthAndAngle}[2]{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\global\let\myangle\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x % no need to use a new dimen
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)/28.45274} % to convert from pt 
 to cm
\global\let\mylength\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,4) rectangle (7,-5);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,4);
    \getLengthAndAngle{A}{B}    
    \draw[help lines,gray] (0,-3) grid (5,5);
    \begin{scope}[blue, thick]  
    \draw (A) -- (B)--+(\mylength,0); 
    \draw[rotate around={-\myangle:(A)}] (A)--+(\mylength,0);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (B) circle (\mylength cm);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: look `angle` library.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/coordinates-a-b-compute-b-a-and-angle-between-x-and-b-a?rq=1

Comment: @Zarko If you mean the `angles` library that is as you know for drawing an angle symbol between two lines, the OP wants to calculate an angle and a distance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that at least sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you. As it is it is not clear what you mean by "collect".

Comment: @TorbjørnT., yes i mean `angles`. it seems that i misunderstood the question.

Comment: \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpoint{1cm}{3cm}}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{4cm}}
\pgfmathresult
has the inconvenient that I don't know how calculate the coordinates x and y of the two given points... and \pgfmathresult must rapidly used, or it changes

Comment: and veclen in the pgfmanual is trated as
let   \p1 = ($ (B) - (A) $)   in....
and I am looking for allocate the result for a posterior usage.

Comment: Yes @TorbjørnT.... I didn't found it . Thank you.
and thak you gays, I solved with that help.

Comment: If you move the `}` after `we need a global macro` to a new line, your code compiles. And you are loading calc, so I do not inevitably see a reason for all the gymnastics. You could just do `\drawlet \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)} 
 in [rotate around={-\n1:(A)}] (A)--+(\n2,0);` to have angle and the length in `\n1` and `\n2`, respectively. That is, this line reproduces your result without the need of these macros.

Comment: Hi JOM. Please undelete [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422655/156344). Your question is answered in comments, so it is closed. That is how this site works. No worries, your question is not bad, and it _is_ useful for future visitors. It is just like "closed issues on GitHub". No one is disturbed by closed questions - we are only disturbed by spam questions, and your question is not a spam. Please undelete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative solely based on `calc`, i.e. not using extra macros, and with a little helper that allows you to "export" the length outside the path (and scope).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[globalize/.code n args={2}{\xdef#2{#1}}]
    \clip (0,4) rectangle (7,-5);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,4);
    \draw[help lines,gray] (0,-3) grid (5,5);
    \begin{scope}[blue, thick]  
    \draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={veclen(\y1,\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)}
     in [globalize={\n2}{\mylength}] (A) -- (B)--+(\n2,0)
     [rotate around={-\n1:(A)}] (A)--+(\n2,0);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (B) circle (\mylength);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}. Can we globalize both variables... and no drawing at all?

Comment: @JOM Sure: `\path let \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={veclen(\y1,\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)}
     in [globalize={\n2}{\mylength},globalize={\n1}{\myangle}];`. Just watch out for globalization critics! ;-)