# How to measure the distance of two points?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is this. Is there a way to measure the distance of two points? (The points are drawn with TikZ.)

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: [How can I compute the distance between two coordinates in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/how-can-i-compute-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-tikz)

Comment: @PaulGessler Distance between two coordinates is ambiguous. One point has two coordinates (in math) and coordinate in TikZ is used for notion that is "point" in math.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `veclen` function.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (30:1) coordinate(a) -- (75:3) coordinate(b); 
  \path let \p1=(a), \p2=(b), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in node{\n1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And if you want the length in cm or inches, you can see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15002/9335).

[image]

Comment: How do I store `\n1` for later use like in `\node [minimum width=\n1]{};`? I would rather not use `\newlength` because I'd like to keep the code localized and in pgf. Therefore, I tried inserting `\pgfsetmacrolength` into your last node: `node{\n1\pgfsetmacrolength{\var}{\n1}}`.

Comment: @macmadness86 It is hard to know what is the best thing to do without example. One solution is to define a global macro `\var` using `... in \pgfextra{\xdef\var{\n1}}`. You don't need a node just for saving the macro.