# How to align decimal separator inside a specific table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, best-practices

The table comes from the excellent answer of Philippe Goutet [about this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm/8337#8337) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}      
\usepackage{array,booktabs} % I add booktabs AM
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
%http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/7e812e5d6e67fcc5
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  % 

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}  % Philippe Goutet 
  {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{mm}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{cm}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{ex}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{bp}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{dd}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{pc}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\def\colunit{in}}l<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1\colunit}}
   >{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1mm} &         
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1ex} &   
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1bp} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1pc} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would like to align the decimal separator in each column. I try with `numprint` and `siunitx`. I know the trick `r@{.}l` but here ...  I'm waiting to see ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{D{.}{.}{2.5}<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1#1}}}
% for a comma as decimal separator use the following line
%\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{D{.}{,}{2.5}<{\convertto{\rowunit}{1#1}}}
```

Then the table can be input as

```
\begin{tabular}{Z{pt}Z{mm}Z{cm}Z{ex}Z{em}Z{bp}Z{dd}Z{pc}Z{in}>{\bfseries}l}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1mm} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1ex} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1bp} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1pc} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
\gdef\rowunit{pt} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{mm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{cm} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{ex} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{em} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{bp} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{dd} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{pc} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\gdef\rowunit{in} & & & & & & & & & \rowunit\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

In order to format the table using facilities of `siunitx` one can build it before typesetting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs} % I add booktabs AM
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter
%http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/7e812e5d6e67fcc5
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1\relax\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\arow#1{
  \convertto{#1}{1pt}&
  \convertto{#1}{1mm}&
  \convertto{#1}{1cm}&
  \convertto{#1}{1ex}&
  \convertto{#1}{1em}&
  \convertto{#1}{1bp}&
  \convertto{#1}{1dd}&
  \convertto{#1}{1pc}&
  \convertto{#1}{1in}&
  #1}
\edef\rows{%
  \unexpanded{%
    \begin{tabular}{*{9}{S[table-format=2.5]}>{\bfseries}l}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1pt} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1mm} &         
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1cm} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1ex} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1em} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1bp} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1dd} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1pc} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries 1in} & \\
  }
  \arow{pt}\noexpand\\
  \arow{mm}\noexpand\\
  \arow{cm}\noexpand\\
  \arow{ex}\noexpand\\
  \arow{em}\noexpand\\
  \arow{bp}\noexpand\\
  \arow{dd}\noexpand\\
  \arow{pc}\noexpand\\
  \arow{in}
  \noexpand\end{tabular}
}
\rows
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add to the `S` column specification all other options that are needed.

Comment: I saw some examples with `dcolumn` but I was not able to use it, so thanks !! Is it possible with `numprint` or `siunitx`?

Comment: I get a new problem, how to write numbers with french format.

Comment: @Altermundus With a comma? Just write `d{.}{,}{2.5}` instead of `d{.}{.}{2.5}` in the definition of the `Z` column type.

Comment: No it's more complicated, I need to have a separator each three digits like `1 234,567 89`. With numprint, it's easy because with frenchb and babel it's automatic I need to use \newcolumntype{d}{n{2}{5}} but I have a problem with `{\convertto{\rowunit}{1#1}}

Comment: @Altermundus I don't think it's necessary in this case, but here's a solution

Comment: I agree with your last remark (it's not necessary) but it's  interesting to know how to combine three conditions : alignement of the decimal separator, the use of siunitx to format numbers and in the same time, apply a macro to each cells of a table. It's not really easy ! Now I think I will get a headache to understand this code :)

Comment: @Altermundus It's not so difficult: I prepare the rows *before* typesetting the `tabular`, exploiting the fact that `\convertto` is expandable. So when TeX really sees the table to typeset the numbers are already there and have not to be computed.