# Setting height of \includegraphics{} from current display style

Tags: fonts, graphics, fontsize

I'm thinking about building a new symbol library and I need to test out the command set. I slapped together a quick set of math symbols using a set of commands

```
\newcommand{\example}{\includegraphics[height=\height]{example.jpg}}
```

and a scanner. It works fine for a kludge, but the problem is that I would like the `\height` argument to be set equal to the value `1em` in the current display style (i.e., smaller for subscripts and superscripts, etc.) I can't find any information and don't know if there's a way to do this (it's not exactly what the graphicx package was designed for). Any suggestons?

Answer (score 2):

The height you are looking for is `\fontdimen6\textfont2`: the length of a `\quad` (1em by definition) in the text style of the current symbol font (family 2).  Of course, if you are in scriptstyle or scripscriptstyle you want `\scriptfont` or `\scriptscriptfont`, and you can use a different family (up to 15; I am not sure what their significance is but if you are designing a font perhaps you are).

I should mention that if you use this before the first time a math `$ $` pair is used, the symbol font won't be loaded and you will get a mysterious error about `\nullfont`.

Comment: Is there a different flavor of your answer for vertical heights, i.e., the height of an `x` in the current mathstyle, rather than a horizontal measure like em?  Or will they always be defined as proportional, as would seem to be indicated by this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm/113513#113513?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `\mathchoice` prinitive to set in each of the math sizes:

```
\def\something{\mathchoice
  {\includegraphics[height=\fontdimen6\textfont2]{...}}%
  {\includegraphics[height=\fontdimen6\textfont2]{...}}%
  {\includegraphics[height=\fontdimen6\scriptfont2]{...}}%
  {\includegraphics[height=\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2]{...}}%
}
```

(using `graphicx` package for the graphics inclusion)

or more simply let the AMS take care of you , use `amstext` package and then:

```
 \def\something{\text{\includegraphics[height=1em]{...}}%
```

Comment: Don't you need a `\fontdimen` for those heights?

Comment: @RyanReich yes, will fix, thanks:-)

Comment: I hope amstext does the trick, but if not I'll have \mathchoice on reserve. Thanks very much!