# Why six \noexpand in a row?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

Trying to understand TeX's rules for parsing dimensions, I came up with the following weird behaviour:

```
\dimen0=1\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\empty pt
```

is valid, but

```
\dimen0=1\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\empty pt
```

yields

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   p
<to be read again> 
                   t
<*> ...oexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\empty pt

?
```

What causes the difference?

Comment: I need 7 `\noexpand` to get the error.

Comment: Same here. Either it is a stack/register limitation or maybe it tries to `\noexpand` what is after/in the definition/instance of `\empty` and depending on the version may or may not fail. Adding more `\noexpands` seems to always produce the error which suggests it is a parser limitation.

Comment: It's six with Knuth's TeX, but seven with e-TeX.

Comment: ooohhhhh in T:2011 I get an error with tex but not pdftex

Comment: It is platform-dependent. I would go with @AbstractDissonance that it's due to either a stack or parser limitation. Unlike `\expandafter`, there is a limit to the chain-length of `\noexpand`. Or can `\noexpand` become a frozen `\relax`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa See what I found in my answer below.  It ends up not being a stack limitation (that would have surprised me a bit, since TeX can happily `\expandafter` thousands of tokens.  Another example is that `\toks0\noexpand\noexpand...\noexpand{}` will work fine.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: That was an interesting effort by you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This was tricky to track down.  Notice that we get an error after different numbers of `\noexpand` depending on the unit, which means that TeX does a different number of expansions depending on the unit.  To experiment with this, let's set the active character `~` to be `\noexpand`, then try various assignments, increasing the number of `~` until TeX complains.  Here are the maximum numbers of `~` for the original TeX engine:

```
\let~\noexpand
\dimen0=1~~\dimen1
\dimen0=1~~~em
\dimen0=1~~~~ex
\dimen0=1~~~~~true~pt % (and others)
\dimen0=1~~~~~~pt
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~in
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~pc
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~cm
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~mm
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~bp
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~~dd
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~cc
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~sp
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ % crashes after reading the last ~.
```

Clearly, all units are not created equal.  The key is found in the `tex.web` file: the code TeX uses for scanning a unit is copied below.  Let's comment on the case of

```
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~pt
```

for instance, which leads to an error (with 7 `~`).  TeX reads the number `1`, expands the first `~` which temporarily turns the second `~` to `\relax`, stopping the expansion of `1`: the number is complete.  The:

```
@<Scan units and set |cur_val| to $x\cdot(|cur_val|+f/2^{16})$...@>=
```

This is essentially a "title".

```
if inf then @<Scan for \(f)\.{fil} units; |goto attach_fraction| if found@>;
```

Dimension assignments do not allow infinite glue, so this part is skipped.

```
@<Scan for \(u)units that are internal dimensions;
  |goto attach_sign| with |cur_val| set if found@>;
```

This scans for a unit such as `\dimen...`, expanding our second `~` which turns the next `~` to `\relax` (note that in the first line of our example file the `~` acts on `\dimen` and does nothing, so TeX sees `\dimen`).  Then TeX looks for `em`, then for `ex`, "killing" two more `~`.  We are left with 3.

```
if mu then @<Scan for \(m)\.{mu} units and |goto attach_fraction|@>;
```

Skipped: this is not a muskip assignment

```
if scan_keyword("true") then @<Adjust \(f)for the magnification ratio@>;
@.true@>
```

TeX tries to scan `true` and fails again, leaving us with 2 `~`.

```
if scan_keyword("pt") then goto attach_fraction; {the easy case}
@.pt@>
```

TeX looks for `pt`, expands, but the next `~` turns the last `~` to `\relax`, hiding the `pt` which follows.  Yet another failure.

```
@<Scan for \(a)all other units and adjust |cur_val| and |f| accordingly;
  |goto done| in the case of scaled points@>;
```

The code called there tries various units one by one: `in`, `pc`, `cm`, `mm`, `bp`, `dd`, `cc`, `sp`.  Our last `~` does nothing to the following `p`, and TeX keeps seeing a `p`, trying to match it with the units.  When scanning for `pc`, TeX recognizes the `p`, but is then disappointed by the `t`.  Eventually, TeX gives up.  Note that the error message in this case shows both `p` and `t` as "to be read again".  If you add two more `~`, TeX hasn't reached the `p` yet when trying to parse `pc`, so only the `p` will be "to be read again".

```
attach_fraction: if cur_val>=@'40000 then arith_error:=true
else cur_val:=cur_val*unity+f;
done:
```

Rest of the code, we don't care here.

As a side note: since eTeX scans a few additional units than TeX, the following crashes at 14 `~` with TeX but 18 with eTeX:

```
\let~\noexpand
\dimen0=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~sp
```

Comment: Amazing! Nice job! It was a very intriguing puzzle.