# What unit of measure is pt in the documentclass?

Tags: fontsize, document-classes, class-options

I would like to know what is the meaning of `13pt` in here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{article}
```

My first guess was that it was the size of the characters, but changing the number does not seem to do that.

Comment: You most likely receive a message in your output (`.log`) saying `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [13pt]`

Comment: An option is just a string of characters; the class does nothing with unknown options, and `13pt` is unknown to `article`, which has only `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` for choosing the main font size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`13pt` in `\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{article}` means the font size. But unfortunately article class offers only 10, 11 and 12pt sizes. If you want bigger font you may switch to KOMA class (`scrartcl`) or `extarticle` or `memoir` class. Also you may try the packages --- `scrextend`, `anyfontsize`, `fix-cm` to change the font sizes in other document classes.

For details on these units of font size [please see this question and answers.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm/)

Comment: None of these classes offers 13pt, AFAIK.

Comment: @egreg: true. I didn't mean it. I said only bigger fonts :)

Comment: thanks, and what are the units of the size then? I mean, for example how many millimeters are 10pt?

Comment: @inquisitor: TeX uses the traditional printing points system (Ie not Adobe), where 1 inch (or 25.4mm) is 72.27 points.

Comment: Wikibooks provide a nice [conversion table](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Useful_Measurement_Macros) between different ways of measuring length/size.