# How to change font size globally below 8pt?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

With `\documentclass[a4paper, 6pt]{article}` I still have a fontsize of `8pt`.

How can I reduce the global font size for exemple to write a reference card of something?

Comment: Possible related in these links https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71272/what-unit-of-measure-is-pt-in-the-documentclass, http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html

Comment: I have not written that your question is a duplicate :-). Don't worry. Look at the second link if it can be useful.

Comment: The `article` class options for font sizes are `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` --- `6pt` is not a valid option.

Comment: Yeah but since I am using TrueType fonts I should be able to have smaller fonts

Comment: The options 10pt 11pt 12pt are not sizes that can be adjusted arbitrarily they are names of options that set up section headings list spacing etc as well as the values used for all size commands such as \large you can use \tiny after begin document if you just want the to set a small font size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load package `scrextend` with option `fontsize=6pt`. And you need a font which provides the needed sizes.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=6pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: For me this is a novity. I not known this package scrextend.

Comment: @Sebastiano `scrextend` is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. It provides some KOMA-Script features for usage with other classes. It is not possible (and not necessary) to load this package with a KOMA-Script class.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution through the `fontsize` package. It is based on `scrextend` but it is totally independent from KOMA.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=6pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum     
\end{document}
```

Here is a minimal working example which shows some features of the package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \changefontsize[13.3]{11}
% A smoothly scalable font is required for some features:
%\usepackage{cochineal}

\begin{document}

Main font set to 11 pt on 13.3 pt.

\changefontsize[13]{12.8}

Main font set to 12.8 pt on 13 pt.
 
\printsamples{12.4pt}{10.5pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]