# What is the easiest way to see default "spaces" with respect to "ex" and "em" in the book class?

Tags: spacing

What is the easiest way to see  default "spaces" with respect to "`ex`" and "`em`" in the `book` class? I mean by spaces all horizontal and vertical spaces such as:

1. the space before and after the section headings in the text
2. the space between the captions and the text after it
3. the space between the header and the main text
4. the space between the figures and their caption
5. the space between the footnotes at the bottom of the pages

and so on.

I'm using `xelatex` and TeX Live 2012 on Win7.

Comment: See, for instance, page 132 of `lshort`. In your command line, type `texdoc lshort`

Comment: @hpesoj626 I want the default values, not the customized values of the lshort. Also, I want a complete list.

Comment: @Sisabe `lshort` documents LaTeX2e, which is the version of LaTeX in use. Therefore you find there the default values documented.

Comment: @tohecz I want the values as a list.

Comment: @Sisabe There is no such list of all distances. List all of them you are interested in and we will provide a code to show them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer makes use of Philippe Goutet's `\convertto` macro in [What are the various units (ex, in, pt, etc.) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm).

### Code

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89986/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-see-default-spaces-with-respect-to-ex-and-em-in#89986
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
    {>{\def\colunit{pt}}l
     >{\convertto{pt}{\rowlength}}l
     >{\def\colunit{em}}l<{\convertto{em}{\rowlength}}l
     <{\convertto{ex}{\rowlength}}}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{em}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{ex}}\
\gdef\rowlength{\lineskip} \verb!\lineskip!  & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\baselineskip} \verb!\baselineskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\belowcaptionskip} \verb!\belowcaptionskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\abovedisplayskip} \verb!\abovedisplayskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\belowdisplayskip} \verb!\belowdisplayskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\abovedisplayskip} \verb!\abovedisplayskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\abovedisplayshortskip} \verb!\abovedisplayshortskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\belowdisplayshortskip} \verb!\belowdisplayshortskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\parskip} \verb!\parskip! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\textfloatsep} \verb!\textfloatsep! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\intextsep} \verb!\intextsep! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\floatsep} \verb!\floatsep! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\textheight} \verb!\textheight! & & & \\

\gdef\rowlength{\textwidth} \verb!\textwidth! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\parindent} \verb!\parindent! & & & \\

\gdef\rowlength{\oddsidemargin} \verb!\oddsidemargin! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\evensidemargin} \verb!\evensidemargin! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\headheight} \verb!\headheight! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\marginparsep} \verb!\marginparsep! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\topmargin} \verb!\topmargin! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\headsep} \verb!\headsep! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\marginparwidth} \verb!\marginparwidth! & & & \\
\gdef\rowlength{\marginparpush} \verb!\marginparpush! & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `belowdisplayskip` comes twice instead of `belowdisplayshortskip`.

Answer (score 4):

For the page layout ones, use the package `\usepackage{layout}` and add the command `\layout` into the document body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

The others can be displayed as well, but a list of those you want is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The following code uses `printlen` package and I typically use it to see all the parameters of interest to me. Modify the code for other parameters. Use `uselengthunit` to change the unit you are interested in. Unfortunately, `printlen` doesn't provide lengths in `em` and `ex`. However, you could convert `pt` to `ex` and `em` for a given `fontsize`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{printlen}
%
\begin{document}
{\Large \textsc{Vertical}}\\
  \uselengthunit{pt}
  \verb|\lineskip|~~\the\lineskip\\
  \verb|\baselineskip|~~\the\baselineskip\\
  \verb|\baselinestretch|~~\baselinestretch\\
  \verb|\abovecaptionskip|~~\printlength{\abovecaptionskip}\\
  \verb|\belowcaptionskip|~~\printlength{\belowcaptionskip}\\
  \verb|\abovedisplayskip|~~\printlength{\abovedisplayskip}\\
  \verb|\belowdisplayskip|~~\printlength{\belowdisplayskip}\\
  \verb|\abovedisplayshortskip|~~\printlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}\\
  \verb|\belowdisplayshortskip|~~\printlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}\\
  \verb|\parskip|~~\printlength{\parskip}\\
  \verb|\textfloatsep|~~\printlength{\textfloatsep}\\
  \verb|\intextsep|~~\printlength{\intextsep}\\
  \verb|\floatsep|~~\printlength{\floatsep}\\
  \verb|\textheight|~~\printlength{\textheight}\\
  %\verb|\textwidth|~~\printlength{\textwidth}\\  

\vspace{15pt} {\Large \textsc{Horizontal}}\\
  \verb|\textwidth|~~\printlength{\textwidth}\\
  \verb|\parindent|~~\printlength{\parindent}\\
  %\verb|\textwidth|~~\printlength{\textwidth}\\  

\vspace{15pt} {\Large \textsc{Misc.}}\\
  \verb|\textfraction|~~\textfraction\\
  \verb|\topfraction|~~\topfraction\\
  \verb|\floatpagefraction|~~\floatpagefraction\\
  \verb|\clubpenalty|~~\printlength{\clubpenalty}\\
  \verb|\widowpenalty|~~\printlength{\widowpenalty}\\
  \verb|\displaywidowpenalty|~~\printlength{\displaywidowpenalty}\\
  \verb|\tolerance|~~\printlength{\tolerance}\\
  \verb|\pretolerance|~~\printlength{\pretolerance}\\
  \verb|\emergencystretch|~~\printlength{\emergencystretch}\\
  %\verb|\textwidth|~~\textwidth\\  


\end{document}
```

Comment: 1- Are these values dependent on the font size of the text? 2- Why the `\belowcaptionskip` is zero? It's not zero, it's about 1.5 cm.

Comment: Some values like `baselineskip` etc. are font dependent while others like `textfraction` are not. Space between `caption` and the text below includes among other things `textfloatsep`. So thats why you are seeing space below caption.

Comment: @Sisabe `\belowcaptionskip` _is_ zero. It is `\textfloatsep` and `\floatsep` adding the space.

Comment: @devendra Is there a way to know which one is font dependent and which one is not?

Comment: @Sisabe I do not know a way. My guess is that it comes from experience and reasoning if it makes sense for a given parameter to be dependent on fontsize. For e.g. - it makes sense for `baselineskip`, `belowcaptionskip` to be dependent on the fontsize while `textwidth` should clearly be independent of fontsize.

Comment: @devendra -- while `baselineskip` *is* generally dependent on font size, it is usually not dependent on the x-height (`ex`).  some fonts have relatively large x-height (e.g. lucida), while others (e.g. bembo) have a smaller x-height for the same nominal font size.  on the other hand, `textwidth` should sometimes be dependent on font size; if you've ever tried to read legal "boilerplate" you will understand why -- having very small print in very long lines is a disincentive to read the content.  (experience *does* count.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was tempted to add a correction about `textwidth` (since I am writing my thesis in Bringhurst style document). Thanks for correcting me.