# How to print a length accurately and with user-controlled rounding?

Tags: lengths, units, unit-of-measure

Tried the printlen package, but it seems to not understand what 2.5in means:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{printlen} 
\uselengthunit{in} 
\begin{document} 
\newlength{\advertwidth} 
\setlength{\advertwidth}{2.5in} 
\printlength{\advertwidth} 
\end{document}
```

Typesetting the above yields `2.50049 in` --- is there something better?

NB - in addition to the above, the project in question needs the packages:

```
\usepackage{calc,geometry,xcolor,graphicx,csvsimple}
```

the last in particular, conflicts w/ the answers initially provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{printlen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printer}[3][in]{%
    \FPeval\temp{round(\expandafter\strip@pt\csname#2\endcsname/72.27:#3)}%
    \temp#1}
\makeatother

\newlength\xxx
\setlength{\xxx}{2.5in}    
\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}    

\printer{xxx}{1}

\printer{xxx}{2}

\printer{xxx}{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

The recently uploaded `lengthconvert` package seems to be what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\Convertsetup{unit=in}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\advertwidth}
\setlength{\advertwidth}{2.5in}

\Convert{\advertwidth}

\Convert{72.27pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it clashes with `csvsimple` --- I've emailed the two package authors, so hopefully this will get worked out.

Comment: The macro `\TrimSpaces` in `csvsimple` should have an `@` name, since it's an internal of the package. The clash is with `xparse`, rather than `lengthconvert`

Comment: Prof. Sturm, the author of csvsimple pointed out in a private e-mail that re-ordering the packages would've been sufficient to fix this, but has indicated that he will change the relevant macro name in his next update. Thanks!

Comment: @WillAdams No, it wouldn't be sufficient; loading `csvsimple` after `xparse` would avoid raising the error in this particular case, but would break `xparse`.

Comment: Okay, next version then.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `lengthconvert` package has not been updated to reflect some changes in `expl3`, so it should not be used, unless the fix proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270885/4427 is applied.

Answer (score 11):

The obligatory `expl3` solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \printlengthas } { m m }
  { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {#1} { 1 #2 } #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document} 
\newlength{\advertwidth} 
\setlength{\advertwidth}{2.5in} 
\printlengthas{\advertwidth}{in}
\end{document}
```

(`\dim_to_unit:nn` is currently experimental, but the idea is bound to stay: just a question of the name.)

Note: this currently requires a recent release of `expl3`: `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn` was added to the CTAN version on 2014-07-15.

Comment: I see egreg's solution also uses `expl3` internally: mine is a wrapper around basic TeX arithmetic only (`lenghtconvert` uses the L3 FPU).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't play well w/ `csvsimple` either.

Comment: @WillAdams I think that should be asked as a separate question ('How to use `csvsimple` and `xparse`: clash over `\TrimSpaces`'). A solution is I think easy, as `csvsimple` uses `\TrimSpaces` only internally and only in one place, and this can be fixed using an alternative version from `expl3`. (This is separate from the question posed here, so two separate but linked questions would be better than one with two entirely separate parts.)

Comment: `dim_to_unit` isn't documented :-(

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ah, this might not be in the release version just yet!

Comment: Moot point. Prof. Sturm will be fixing csvsimple.

Comment: @WillAdams The fixed version of `csvsimple` has been uploaded on CTAN (and included in TeX Live)

Answer (score 1):

The function `\printlen[Unit][FracNr]{length}` formats the output of the unit in sans serif, which I don't like, so I use the following four macros to output a length in pt, in, cm and mm. The macros require the packages fp for non-integer division and siunitx.

```
\newcommand{\ScaledPointsInPoint}{\number \dimexpr 1pt \relax}

\newcommand*{\FPSizePt}[2][0]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #2\relax}{\ScaledPointsInPoint}%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}%
\SI\res{pt}}

\newcommand*{\FPSizeIn}[2][2]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #2\relax}{\ScaledPointsInPoint}%
\FPdiv\res{\res}{72.27}%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}%
\SI\res{in}%
}

\newcommand*{\FPSizeCm}[2][2]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #2\relax}{\ScaledPointsInPoint}%
\FPdiv\res{\res}{72.27}%
\FPmul\res{2.54}{\res}%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}%
\SI\res{\cm}}

\newcommand*{\FPSizeMm}[2][2]{%
\FPdiv\res{\number\dimexpr #2\relax}{\ScaledPointsInPoint}%
\FPdiv\res{\res}{72.27}%
\FPmul\res{25.4}{\res}%
\FPeval\res{round(\res:#1)}%
\SI\res{\mm}}
```

Usage:

```
\newlength{\testlen}\setlength{\testlen}{5440 pt}
\FPSizeIn{\testlen}, \FPSizeCm[4]{\testlen}, \FPSizeMm{\testlen}, \FPSizePt{\testlen}.
```

Output in locale=DE: 75,27 in, 191,1941 cm, 1911,94 mm, 5440 pt.