# How to typeout dimensions in mm?

Tags: dimensions, logging

```
\typeout{***This vertical space will be \the\textheight}
```

prints

> ***This vertical space will be 153.64488pt

Is it possible to print `\the\textheight` in mm?

Comment: Related: [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from [How to print a length accurately and with user-controlled rounding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123283/5764), here is a way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123283/5764
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand { \printlengthas } { m m }
  { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {#1} { 1 #2 } #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document} 

\newlength{\advertwidth} 
\setlength{\advertwidth}{2.5in} 
\printlengthas{\advertwidth}{in}
\printlengthas{\advertwidth}{mm}

\typeout{The length \string\advertwidth\space is \printlengthas{\advertwidth}{mm}.}
\end{document}
```

The `.log` includes

```
The length \advertwidth is 63.50034mm.
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be much easier?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\begin{document}
\Convert[unit = mm]{\textheight}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Oh, I see, this is not a `typeout` ...

Comment: `\textheight = 1564.90157mm = 156.490157cm` !!
Possibly there is inconsistency between recent l3 packages
and lengthconvert.sty.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto I didn't even look at what the number said. This is worth a new question, I think.

Comment: New question opened at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270857/converting-lengths-with-lengthconvert-and-l3fp