# Converting lengths with lengthconvert and l3fp

Tags: conversion, lengths, l3fp

The package [`lengthconvert`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lengthconvert) "uses
the modul `l3fp` to convert the length". But its conversions are totally off the charts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\begin{document}
\the\textheight

\Convert[unit = mm]{\textheight}

\Convert[unit = cm]{\textheight}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this due to some problem with the `l3kernel`, or has the `l3kernel` changed some of its internals that `lengthconvert` hasn't been updated to reflect?

Comment: It's a bug in `lengthconvert`, which has not been updated to reflect some changes in `expl3` that now disallow using directly a dimension as an `fp` expression. See a recent discussion in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=24244173#24244173

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether l3fp is changed or not.
The following seems to show right dimensions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__lconv_calc_dim_fixed:n #1
 {
  \fp_eval:n
     {
      round( \dim_to_fp:n { #1 } / (1\l__lconv_unit_tl) , \l__lconv_precision_int)
     }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \__lconv_calc_dim:n \__lconv_calc_dim_fixed:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
\the\textheight

\Convert[unit = mm]{\textheight}

\Convert[unit = cm]{\textheight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\cs_set_eq:NN` instead of `\let`.

Comment: @Henri Menke -- Thanks a lot. I don't know expl3 programming. Please edit.