# Meaning of font size

Tags: fontsize

What is font size in LaTeX?  More precisely, What does LaTeX  mean for 12 point? How space does get a letter in output of LaTeX's file in 12 pt?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

Comment: LaTeX `pt` is the same as Office `pt`. Point!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Your question is rather too vague: What do you want to know exactly? What do you already know about font size and point sizes, within or beyond the LaTeX context? Have you tried to google the question yourself, and what did you find that you don't understand?

Comment: Realy, 12pt for a letter i.e How far?

Comment: @bigli, Look at it?

Comment: @Sigur In fact, that's not usually true. 1pt in TeX is 1/72.27 inches, whereas 1pt in Office is 1/72 inches, which TeX calls `bp` (big point).

Comment: Related questions: [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599) and [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260). Perhaps this question is a duplicate of the first?

Comment: Is it assosiation with the width of letter M?

Comment: A better visual indicator of the "point size" of a font is the height of a round parenthesis, i.e., `(` and `)`. In many font families the height of a parenthesis is very close to the nominal point size.

Comment: @bigli yes, a em space is usually very close to width of a capital M.

Answer (score 4):

These are general typographical conventions. One [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) is defined as 1/72.27 inches. Font sizes are traditionally identified by the width of the widest letter, M (other traditions base it on height), or more precisely by the dimensions of an abstract "em box" in which the font's letters are placed. (Hence, the actual width of M will be different.) An "em" is a font-dependent dimension that is (by definition) exactly equal to the width of the em box, so that in a 12 point font, `1em == 12pt`.

In LaTeX, `12pt` is actually the name of a document class option. Only `12pt`, `11pt`, and `10pt` (the default) are defined as options for the standard LaTeX classes. These define the base font; section heads and footnotes use other, appropriate sizes.

Comment: If width of the letter M to be 12pt, how is it for otherwise? How is it for empty space between two words in 12pt ?

Comment: @bigli - the width of interword space is usually *much less* than that of `M`.

Comment: Interword spaces are flexible, to allow for text to be exactly aligned with both margins. The width of all letters depends on the font, and the distance may be adjusted for each pair of letters ("kerning").

Comment: The width of an M in `cmr10` is `9.167pt`. The width of M in `cmbx10` is `10.9167pt`. Knuth claims the point size of a font is the height of its parentheses. In my experience even this is not always true (except, perhaps, in the fonts Knuth created).