# New warning on Console

Tags: xetex, warnings, dvipdfmx

I've just started getting the following warning (or rather, *two* warnings) on my console:

```
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
```

What *do* they mean?

More precisely, typesetting:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,xparse}
%%Greek letters
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\@dg}{O{0.88}oO{}}
{\str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{n}
        {\IfValueTF{#2}
            {#2{\scalebox{0.88}[0.88]{$#3\delta$}}}
            {\errmessage{Too few arguments}\errhelp{If you specify `n' as the first argument, the second optional argument must be specified, otherwise use a number as the first argument or specify no optional argument.}}
        }{\str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{e}
            {\IfValueTF{#2}
                {#2{\scalebox{0.65}[0.65]{$#3\delta$}}}
                {\scalebox{0.65}[0.65]{$#3\delta$}}
        }{\str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{b}
                {\IfValueTF{#2}
                    {#2{#3\delta}}
                    {{#3\delta}}
         }{\IfValueTF{#2}
                    {#2{\scalebox{#1}[#1]{$#3\delta$}}}
                    {\scalebox{#1}[#1]{$#3\delta$}}
}}}}
\newcommand{\dg}{\@dg}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$$\overbracket[0.01pt]{\underline{E_{ii}^2}}^{E_{ii}}+\overbracket[0.01pt]{E_{ii}E_{kk}}^{\dg[n][][\scriptstyle]_{ik}E_{ik}}-\overbracket[0.01pt]{E_{ii}E_{ik}}^{E_{ik}}-\overbracket[0.01pt]{E_{ii}E_{ki}}^{\dg[n][][\scriptstyle]_{ik}E_{ii}}+\overbracket[0.01pt]{E_{kk}E_{ii}}^{\dg[n][][\scriptstyle]_{ik}E_{ki}}+$$
\end{document}
```

gives:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gunguMWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mhsetup.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)))
(./gunguMWE.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty) [1]
(./gunguMWE.aux)
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: height=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: height=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: height=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: height=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: height=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
** WARNING ** Too thin line: width=655 (0.00995717 bp)
** WARNING ** Please consider using "-d" option.
 )
Output written on gunguMWE.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on gunguMWE.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on gunguMWE.log.
```

Interestingly enough, with `pdfTeX` I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gunguMWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mhsetup.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)))
(./gunguMWE.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty) [1{/usr/lo
cal/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./gunguMWE.aux
) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pf
b></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/l
ocal/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on gunguMWE.pdf (1 page, 46192 bytes).
SyncTeX written on gunguMWE.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on gunguMWE.log.
```

that's to say, the warnings vanish. Since I've given all the console messages, could you tell me also what ll. 2-3 mean? And am I right in guessing the last lines in the `pdfTeX` version, just before `Output written on`, have to do with font definitions? And how are they dealt with with `XeTeX`?

Comment: Minimal example, please.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by specifying a line width of `0.01pt` (which gets "translated" to `0.00995717 bp` in the typesetting run -- for the overbracket lines?

Comment: I want very thin lines. Is there any problem in that? Shouldn't the conversion be `0.01pt = 0.0099626400000099626403...bp` or something like that?

Comment: @MickG: Please show us a device that can display such thin lines (you want lines that are 0,0035mm wide). Anyway: It's just a _warning_.

Comment: @MartinSchröder OK I exaggerated. And I know it's just a _warning_, as the title of the question clearly states. But since `TeX` is trying to tell me something, I'd like to understand its language. The exaggeration is probably due to the fact I don't have a clear idea of what a `pt` is. How many `cm` is a `pt`? And what is the `-d` option? Thx for the answer anyway.

Comment: Regarding units: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning comes from `(x)dvipdfmx`. The code in question is

```c
if (width > height) {
  /* NOTE:
   *  A line width of 0 denotes the thinnest line that can be rendered at
   *  device resolution. See, PDF Reference Manual 4th ed., sec. 4.3.2,
   *  "Details of Graphics State Parameters", p. 185.
   */
  if (height < dev_unit.min_bp_val) {
    WARN("Too thin line: height=%ld (%g bp)", height, width_in_bp);
    WARN("Please consider using \"-d\" option.");
  }
  len += dev_sprint_line(format_buffer+len,
                         height,
                         xpos,
                         ypos + height/2,
                         xpos + width,
                         ypos + height/2);
} else {
  if (width < dev_unit.min_bp_val) {
    WARN("Too thin line: width=%ld (%g bp)", width, width_in_bp);
    WARN("Please consider using \"-d\" option.");
  }
  len += dev_sprint_line(format_buffer+len,
                         width,
                         xpos + width/2,
                         ypos,
                         xpos + width/2,
                         ypos + height);
}
```

from [`pdftex.dev`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipdfm-x/pdfdev.c?view=log).

So you are trying to draw a line that's too thin to be printable. The message also hints at the `-d` option:

```
-d number       Set PDF decimal digits (0-5) [2]
```

So the number is also too small for dvipdfmx to print since it needs more digits than currently configured; `-d 5` might help (I don't know how to set that with xetex).

Comment: How can I find out what the minimum width (`dev_unit.min_bp_val`) is?

Comment: @MickG: It's calculated at runtime in `pdf_init_device`.