# How TeX does its scale factor calculation?

Tags: tex-core, calculations, dimensions

With the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dimen0=1sp \dimen1=0.5\dimen0 \dimen2=0.99999\dimen0
\dimen3=0.999992\dimen0 \dimen4=0.999993\dimen0
\count255=\dimen0 \the\count255 sp ~
\count255=\dimen1 \the\count255 sp ~
\count255=\dimen2 \the\count255 sp ~
\count255=\dimen3 \the\count255 sp ~
\count255=\dimen4 \the\count255 sp ~

\end{document}
```

I got the following result

```
1sp 0sp 0sp 0sp 1sp
```

I cound not understand how TeX does its arithmetic calculation.

Comment: `1sp` is the smallest unit of length in TeX.  Everything smaller than that is defined by rounding and 0.999993 is apparently rounded to 1.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231281/164314) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338510/164314) by @jfbu

Comment: I guess the question is about 0.999993 being rounded to 1. The answer to that question by @egreg is even more relevant. (TeX basically uses fixed-point arithmetic with 16 bits after the point, i.e. it multiplies everything by 65536 and works with integers.) Working it out: for converting `0.999993` into binary, start with `a = 0`, then for each digit `3`, `9`, ... etc, set `a = (a + d * 131072) div 10`.  So: in case of `0.999993`, `a` takes the values 39321,  …, 131071, after which `a = (a + 1) div 2` results in `a = 65536`, i.e. 1. In the case of `0.999992` we end up with a = 131070, so 0.

Comment: Or to put it more simply: in fixed-point arithmetic with 16 bits of precision, the fractional value just below 1.0 (=65536/65536) is 65535/65536 = 0.9999847412109375. And the number 0.999992 is closer to this than to 1 (and is rounded to this), while the number 0.999993 is closer to 1 than to this (and is rounded to 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338510/164314) by @jfbu explains how `TeX` does its algebra.

## For `0.999992` or less

> Step 1. `0.999992*65536 = 65535.475712`, which is then rounded to
> `65535` or less.
>
> Step 2. Conversion: `65535/65536`, which must then be *rounded down*
> to zero!

## For `0.999993` or slightly more

> Step 1. `0.999993*65536 = 65535.541248`, which is then rounded to
> `65536`!!!
>
> Step 2. Conversion: `65536/65536`, which must then be *rounded down*
> to one!