# \the vs. \value: what is the difference

Tags: tex-core, counters

I would like to understand the difference between `\the` and `\value{}`
when using counters in LaTeX.

Comment: Related: [The `\the` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\thecounter` *typesets* the result of the counter, be it in arabic, roman, etc, while `\value{counter}` provides an *integer value* in return. In many, but not all, instances, the difference will go unnoticed.

The rule is, if you are looking for a character, use `\the...`; if you are looking for an integer, use `\value{...}`.

Here's an example where it matters.  By typesetting the page number in roman (via `\pagenumbering{roman}`), the option of `\romannumeral\thepage` is no longer an option, since it would be attempting `\romannumeral i`, whereas `\romannumeral\value{page}` works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
\romannumeral\value{page}

% \romannumeral\thepage will break
\end{document}
```

Here's another example...you cannot typeset `\value`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{Q}
\setcounter{Q}{2}

%\value{Q} will break

\theQ
\end{document}
```

The difference can also affect comparisons, since `\if` compares tokens, not integers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{Q}
\setcounter{Q}{2}

\if\value{Q}2 T\else F\fi is false

\if\theQ2 T\else F\fi is true

\end{document}
```

The above example would show a match, were the `\if`s changed to `\ifnum`s, since `\ifnum` will interpret/convert the character `2` into an integer.  However, even that can get you into trouble for more complex cases.

Here, I can combine `\theQ` with `3` to represent `23`.  The same does not apply for `\value{Q}3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{Q}
\setcounter{Q}{2}

%\ifnum\value{Q}3=23 T\else F\fi will break

\ifnum\theQ3=23 T\else F\fi is true

\end{document}
```

Now this last one is quite unusual.  That of using `\value` to try to provide the numerical part of a length specification.  It works as expected if you merely specify `\value{Q} pt`.  However, if you try `2\value{Q} pt`, it takes the `2` as a multiplier and `\value{Q}` as a length specified in `sp` machine units!  The trailing `pt` becomes an extraneous residual, not even part of the length.

This behavior occurs because, deep down in TeX, lengths are actually stored as integer counts in machine units. [What value TeX uses as its minimal unit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231269/what-value-tex-uses-as-its-minimal-unit)

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\q{\rule{2pt}{10pt}}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{Q}
\setcounter{Q}{2}

\q\hspace{\theQ pt}\q{} skips 2pt

\q\hspace{\value{Q} pt}\q{} skips 2pt

\q\hspace{1\theQ pt}\q{} skips 12pt

\setcounter{Q}{100000}

\q\hspace{2\value{Q} pt}\q{} skips 200000sp before reaching the ``pt''

\q\hspace{200000 sp}\q{} skips 200000sp for comparison
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2925716 `\ifnum <condition> <true code>\else <false code>\fi` is TeX's way to perform integer comparisons, where the condition includes an `=`, a `<` or a `>`.  The particular case given is merely checking whether TeX finds the left side of the equation to equal a value of `23`.  If so it outputs `T`, if not an `F` is output.  In the case of `\value{Q}3`, the test breaks, because `\value{Q}3` cannot be interpreted as a valid integer.

Comment: Yes I've imagined that therefore I've deleted my comment. "by breaks" you mean it doesn't compile am I right?

Comment: @user2925716 yes...compile fails, rather than just yielding a "false" result.

Comment: BTW I've tried this in XeTeX but it hasn't printed "j" as I expected: `\if T j\fi` Why?

Comment: @user2925716 The command `\if T j\fi` will never print anything.  `\if` compares the next two fully expanded tokens.  In this case, it compares if the token `T` is the same as the space token.  If that were true, it prints out a `T`.  No false instruction is given

Comment: OK. SO how do I print j if something is `true`? i.e. what's the correct version of my incorrect toy example ?

Comment: I'm trying to learn basics of LaTeX programming ala TM by my question.

Comment: @user2925716  For example, `\newcommand\tmp{j}\if j\tmp True\else False\fi`.  See TeXbook, page 209, or other introductory references.

Comment: Why the mere declaration of a `\newcommand` `\newcommand\tmp{j}\if j\tmp True\else False\fi` **already** prints `True`?

Comment: @user2925716 My example does two things.  It declares a variable `\tmp` to contain the token `j`.  That is meant to represent some part of your document where something gets set that you later (perhaps much later) want to compare.  The `\if j\tmp` comparison takes the two tokens following the `\if`, namely, `j` and `\tmp` which will expand to `j` by way of substitution, and compares them.  If they match, the true branch is followed, otherwise the false branch is followed.  If the `\newcommand` set `\tmp` to `{i}`, the comparison would result in a false condition.

Answer (score 9):

This is an interesting mathematical question. The number two hundred seventy-five can be represented in different ways:

- 275 in decimal notation with “Western digits”,
- ٢٧٥ in decimal notation with “Arabic digits”,
- CCLXXV in Roman numerals,
- 113 in hexadecimal digits,
- 100010011 in binary digits,

and many others (it's duecentosettantacinque in Italian).

When you define a new counter in LaTeX, with `\newcounter{foo}`, also the command `\thefoo` is defined, which will expand to a representation of the value stored in the counter; the command is initialized to provide the decimal representation of the counter, but one can say

```
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\roman{foo}}
```

and thereupon, calling `\thefoo` when the counter stores the number 275 will produce

> cclxxv

(after macro expansion). The initial definition is essentially equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\thefoo}{\arabic{foo}}
```

A common case is the counter `page`: in the class `book`, the counter's representation uses `\roman` in the front matter and `\arabic` in the main matter and back matter.

However, the number stored in `foo` is indepedent of its representation: in some sense, the counter stores the *abstract* number, something not especially tied to a representation thereof. This abstract value is accessed to by `\value{foo}`.

Let's say you have an application where a counter is bound to contain only the values from 0 to 3 and you want to represent these values with non numerical objects; you can define, for instance,

```latex
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{%
  \ifcase\value{foo}%
     apple% case 0
  \or
     orange% case 1
  \or
     apricot% case 2
  \or
     strawberry% case 3
  \else
     bummer% wrong setting found
  \fi
}
```

The conditional `\ifcase` branches according to the number following it, in this case the abstract value stored in the counter.

You cannot say `\value{foo}` in the document in order to print the value, because the abstract number can only be *represented* in some way and you have to specify which one. Instead, when TeX is *looking* for a number (such as after `\ifcase`), then `\value{foo}` is the right code to use.

The objection “but we could use `\arabic{foo}` instead of `\value{foo}`” is dismissed. You *really* want the abstract number there, not some representation thereof.