# How to make a copy of a counter?

Tags: counters, latex3

My need is quite simple. For example, I have a counter **cnt1**, now I want to create a new counter **cnt2** which actually is the same one as **cbt1** except for their names. That is **cnt2**  is a copy of **cnt1** or just a rename of **cnt1**.

I have tried the following:

```
\newcounter{cnt2}
\setcounter{cnt2}{\value{cnt1}}
```

But it didn’t work as what I expect. I mean it is not the completely copy of **cnt1**. How can I make a copy of counter in LaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a package for that, called `aliascnt`. See [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=850) for a very related discussion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newcounter{cnt1}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{cnt1}{7}%
\newaliascnt{cnt2}{cnt1}%
$\number\value{cnt1}=\number\value{cnt2}$

\addtocounter{cnt1}{5}%
$\number\value{cnt1}=\number\value{cnt2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Nice work!

Comment: +1. Just out of curiosity: Is there an advantage in writing `\number\value{cnt1}` instead of `\arabic{cnt1}`?

Comment: @Mico It is just a habit, I could have used `\arabic` instead, so there is no advantage in this code. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511440/194703) one can find a discussion on this.

Comment: You can do it without the package, but it is ugly!  `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\csname c@cnt2\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@cnt1\endcsname`