# How can I print a length in centimeters?

Tags: dimensions, units

(I am a new to LaTeX.) I'm trying to print a length in centimeters. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newdimen\mylength
\mylength=1in 
\the\mylength
\end{document}
```

And here is the resulting output:

> 72.27 pt

However, I want to show output in centimeters: Example: \the dimen [cm]\mylength. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `\convertto` macro from [Philippe Goutet's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/29873):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newdimen\mylength
\mylength=1in
\convertto{cm}{\the\mylength} cm
\end{document}
```

Output:

> 2.54cm

Comment: Actually i am using VTEX (visual text) but its giving me Undefined control sequence error.

Comment: This one: http://www.micropress-inc.com/texdocs/edmain.htm ?

Comment: I have some confusion from above answer that is why i multiplied 1in with 65536 (#2*65536), what is the reason to used 65536  and why i divide / \number (/\number\dimexpr 1#1),what is the reason to use \number . And why i used 1#1(1#cm)      \dimexpr 1#1. It would be very helpful if you briefly explain me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything is explained here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/7e812e5d6e67fcc5 and here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm/8337#8337

Comment: Can you explain only one thing that is why we used 65536? I need Clear idea about that. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Internally TeX uses scaled points (sp) and 1 pt = 65536 sp.

Comment: I have one confusion that is why we used \number? Need to clear idea about that. Thanks man you are helping me lot.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm you should ask a new question with a MWE if there are any other issues.