# Metric Didot point and Cicero

Tags: unit-of-measure

A while ago I found out that there are two hardly known units available at least in `pdftex`: `nd` and `nc` for a Didot point of 0.375 mm as exactly as TeX can represent it in `sp` and the corresponding cicero of 12 points. From [Q319652](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319652/is-1238pt-1157dd-an-exact-definition-for-the-didot-point-in-tex):

> So 1238/1157 pt/dd or pc/cc is indeed exact and there are actually two units for the “metric Didot point” of 375 µm and its cicero: `nd` and `nc`:
>
> - 1nd = ⌊685/642 pt⌋ = 69925sp ≈ 0.375mm
> - 1nc = ⌊1370/107 pt⌋ = 839105sp ≈ 4.5mm

However, these units are not mentioned in Knuth's TeX Book and tex.web §458. When have they been added and where are they available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pdftex manual `texdoc pdftex` section 7 says

> Two new units of measure were introduced in pdfTEX 1.30.0:

With texlive engines at least, nd is recognised in etex, pdftex, luatex, but not tex, xetex, ptex, uptex, euptex

Comment: Thanks and just for the record: [pdftex 1.30.0 was released 1 August 2005](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2005-August/005913.html).