# How to know the column width of a two column article?

Tags: two-column, width, article, lengths

I'm writing an article with 2 columns. If my document is this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
left=2.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=2.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Is there a way tho know exactly the width of the column (see picture)? I need it for draw in others softwares using this lenght.

[image]

Comment: it is `(\textwidth-\columnsep)/2` but just stick `\showthe\columnwidth` into your document and tex will show the value in the log

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, What is "the log"?

Comment: whenever you run tex on a file `something.tex` all messages are written to a file `something.log` in the same directory. most of the messages (including `\showthe` messages are also shown on the terminal directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Found it!!! The values are in pt units, there's a way to change it to cm?

Comment: type the value into a calculator divide by 72.27 to get inches and then convert to whatever unit you want:-)

Comment: For a conversion table see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/95544

Comment: If you use also `columnsep=1cm` then is (21-2-2-1)/2=8 cm.  You can also test it in the  PDF preview  with `\the\columnwidth`  (I am to lazy to search in the logs)... but  why the hell you need to know if the column is 8.00 cm or 8.03 cm ?  You can(must) always use a  relative length  as `\columnwidth` instead of absolute length as `8cm` in images, tables, etc. Using relative lengths as far you can,  guarantees that  if you change the document layout, everything change accordingly (this does not happen if you manage  lengths in cm).

Comment: @Fran I don't know about OP, but I wanted to find the IEEE template column width so that when I'm making figures on some drawing app I can have an idea of how much width I have available to use. I still use relative lengths, like you suggest, when putting it in a figure environment though. Using the multiple suggestions given here I managed to get the width with `\the\columnwidth` (252.0pt) and turn that into cm with the `lengthconvert` package with `\Convert{\the\columnwidth}` (8.85679 cm).

Answer (score 24):

The column width is stored in the length `\columnwidth`. It's value can be turned into a text representation using `\the\columnwidth`. Either use this inside `\message{...}` to print it to the LaTeX compiler output and log file or directly in the text if you want. The value is in Points (pt) which are 1/72.27 of an inch. (Not that PDF and Postscript have points with 1/72 inches for simplify calculations. These are called "big points" (bp) in TeX.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
left=2.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=2.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{bla}
some text \message{The column width is: \the\columnwidth}
The column width is: \the\columnwidth
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Which gives me: `The column width is: 236.84843pt`