# Using `calc` package to draw a line segment for Ptolemy's Theorem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have quadrilateral ABCD inscribed in a circle. I am to locate a point `P` on the line through `C` and `D` so that `D` is between it and `C` and

`|DP| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|`.

The length of `DP` is drawn too long. What is wrong with the code that I have for locating `P`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[dashed] (195:2.5) arc (195:160:2.5);
\draw (160:2.5) arc (160:5:2.5);
\draw[dashed] (-15:2.5) arc (-15:5:2.5);


%Chord $\overline{AB}$ is drawn.
\path (100:2.5) coordinate (A) (160:2.5) coordinate (B) (5:2.5) coordinate (C) (40:2.5) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D);


%Labels for the endpoints of the chord AB are typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{A}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +({\n1+180}:0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(\n1:0.15)$){\textit{C}};
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(D)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{D}};


%P is a point on the line through C and D so that D is between it and C, and |PD| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|.
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, \p2=($(A)-(D)$), \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)}, \p3=($(B)-(C)$), \n3={veclen(\x3,\y3)} in coordinate (P) at
($(D)!{(-1*\n2*\n3/\n1)*1cm}!(C)$);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (D);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the location of `(D)` you multiply with 1cm which is blowing up. The computations are in pt so you need 1pt.

Comment: It is for the location of `P`.

Comment: Are you saying that I should replace `cm` with `pt`?

Comment: Yes, or just remove it altogether, i.e. `($(D)!{-1*\n2*\n3/\n1}!(C)$)`.  Edit: All the `\nX` are lengths in `pt`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Is the `2.5` in the command `\draw (160:2.5) arc (160:5:2.5)` a measurement in points?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. What is the command if I wanted `P` located on the line through `C` and `D` that is at a distance from `D` equal to `(\n2*\n3)/\n1` times the distance between `C` and `D`?

Comment: For the first, surely if you look at your output you'll see that it obviously isn't in `pt` (1pt is about 0.3mm). In that case it'll be cm. For the second, you need to convert from pt to cm, so divide by 28.45 (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260).

Answer (score 8):

You ask two quite different questions, actually. To position `P` so that `|DP| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|`, you only need to remove `*1cm` from your code, i.e.

```
coordinate (P) at ($(D)!{(-1*\n2*\n3/\n1)}!(C)$)
```

and not

```
coordinate (P) at ($(D)!{(-1*\n2*\n3/\n1)*1cm}!(C)$)
```

The reason is that `\n2*\n3/\n1` is already a length, in `pt`, and as [percusse says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419545/using-calc-package-to-draw-a-line-segment-for-ptolemys-theorem/419691?noredirect=1#comment1049894_419545), for the calculation `pgf` will convert `1cm` to `pt` as well. So you get a length that is 28.45 times too long, as 1cm is about 28.45pt.

To see this you can print out the values in a node like this

```
\path let 
 \p1=($(A)-(B)$),
 \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
 \p2=($(A)-(D)$),
 \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
 \p3=($(B)-(C)$),
 \n3={veclen(\x3,\y3)},
 \n4={-1*\n2*\n3/\n1},
 \n5={1cm},
 \n6={\n4*1cm}
in
 coordinate (P) at ($(D)!\n4!(C)$)
 node [right=5mm] at (C|-A) {%
   $\begin{aligned}
    n_1 &= \n1 \\
    n_2 &= \n2 \\
    n_3 &= \n3 \\
    n_4 &= \n4 \\
    1\,\mathrm{cm} &= \n5 \\
    n_4 \cdot 1\,\mathrm{cm} &= \n6
   \end{aligned}$};
```

(note the `aligned` environment requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

which gives you this:

[image]

## Old answer

In [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419545/using-calc-package-to-draw-a-line-segment-for-ptolemys-theorem/419691?noredirect=1#comment1050183_419545) you asked a different question:

> What is the command if I wanted `P` located on the line through `C` and `D` that is at a distance from `D` equal to `(\n2*\n3)/\n1` times the distance between `C` and `D`?

There are a couple of things to consider. First of all, `veclen` will give you a length in `pt`, because `\xN`/`\yN` will be in `pt`. So because the rest of the diagram uses `cm`, you need to scale the result. I tend to just remember that 1in = 72.27pt = 2.54cm, so multiply by 2.54/72.27, but that corresponds to dividing by about 28.45. (See also [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260).)

Second, `\nN` will regardless return a length in `pt` unless told otherwise, so you need to use the `scalar` function to strip the unit. This is needed because with the `($(a)!X!(b)!$)` syntax, `X` can be either a length or a factor. You want a factor.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[dashed] (195:2.5) arc (195:160:2.5);
\draw (160:2.5) arc (160:5:2.5);
\draw[dashed] (-15:2.5) arc (-15:5:2.5);


%Chord $\overline{AB}$ is drawn.
\path (100:2.5) coordinate (A) (160:2.5) coordinate (B) (5:2.5) coordinate (C) (40:2.5) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D);


%Labels for the endpoints of the chord AB are typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{A}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +({\n1+180}:0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(\n1:0.15)$){\textit{C}};
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(D)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{D}};


%P is a point on the line through C and D so that D is between it and C, and |PD| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|.
\path let
  \p1=($(A)-(B)$),
  \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)*2.54/72.27}, % pt -> cm; 1in = 72.27pt = 2.54cm
  \p2=($(A)-(D)$),
  \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)*2.54/72.27},
  \p3=($(B)-(C)$),
  \n3={veclen(\x3,\y3)*2.54/72.27},
  \n4={-scalar(\n2*\n3/\n1)} % scalar strips the unit, so you get 4.88, not 4.88pt
in
coordinate (P) at  ($(D)!\n4!(C)$);

\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the code.

Comment: You say that the `calc` package give `\n1`, `\n2`, and `\n3` in units of points, and a computation like `(\n2*\n3)/\n1` is in units of points ... but `scalar((\n2*\n3)/\n1)` is in units of centimeters. Will `scalar(veclen(\x3,\y3))` be in units of centimeters?

Comment: You express `\n1`, `\n2`, and `\n3` in units of centimeters. Why did you use "scalar" in the command for `\n4`?

Comment: @user74973 The scaling with `*2.54/72.27` is to get the value right. For example if `A` and `B` was 1cm apart, `veclen(\x1,\y1)` gives you `28.45pt`, but `veclen(\x1,\y1)*2.54/72.27` gives you `1pt`.  Note the `pt` is still there. `scalar` just strips `pt`, so you get a unitless number.

Comment: If the distance between `A` and `B` were 1cm, `veclen(\x1,\y1)*2.54/72.27` would calculate the length of line segment `AB` in units of centimeters. Since the location of point `P` is computed from the ratio `|AD|*|BC|/|AB|`, why do you instruct `TikZ` to calculate the lengths of  these line segments, via `\n1`, `\n2`, and `\n3`, in units of centimeters? Why not just keep them in units of points? (Now, I understand your use of `scalar` in the calculation for `n4`.)

Comment: @user74973 If you try that, you'll see that `|DP|` becomes rather large ... Actually though, I think I was confused by your comment where you say that `P` should be "at a distance from `D` equal to `(\n2*\n3)/\n1` times the distance between `C` and `D`". That is what I have done in my code. But in your question you state that you want `|DP| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|`, which is not the same thing. I guess that comment was wrong, so `scalar` isn't needed, and neither is the scaling by `*2.54/72.27`. Will edit my answer later tonight.

Comment: I see that you have edited your response. I will look at it later.  Thanks.  (I will delete this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the node distance : 
`\coordinate (P) at ($(D)!{(-\AD*\BC/\AB}!(C)$);`

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NodeDist}[3][\MyDist]{%
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
                 {\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
    % no need to use a new dimen
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    % to convert from pt to cm   
    \pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)/28.45274}
    \global\let#1\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro    
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[dashed] (195:2.5) arc (195:160:2.5);
\draw (160:2.5) arc (160:5:2.5);
\draw[dashed] (-15:2.5) arc (-15:5:2.5);


%Chord $\overline{AB}$ is drawn.
\path (100:2.5) coordinate (A) (160:2.5) coordinate (B) (5:2.5) coordinate (C) (40:2.5) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D);


%Labels for the endpoints of the chord AB are typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{A}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +({\n1+180}:0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(\n1:0.15)$){\textit{C}};
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(D)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(D)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.15)$){\textit{D}};


%P is a point on the line through C and D so that D is between it and C, and |PD| = (|AD|*|BC|)/|AB|.
%\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, \p2=($(A)-(D)$), \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)}, \p3=($(B)-(C)$), \n3={veclen(\x3,\y3)} in coordinate (P) at
%($(D)!{(-1*\n2*\n3/\n1)*1cm}!(C)$);

\NodeDist[\AD]{A}{D}
\NodeDist[\BC]{B}{C}
\NodeDist[\AB]{A}{B}

\coordinate (P) at ($(D)!{(-\AD*\BC/\AB}!(C)$);

\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```