# How do I set and get the correct font size?

Tags: fontsize

I am working on a grant application that has to have 11pt font. I am using the following code and the research office is telling me the actual font is 10.9. How can I fix this issue?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=Tex, Scale=1}
\nonfrenchspacing
\fontspec{texgyretermes-regular.otf}[WordSpace = 0.1]
\fontspec{texgyreschola-regular.otf}[PunctuationSpace=0]

\begin{document}


...

\end{document}
```

Many thanks. 
Cheers,
Jason

Comment: This is surprising since `1pt = 0.35146 mm` and therefore `0.1pt = 0.035146 mm`. I am not sure that a difference of three hundredths of a millimetre is detectable. [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/138900)

Comment: @AndréC They are visually indistinguishable, but computers look at data and the PDF file advertises `/F1 10.9091`.

Comment: @egreg Interesting. How did you get this data from the PDF?

Comment: @AndréC I asked `qpdf` to uncompress it.

Comment: @egreg What is qpdf? How do I get the same result as you?

Comment: @AndréC You can also run `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0" <filename>` and then look at the PDF file with a text editor. Font declaration start with `/F<number>`. `qpdf` is an external utility that can postprocess PDF files.

Comment: @egreg It works, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the useless bits and scaling the font

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0084]

\begin{document}

ABC

\end{document}
```

The uncompressed PDF file says

```
stream
 q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm BT /F1 11.0008 Tf 70.735 -68.742 Td[<002400250026>]TJ 159.332 -558.307 Td[<0014>]TJ ET Q
endstream
```

so the font should be recognized as 11 (PostScript) points. The scale factor takes care of the fact that 11pt actually defines a font at 10.95pt and that PostScript has a somewhat larger point: 72 PostScript points equal 72.27 TeX points.

Comment: "PostScript points" (72 per inch) are referred to in TeX lingo as `bp` ("big points").  Selecting a font at `11bp` should be equivalent to this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it is at normalsize but scaling the font definition as here covers all of  \large and \footnotesize etc at one go.