# How to make a section of text have predefined fixed width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, text

#### 1) The latex code I currently have and the corresponding output

```
\def\lineA{Email   \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineB{Phone   \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineC{Address \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineD{Website \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
...
\lineA \\
\lineB \\
\lineC \\
\lineD \\
```

**This is producing the following results**

[image]

#### 2) The latex code I want and the corresponding output

```
\def\lineA{\width{20px}{Email}   \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineB{\width{20px}{Phone}   \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineC{\width{20px}{Address} \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineD{\width{20px}{Website} \ \ \ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
...
\lineA \\
\lineB \\
\lineC \\
\lineD \\
```

**That should hopefully be producing the following results**

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use a regular tabular?

Comment: you could use a tabular or replace `\width{20px}` by `\par\makebox[20px][l]` (and remove the  `\\ ` especially the final one which is in error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for here (instead of `\width`) is `\makebox[<len>][<align>]{<stuff>}`, which sets `<stuff>` inside a box of width `<len>` and a particular `<align>`ment (`l`eft, `r`ight, `c`entred or `s`tretched). The default is `c`entred if you don't specify any `<align>`ment. You can specify `<len>` in `p`i`x`els, but there are other, standard lengths typically used, depending on whether you want something absolute (like `p`oin`t`s) or relative (like `em`s). See [What are the various units (`ex`, `em`, `in`, `pt`, `bp`, `dd`, `pc`) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/5764).

In your particular case, use something like

```
\def\lineA{\makebox[5em][l]{Email}   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineB{\makebox[5em][l]{Phone}   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineC{\makebox[5em][l]{Address} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\lineD{\makebox[5em][l]{Website} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
```

If you want to calculate the maximum width automatically you can consider using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` where you use the same `<tag>` for each element you want to consider.

Comment: I just learned something new! Thanks for the help, partner!

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is a mix of LaTeX and TeX code. I show you pure TeX code:

```
\def\lineA{\leavevmode\hbox to5em{Email\hss}   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par}
\def\lineB{\leavevmode\hbox to5em{Phone\hss}   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par}
\def\lineC{\leavevmode\hbox to5em{Address\hss} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par}
\def\lineD{\leavevmode\hbox to5em{Website\hss} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par}
 
\lineA
\lineB
\lineC
\lineD
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
Email & \texttt{name@example.com} \\
Phone & (888) 555 99 99 99 \\
Address & 99 Some Street, Sometown \\
Website & \texttt{https://name.example.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]