# Without using \hspace{…pt} how to make nice alignment of separate equations?

Tags: spacing, align

[image: I added different values of hspace to manually align them]

My code excluding preamble (don't judge please):

```
\subsection{Inverse Hyperbolic Trigonometric Identities}
\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{45pt}
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelindent=16mm,leftmargin=!]
    \incrvariable\x
    \setcounter{enumi}{\x}
    \item%194
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2-1} \hspace{20pt} &\text{Domain: } [1,\infty) \hspace{26.5pt} &&\text{Range: } [0,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%195
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2+1} \hspace{20pt} &\text{Domain: } (-\infty,\infty) \hspace{10pt} &&\text{Range: } [1,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%196
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \hspace{16.4pt} &\text{Domain: } (-1,1) \hspace{22pt} &&\text{Range: } (-\infty,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%197
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \hspace{15.25pt} &\text{Domain: } (-1,1) \hspace{21.9pt} &&\text{Range: } [1,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%198
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \hspace{16.72pt} &\text{Domain: } (-\infty,\infty) \hspace{9.5pt} &&\text{Range: } (-1,1)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%199
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} \hspace{15.48pt} &\text{Domain: } [1,\infty) \hspace{26.1pt} &&\text{Range: } [0,1)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \end{enumerate}
```

The \hspace{} is the important (and annoying) part.

How can I improve my code without changing "enumerate" and "aligned" or something else that looks almost identical? (Something that keeps track of elapsed pts?)

OR with preamble here: (it's looonnng)

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\newunicodechar{ℤ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newunicodechar{ℝ}{\mathbb{R}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\mathindent{3cm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tocloft} %Change font size of TOC
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Content}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\small}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Odd page number on the right 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\align@preamble{%
   &\hfil
\strut@
\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
\ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
\llap{\set@field}%
\tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
\ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
\rlap{\set@field}
\hfil
\tabskip\alignsep@
}

\titleformat{\section} 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\makebox[45pt][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection} 
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\makebox[45pt][l]{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection} 
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\makebox[45pt][l]{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-1em}

\setlength{\parindent}{45pt}

\title{\Huge{\textbf{Mathematics Directory}}}
\author{\Large{Zhiyuan Liu}}
\date{}

%\newcommand\X{0}
%\renewcommand\X{0} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\newvariable#1{\gdef#1{0}}
\def\addtovariable#1#2{\xdef#1{\number\numexpr#1+#2\relax}}
\def\incrvariable#1{\addtovariable#1{1}}

\newvariable\x

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}
\subsection{Inverse Hyperbolic Trigonometric Identities}
\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{45pt}
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelindent=16mm,leftmargin=!]
    \incrvariable\x
    \setcounter{enumi}{\x}
    \item%194
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2-1} \hspace{20pt} &\text{Domain: } [1,\infty) \hspace{26.5pt} &&\text{Range: } [0,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%195
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2+1} \hspace{20pt} &\text{Domain: } (-\infty,\infty) \hspace{10pt} &&\text{Range: } [1,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%196
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \hspace{16.4pt} &\text{Domain: } (-1,1) \hspace{22pt} &&\text{Range: } (-\infty,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%197
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \hspace{15.25pt} &\text{Domain: } (-1,1) \hspace{21.9pt} &&\text{Range: } [1,\infty)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%198
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \hspace{16.72pt} &\text{Domain: } (-\infty,\infty) \hspace{9.5pt} &&\text{Range: } (-1,1)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \incrvariable\x
    \item%199
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} \hspace{15.48pt} &\text{Domain: } [1,\infty) \hspace{26.1pt} &&\text{Range: } [0,1)
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

OR someone may have already answered it. Tell me the post. Cheers.

Comment: don't simply dump your code with a long preamble in your question. Clean it up and shorten it so that it shows only the relevant part.

Comment: What about to write your equations in (long)table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a set of tabulated data. A simple `tabular` would do. I'd enclose each math expression between separate delimiters `\(...\)`. If you have a large data to present that exceed a page or you simply expect a page break somewhere between lines, you would need `longtable` instead.

The example below is based on `longtable`. Uncomment `\everymath={\displaystyle}` if all math expressions should be in display style. This may require additional vertical spacing via increased `arraystretch` or `extrarowheight`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\section{Long table}
\begingroup
\newcounter{eqno}\setcounter{eqno}{190}
\newcommand\addeqno{\stepcounter{eqno}\theeqno.}
\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
% \everymath={\displaystyle}
%%%
\begin{longtable}[r]{@{}
        r
        >{\(}l<{\)}
        >{Domain: \(}l<{\)}
        >{Range: \(}l<{\)}
    @{}}
    \addeqno & \sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2-1}           & [1,\infty)       & [0,\infty) \\
    \addeqno & \cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2+1}           & (-\infty,\infty) & [1,\infty) \\
    \addeqno & \sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & (-1,1)           & (-\infty,\infty) \\
    \addeqno & \cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & (-1,1)           & [1,\infty) \\
    \addeqno & \tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} & (-\infty,\infty) & (-1,1) \\
    \addeqno & \tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} & [1,\infty)       & [0,1)
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

On the other hand, with `enumerate`, you would have to simulate columns. [`\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{<content>}`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cmbox-_0026-_005cmakebox.html) creates a box of a fixed width, no matter of the content. So if you place three such boxes  horizontally, you achieve the desired effect. The downside is the width for each box has to be set manually and might need readjustment once you have changed the content. The package `eqparbox` provides a convenient macros, such as `\eqmakebox[<label>][<alignment>}{<content>}`. It works exactly as a regular `makebox` but instead of the width, user provides labels. Then, the width is calculated based on the longest content per label.

You can see this solution requires more coding, while the final effect is exactly the same as with `longtable`/`tabular`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[
    align=left,
    widest=a,
    labelindent=10mm,
    leftmargin=!,
    before={\setcounter{enumi}{190}},
]
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2-1}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain:\([1,\infty)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range:\([0,\infty)\)}
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\sqrt{x^2+1}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain: \((-\infty,\infty)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range: \([1,\infty)\)}
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x}) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain: \((-1,1)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range: \((-\infty,\infty)\)}
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain: \((-1,1)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range: \([1,\infty)\)}
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain: \((-\infty,\infty)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range: \((-1,1)\)}
\item
    \eqmakebox[eq][l]{\(\tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x})=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[do][l]{Domain: \([1,\infty)\)}%
    \quad
    \eqmakebox[ra][l]{Range: \([0,1)\)}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does eq, do, ra mean?

Comment: These are labels chosen by me. They just stand for _equation_, _domain_, and _range_--I should have used the full names for more clarity. Labels for this macro are like identifiers and groups texts for which boxes are calculated to tell `\eqmakebox` under which identifier the maximum text should be calculated for. Without it, all text would be considered. See the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox?lang=en).

Comment: If you still have a problem, let me know and I'll edit the answer with an explanation. You may ask another question about it, as well. Just make sure to point out what is confusing and give a code, an example, which demonstrates difference between current and expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering if there are any ways to manually set the length of the invisible "Box/Table" either a Long table or enumerate? Cheers.

Comment: Well, I am guessing you might want to change gaps between "cells". In `enumerate`, substitute lines of `\quad` with `\hspace{<<length>>}%` (keep the `%` at the end); `1em` = `\quad`, which is  `10pt` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/31283). In `longtable`, add `\setlength\tabcolsep{<<length>>}` in code somewhere before `\begin{longtable}`; the default column sep. is `6pt`.

Comment: Oh my goodness it works so perfectly well! Thank you so much for making it easy. Now I can use it in different sections/subsections and it will look pretty!

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two ways to accomplish your typesetting objective: with an `alignat*` environment, and with a `longtable` environment.

First, the `alignat*`-based approach. Observe: not a single `\hspace` statement anywhere in sight.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\increment}{\refstepcounter{mycount}\themycount.}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4} % just for this example
\stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{Inverse hyperbolic trigonometric identities}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
&&&&& \text{Domain} && \text{Range} \\[\jot] % "header line"
\increment &\qquad&
\sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x}) &= \sqrt{x^2-1} &\qquad&
[1,\infty) && [0,\infty) \\
\increment &&
\cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x}) &= \sqrt{x^2+1} &&
(-\infty,\infty) &\qquad&
[1,\infty) \\ \increment &&
\sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x}) &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &&
(-1,1) && (-\infty,\infty) \\[\jot] % "\jot" inserts a bit more vertical whitespace
\increment &&
\cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x}) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &&
(-1,1) && [1,\infty) \\[\jot]
\increment &&
\tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x}) &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} &&
(-\infty,\infty) && (-1,1) \\[\jot]
\increment &&
\tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x}) &= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} &&
[1,\infty) && [0,1)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

---

Second, the `longtable`-based approach. Observe: Still no `\hspace` directive anywhere in sight. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\increment}{\refstepcounter{mycount}\arabic{mycount}.}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\refstepcounter{mycount}\arabic{mycount}.}l}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4}   % just for this example
\stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{Inverse hyperbolic trigonometric identities}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\addtolength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} Z LLLL @{}}

%% header
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{} &&& \textup{Domain} & \textup{Range} \\[1ex]
\endhead

%% body of table
& \sinh(\cosh^{-1}{x}) & \sqrt{x^2-1} &
  [1,\infty) & [0,\infty) \\
& \cosh(\sinh^{-1}{x}) & \sqrt{x^2+1} &
  (-\infty,\infty) & [1,\infty) \\ 
& \sinh(\tanh^{-1}{x}) & \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &
  (-1,1) & (-\infty,\infty) \\ \addlinespace
& \cosh(\tanh^{-1}{x}) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & 
  (-1,1) & [1,\infty) \\ \addlinespace
& \tanh(\sinh^{-1}{x}) & \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} &
  (-\infty,\infty) & (-1,1) \\ \addlinespace
& \tanh(\cosh^{-1}{x}) & \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} &
  [1,\infty) & [0,1) \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. This is a lot clearer arrangement without unnecessary clutter with repeated words.