# How to have pdfLaTeX output PDF/X-3:2002 format pdfs?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I'm using Blurb to publish a manuscript, and they require PDF/X-3:2002 format pdfs.  How do I get pdfLaTeX to output pdfs that match that specification? I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: It's always good to add hyperlinks to things you are mentioning and are not known by everyone: I assume you are talking about http://www.blurb.com/?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://redskiesatnight.com/books/pod/latex-templates-for-pod-publishing-with-blurb-com/

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't have much to do with the specifics of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x)

Comment: @tkerwin: From what I can make out, PDF/X-3 is a superset of PDF/X-1, with the key enhancement being to do with colour. So an obvious question is 'Does your manuscript use colour?'.

Comment: Yep, full color images.

Comment: @Torbjorn: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment and posted the same thing. :-|

Comment: @Andrey: No worries, I could have posted it as an answer myself.

Comment: Thank you, this blog helped me solve this problem. I've written a small blog post with a more detailed explanation about the book setup using LaTeX and the memoir class, using as a reference the template cited in this thread. [Creating A Compliant PDF for Blurb Book with TeX](http://goo.gl/hMdrm)

Comment: Thanks @EnricoM.Crisostomo, this has gotten me the closest to producing a verified PDF/X-3 output. The only issue I had to fix was deleting the `/Trapped` line, which was causing problems in Adobe's preflight check. Without this line, I get no preflight errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Googling for *[latex blurb](http://google.com/search?q=latex+blurb)* reveals [a template](http://redskiesatnight.com/books/pod/latex-templates-for-pod-publishing-with-blurb-com/) that apparently does some hackery to generate a conforming PDF/X-3:2002 document.

There is also the [`pdfx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx) package that could be useful.

Comment: That template worked, but I had to use xetex to pass `-output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 3"`, along with copying the special section from the example .tex file.  At first it seemed like xetex had problems with my fonts, but they look good now.  A separate problem is that I have PDF 1.4 images included in my document, but those are charts from R.

Comment: @tkerwin: Hmm, but the template also has a pdfTeX part.

Comment: pdflatex didn't recognize the `-output-driver` command, although there may be another way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with [blurb.com](http://blurb.com)'s PDF/X-3:2002 requirement, and their unhelpful automatic checking that doesn't tell you much about why your file is failing the preflight tests...

Eventually I learnt what I needed to do from the [createspace](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/) package and [this blog post](http://redskiesatnight.com/books/pod/latex-templates-for-pod-publishing-with-blurb-com/).

This minimal example below went through the tests of blurb.com all right. I compiled with `lualatex`. If you want to use `pdflatex`, you'll have to set the font without `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

%% On the front page, blurb.com displays rounded values of the page sizes. For example, it would say that pocket size is 5x8 in. However, during the upload process it will display accurate values

%% blurb.com pocket size:
%% 5.125 x 8.25 in
%% 369 x 594 pts

%% Use inches! Using pt somehow produces a pdf that blurb.com recognizes as different size.
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=5.125in,
paperheight=8.25in,
inner=15mm
}

%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248911/831
\makeatletter
\edef\pwpt{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.996264009963\paperwidth\relax} %paper width in PS points
\edef\phpt{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.996264009963\paperheight\relax} %paper height in PS points
\makeatother

%% microtype, for better justification, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}
\microtypesetup{
% babel=true,
final
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% PDF/X-3:2002 info
%% Replace the title, author, etc. information accordingly to your book.
%% The \pageattr values have to be in pt, compare with the page size settings above.

\pdfobjcompresslevel=0%
\pdfminorversion=3%
\pdfinfo{
  /Title (My Book Title)
  /Author (Mr Author)
  /Subject (biography)
  /Keywords (humans)
  /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-3:2002)
}%
\pdfcatalog{
  /PageMode /UseNone
  /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Info (none)
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S /GTS_PDFX
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (Blurb.com)
    /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
  >> ]
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum[1-150]

% an extra page to make it an even number
\newpage\mbox{}

\edef\mypdfpageattr{
/MediaBox [0 0 \pwpt\space\phpt]^^J
/BleedBox [0.00000 0.00000 \pwpt\space\phpt]^^J
/CropBox [0 0 \pwpt\space\phpt]^^J
/TrimBox [0.00000 0.00000 \pwpt\space\phpt]
}
\expandafter\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\mypdfpageattr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good gracious, this is horrible. Especially the need to specify the various page boxes manually baffles me. Shouldn't that be done by whatever package does the page setup anyway? Given that this answer is two years old, has the situation maybe changed for the better?

Comment: @Christian if you don't want to set the boxes manually you can use [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248911/9335).

Comment: @Nyiti you don't need `\stockwidth` and `\stockheight`. And you should put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when you use `\strip@pt`.

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X) on pdf/X standards says that `PDF/X-3:2002` is based on pdf version 1.3. That should mean that a version 1.3 (or earlier) pdf will be acceptable. Put this in your preamble.

```
\pdfminorversion=3
```

Failing that, Adobe Acrobat Distiller has an option to create files that conform to `PDF/X-3:2002`. The Preview program that you will find on any Mac has an option to save as 'Generic PDFX-3' which might help. There is some more discussion of this issue [here](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/PDF-Compatibility-td4840431.html).

Comment: Most distros already have PDF 1.4 or 1.5 by default. 1.3 doesn't support images with transparency, afair.

Comment: I tried uploading a PDF 1.3 and Blurb didn't accept it.  I believe there are other things required for the file to be PDF/X-3:2002

Comment: It says "based on version 1.3", but this doesn't mean that simply using v1.3 is enough. Probably the PDF must support some v1.3 features so using an earlier version might *not* be OK, while using a higher version might be.

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted a link to a new package "xcomply" on this web site (search for it). It might work for you. One of the choices offered is PDF/X-3:2002.