# Can PDFLaTeX produce PDF/A?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, archiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x)

I wonder if `pdflatex` can produce a standard PDF/A-1 or PDF/A-2 for archival purposes. That would be quite useful.

---

Of course by that I mean fully standard compliant PDF/A; embedded fonts, metadata... the whole deal.

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`pdfx` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx).

Comment: But how?! THis answer do not show how...

Comment: You can simply `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}` for a PDF/A document or `\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}` for a PDF/X document.

The full documentation of pdfx package is available [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfx/pdfx.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can (although I don't know, how far the support goes at the moment). Check out the following website: [Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex)