# XeTeX seems to break headers in Tufte-handout

Tags: xetex, header-footer, tufte

I get the following messed-up running headers on pages 2 and following when using Tufte-Handout class with `fontspec` (and therefore XeTeX). The headers repeat the Title and then add a black box.

[image: Header error]

A lot of errors are thrown up, starting with:

```
Latex Error: ./MinimalExample.tex:13 Argument of \MakeTextLowercase has an extra }.
Runaway argument?
```

A minimal document producing this error follows. Thanks for any advice.

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Helvetica}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Problem Document Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for info: the errors do not occur using LuaLaTeX. For use with LuaLaTeX, replace all `mapping=tex-text` with `Ligatures=TeX`.

Comment: Good, thanks @PaulGessler: That's a good workaround. I notice that the running headers are now lowercased versions of the title, and not small-caps.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. I was looking into why, but had to catch a bus. I'll look into it later this evening if no one else gets to it first. :-)

Comment: I have the same problem with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, with a smaller document : `\documentclass{tufte-handout} \usepackage{lipsum} \title{Lorem Ipsum} \begin{document} \maketitle \lipsum[1-5] \end{document}`

Comment: ... and @egreg ’s solution worked for me ! Thanks !

Comment: I’ve just checked that the same bug occurs with plain LaTeX, but @egreg's fix doesn’t, because of `\addfontfeature`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `tufte-common.def` it is said that in case XeLaTeX is used, its features for letter spacing will be used, but the authors forgot to do it, so the `soul` fallback mechanism is used, which miserably fails.

Fix the definition:

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ifxetex
  \newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\fi


\title{Problem Document Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\allcaps{Abcdef}\\
\smallcaps{Abcdef}\\
\textsc{Abcdef}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Check the values against compilation with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

[image]

You can use `\ifluatex` (from the `ifluatex` package) in case you want to use LuaLaTeX. If you want code that works for both engines, see [Combining \ifxetex and \ifluatex with the logical OR operation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/combining-ifxetex-and-ifluatex-with-the-logical-or-operation)

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg! It solves the problem to include your  {\ifxetex ... \fi} code in the preamble. I take it this reflects a bug in {tufte-common.def}. I can submit the report, unless a more savvy user can add the code or something.

Comment: Thank you, it seems this helped me as well. What's the status?  And, strangely, why did this issue hit my document a few months ago?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I don't think it has been fixed.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. In my previous comment, I actually wanted to say: _...why did this issue did NOT hit my document a few months ago?_ Otherwise, the question is non-sense.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I never use these `tufte` classes, so I can't say much about them.

Comment: I hit the same problem with lualatex, and your fix worked. I suggest replacing the `\ifxetex` by `\ifx\ifxetex\ifluatex\else` to [test for both](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140164/1913), together with `\usepackage[ifluatex,ifxetex]`

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans I added a reference to the relevant question. That trick is funny, but I can't recommend using it. However, users can choose among several possibilities.

Comment: @egreg posted an workable solution six years ago. What can be done to encourage the authors to fix this bug?

Comment: @mk9y The last update to the `tufte` bundle is dated 2015/06/21 v3.5.2