# Problems compiling Tufte title page in XeLaTex

Tags: titles, tufte

I'm not sure why, but I can compile a simple Tufte-style title page using pdfLaTex and Texworks, but the same file chokes in XeLaTex under Texshop.

Where is the error?

First, this MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in}

\title{This is a Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Fall 2014}


\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{loggentry}{2009-Oct-31}{Snow}
\lipsum[1]
\end{loggentry}

\end{document}
```

This MWE does not:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,right=4.cm,bottom=3.cm}

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}
\date{}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{1.5cm}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{2014}

\begin{loggentry}{2014-Dec-31}{Party}

Party
\end{loggentry}
\end{document}
```

I get an error that says,
     "Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra }.
    
    \par
    1.19 \maketitle

I can't find the difference, other than XeLaTex and Texshop. Should these make that much of a difference?

Comment: I'm not clear whether you see a difference with MWE 1 versus MWE 2 or whether you see a difference with both MWE 1 and MWE 2 depending on editor and engine. Either way, try to eliminate the possibilities. Try pdfLaTeX in TeXShop and XeLaTeX in TeXWorks, for example. [The editor should not make a difference; the engine may well do.] And if you can reproduce with a single MWE, use that one for your question and remove the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bug in the `tufte` suite. The minimal example

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

also fails when compiled with `latex`, because with `latex` and `xelatex` there's no possibility of using `microtype` for letterspacing, so `tufte-common.def` resorts to using `soul` features. However, `\MakeTextUppercase` fails with this method.

For XeLaTeX a workaround can be found in my answer to [XeTeX seems to break headers in Tufte-handout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200722/xetex-seems-to-break-headers-in-tufte-handout)

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll have to define font substitutes for the text fonts; the choice

```
\ifxetex
  \newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\fi
```

should produce a quite similar output. The method for choosing the font may be different on your machines, it mostly depends on the installation; so mileage may vary. (Please, ask in comments if the proposed code doesn't work for you.)

Answer (score 2):

Both MWE 1 and MWE 2 compile with pdfLaTeX. Neither MWE 1 nor MWE 2 compiles with XeLaTeX. This is at the command line - the editor is irrelevant.

The following MWE demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The issue apparently has to do with `\MakeTextUppercase` which is triggering an error with `\maketitle` for XeLaTeX but not pdfLaTeX.

Just to clarify, `\MakeTextUppercase` is provided by `textcase`. However, I cannot reproduce the error with `textcase` alone so it has something to do with `tufte`'s usage of it.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is described [here](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/issues/64). The proposed workaround is to add these to the preamble, after fontspec has been loaded:

```
  % Set up the spacing using fontspec features
  \renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}#1}}
  \renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}#1}}
```