# How to prevent font substitution?

Tags: xetex, tufte, ebgaramond

Im trying to make tufte-book to use EB Garamond. It does, but sadly, i have quite a few overfull boxes because many packages/styles use bold fonts.

An MWE for the complaint would be this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,nofonts,nols]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{EB Garamond}
  % some more renewals, as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202189/9293
  % \renewcommand{\bfseries}[1]{\swshape}

\fi

\begin{document}
\part{Whine and cheese}
\end{document}
```

The above mwe compiles with the warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/EBGaramond(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/EBGaramond(0)/m/n' instead on input line 32.

[1] [2] (index.aux)stdin -> index.pdf
[1][2]
4341 bytes written


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

If i use my full document, its getting worse, because quite a few line breaks are at the wrong places (i suspect the font substitution to be the culprit).

I already tried to renew the `\bfseries` command, as i suspect it to be responsible to be used in the `book.sty`, but if i do, the text for the part changes (first few chars are omitted, and "Part" is dropped, too), probably because redefining `\bfseries` does more than setting font weight :/

Therefore i ask you: 
a) How to redefine the acutal font parameterization only for `\part`, and
b) How to redefine all bold for all usage of ebgaramond? (Because EB Garamond does not support `bx`)

or in general: How to fix such an problem?

Comment: EB Garamond has no bold font. End of game.

Comment: hmm. why that? (ebgaramond.sty defines a BoldFont. Why is that one not used?) Or to put it differently: Who does misbehave? ebgaramond.sty? xetex? or book.sty? Or me?

Comment: `ebgaramond.sty` defines a bold font, but if you look closely, it's the medium size one. You get the warning because you're overriding the action of the package by declaring `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`; remove the declaration and the warning will disappear.

Comment: thanks. and once again, TeX leaves me puzzled... So basically thats an answer, right? Mind posting it below?

Comment: And I don't think the overfull boxes have anything to do with boldface missing.

Comment: uhm, acutally, removing the setmainfont worked, mdframed now does proper linebreaks in the theorems...

Comment: Your preamble could be reduced to `\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}`. However, I'd recommend setting it up to use the `T1` encoding when compiled with pdfLaTeX (or LaTeX).

Comment: You might consider using `garamondx` instead: it has a bold weight.

Comment: @Bernard That would not work well with `ebgaramond-maths`, however. Also, it is a controversial choice.

Comment: about minization. I did it for the MWE, but tbh, my choice reg. ifxetex is less likely to change than my choice of font. Therefore, and because i keep together semantic units in the preamble, such base stuff is included explicitly. But, i think its a matter of taste... and garamondx, too...

Comment: @cfr: I did not think of using them with ebgaramond-math, but replacing them if bold fonts are necessary. Why is it a controversial choice? I never really used it.

Comment: @Bernard I don't know much about the history, but I believe that bold fonts did not exist at the time EB Garamond was designed. It is a historic typeface, in other words, and it is a kind of mish-mash to make a bold version. A bit like putting a Turner into a plastic frame or something. egreg has strong feelings on the matter, I believe. I'm inclined to the same view, but less evangelically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ebgaramond` package contains the code

```
  \setmainfont
      [ Numbers = {\ebgaramond@figurealign,\ebgaramond@figurestyle},
        UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
        ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
        BoldFont    = *-Regular ,
        BoldItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
      ]
      {EBGaramond12}
```

which is executed when the typesetting engine is XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. The two macros for the `Numbers` option are set with package options (or applying the default values).

If you look closely, the `BoldFont` option declares the same font for `UprightFont` and the same for `BoldItalicFont` and `ItalicFont`. The reason is simple: EB Garamond features no boldface font so the package instructs `fontspec` to use medium weight fonts for it.

Analogously, the `.fd` file for the fonts with `pdflatex` has

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/m/n }{}
```

and other similar (**s**ilent) **sub**stitutions whose purpose is avoiding warning messages like the one you report.

Why do you get it nonetheless? Because of the declaration

```
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
```

that you have after loading the package, which overrides the previous one. Since the font doesn't have boldface to begin with, when `fontspec` is building the font family data, it doesn't find it, so it doesn't define it and when requested for boldface, LaTeX issues the standard warning for a (nonsilent) substitution.

Remove the declaration.

---

Avoid also `xlxtra`: at present it just loads some packages:

- `ifxetex`
- `fontspec`
- `realscripts`
- `metalogo`

Just load `fontspec` instead. The `realscripts` package may or may not work with the fonts you declare: it's better to experiment whether it does good or not. If you don't need to typeset the XeLaTeX or other similar logos, you don't need `metalogo`. If you do, load it explicitly.

Comment: It isn't necessary to load `ifxetex` or `fontspec` either since `ebgaramond` will load them if XeLaTeX is used (or LuaLaTeX). Nor, in fact, is it necessary to load `ebgaramond` since `ebgaramond-maths` will load it. So `\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}` would be sufficient.

Comment: @cfr This is contingent to the particular packages and might go wrong if different ones are loaded.

Comment: So is the advice to remove `\setmainfont`. That may not be at all desirable if the standard font support package is not Xe/Lua aware.

Comment: @cfr So many variations are possible. But, as a general rule, I like to see the essential packages I need.

Answer (score 1):

The following code sample works (for me) with `TeXLive`, with document classes that include `article`, `tufte-book`, and `memoir`, as processed by `pdflatex`, `tex + dvi`, and `xetex`.

The output should look something like this:

[image]

From source code like this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%  \documentclass{article} % also works
%  \documentclass{memoir}  % also works

\RequirePackage{lmodern}   % supports \ttfamily\bfseries
\RequirePackage{garamondx} % supports \rmfamily\bfseries
\edef\EBfamilydefaultbf{\familydefault}
\edef\EBrmdefaultbf{\rmdefault}
\RequirePackage[oldstyle,proportional,scaled=1.05]{ebgaramond} 
\edef\EBfamilydefault{\familydefault}
\edef\EBrmdefault{\rmdefault}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter%
  \newcommand{\iffont}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@family}{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
  \newcommand{\ifseries}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@series}{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatletter

\let\oldbfseries\bfseries
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\iffont{\EBrmdefault}%
  {\fontfamily{\EBrmdefaultbf}\selectfont\oldbfseries}%
  {\oldbfseries}%
}
%  
\let\oldmdseries\mdseries
\renewcommand{\mdseries}{\iffont{\EBrmdefaultbf}%
  {\fontfamily{\EBrmdefault}\selectfont\oldmdseries}%
  {\oldmdseries}%
}
%  
\let\oldrmfamily\rmfamily
\renewcommand{\rmfamily}{\ifseries{b}%
  {\fontfamily{\EBrmdefaultbf}\selectfont}%
  {\oldrmfamily}%
}

\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% the following is necessary solely to undo some 'garamondx' patches
\edef\rmdefault{\EBrmdefault}\normalsize\mdseries\upshape\rmfamily%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\centering    
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lit}[1]{\ttfamily\textbackslash{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{upshape} & \rmfamily\mdseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{itshape} & \rmfamily\mdseries\itshape Quantum\\
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{scshape} & \rmfamily\mdseries\scshape Quantum\\[1ex]
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{upshape} & \rmfamily\bfseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{itshape} & \rmfamily\bfseries\itshape Quantum\\
\lit{rmfamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{scshape} & \rmfamily\bfseries\scshape Quantum\\[1ex]
\lit{ttfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{upshape} & \ttfamily\mdseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{ttfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{itshape} & \ttfamily\mdseries\itshape Quantum\\
\lit{ttfamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{scshape} & \ttfamily\mdseries\scshape Quantum\\[1ex]
\lit{ttfamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{upshape} & \ttfamily\bfseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{ttfamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{itshape} & \ttfamily\bfseries\itshape Quantum\\[1ex]
\lit{sffamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{upshape} & \sffamily\mdseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{sffamily}\lit{mdseries}\lit{itshape} & \sffamily\mdseries\itshape Quantum\\[1ex]
\lit{sffamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{upshape} & \sffamily\bfseries\upshape Quantum\\
\lit{sffamily}\lit{bfseries}\lit{itshape} & \sffamily\bfseries\itshape Quantum\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Caveat: I am no sort of LaTeX guru.

Comment: `\bfseries` etc. are declared as robust commands which include checks for maths mode. Aside from typographic considerations, this is probably going to have rather strange side-effects.

Comment: I guess it still checks, maybe, but ....