# Tufte Compile Error with LaTeX

Tags: tufte

I want to use `LaTeX` to compile a Tufte-style book. The build process fails even in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The error message from the commmand line is:
`! Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra }.` This has been pointed out in a previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202142/problems-compiling-tufte-title-page-in-xelatex) (which is also the source of the MWE), but a solution is only provided for `XeLaTeX`. I want to use `latex` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DVI mode (`latex` and `xelatex`), `tufte` loads `soul`, which is, as usual, delicate:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,textcase}
\begin{document}
\so{\MakeTextUppercase{boom!}}
\end{document}
```

You can “register” the command to `\soul` so that it knows how to handle it:

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\ifdefined\soulregister
  \soulregister\MakeTextUppercase{1}%
  \soulregister\MakeTextLowercase{1}%
\fi

\title{this is a title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```