# Is it possible to apply the \vfill command only to even pages?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tufte, fullwidth, clearpage

I'm looking for a solution to apply a fullwidth environment for backmatter (glossary, indexes and TOC) in a Tufte-book documentclass. For this, I try to use the command \vfill to center the text on the page (due to the existence of marginpages in this documentclass.

When I only use the Fullwidth command as in the MWE as follow, I obtain the result as shown in the figure 1.

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Stylus phantasticus}
{
    name=Stylus phantasticus,
    description={Propre aux instruments, est la plus libre, et la moins contrainte des méthodes de 
    composition. Il n'est soumis à rien, ni aux mots, ni aux sujets harmoniques ; elle a été créée 
    pour montrer son habileté, et pour révéler les règles secrètes de l'harmonie, l'ingéniosité des 
    conclusions harmoniques, et l'assemblage fugué. Il est divisé en ces formes qu'on appelle 
    fantaisie, ricercar, toccata, sonate (Athanasius Kircher\index{Kircher, Athanasius}, 
   \textit{Musurgia universalis}, 1650)}
}
\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\printglossaries
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Figure 1:
[image]

When I add the command \vfill as in the MWE below, it is possible to center the text on the even page but modify the page layout on the odd page, as shown in the figure 2.

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Stylus phantasticus}
{
    name=Stylus phantasticus,
    description={Propre aux instruments, est la plus libre, et la moins contrainte des méthodes de 
    composition. Il n'est soumis à rien, ni aux mots, ni aux sujets harmoniques ; elle a été créée 
    pour montrer son habileté, et pour révéler les règles secrètes de l'harmonie, l'ingéniosité des 
    conclusions harmoniques, et l'assemblage fugué. Il est divisé en ces formes qu'on appelle 
    fantaisie, ricercar, toccata, sonate (Athanasius Kircher\index{Kircher, Athanasius}, 
   \textit{Musurgia universalis}, 1650)}
}
\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}
\begin{document}

\clearpage
~\vfill
\begin{fullwidth}
\printglossaries
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Figure 2:
[image]

Is it possible to apply the \vfill command only on even pages?

Please also note the insertion of an unwanted header on the previous page related to the use of the \clearpage command. If there is also the possibility of removing it, I am interested!

This is the entire preambule of my book which is very long (I use XeLateX):

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter] 
{tufte-book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\ifx\ifxetex\ifluatex\else
  \newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1] 
  {\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
  \fi

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize{7}{8}}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize{8}{10}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny{7}{8}}
\renewcommand\small{\@setfontsize\small{10}{12}}
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{14}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{10.95}{15}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12}{16}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{14.4}{18}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{20.74}{30}}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge{24}{36}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{geometry,afterpage}

\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{papersize={17.0cm,24.0cm}}


\geometry{left={1.7cm},right={1.8cm},top={1.5cm},bottom={2.2cm},marginparsep= 
{0.5cm},marginparwidth={3.68cm},includemp,includehead}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}

\newcommand{\plainsubtitle}{}%     plain-text-only subtitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\@subtitle{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}% use provided plain-text title
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}%
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing
    {\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle: \plainsubtitle{}}}}
}

\title{This is the title of my book} 
\subtitle{This is the subtitle of my book: music}

\author{Me}  

\publisher{Various \'{e}ditions}  

%%
% Some shortcuts for Tufte's book titles.  The lowercase commands will
% produce the initials of the book title in italics.  The all-caps commands
% will print out the full title of the book in italics.
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative 
Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}

\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\newfontfamily\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]  
\newcommand\directFermata{{\emmentaler{}\symbol{"E132}}}

% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}%.................. Language setup
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}

% For nicely typeset tabular material
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%
% For graphics / images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the formatting of verbatim
% environments.  We use a slightly smaller font.
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

%%
% Prints argument within hanging parentheses (i.e., parentheses that take
% up no horizontal space).  Useful in tabular environments.
\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}}

% Reset the sidenote number each chapter
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \oldchapter
}

%%
% Prints an asterisk that takes up no horizontal space.
% Useful in tabular environments.
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}

%%
% Prints a trailing space in a smart way.
\usepackage{xspace}

% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
  \ifcase\month\or janvier\or f\'{e}vrier\or mars\or avril\or mai\or juin\or
  juillet\or ao\^{u}t\or septembre\or octobre\or novembre\or
  d\'{e}cembre\fi\space\number\year
}


% Prints an epigraph and speaker in sans serif, all-caps type.
\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  %\sffamily\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}

% Inserts a blank page
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage{units}

% Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of 10/12x26 pc.
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}}

% Macros for typesetting the documentation
\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}% prints in red
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}}% hair space
\newcommand{\hquad}{\hskip0.5em\relax}% half quad space
\newcommand{\TODO}{\textcolor{red}{\bf TODO!}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace}
\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern- 
0.1em\LaTeX}
 \newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}}
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}}% a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1
\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}
\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{%
  \hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}
    }%
    {% add the command and package to the index
       \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} 
(\texttt{#1} 
package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}
    }%
}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{%
  \texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}
    }%
     {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} 
(\texttt{#1} 
package)}% command name
  \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}
    }%
}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1] 
{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
\newenvironment{docspec} 
{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces} 
{\end{quotation}}% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} 
environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 
environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} 
package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class 
option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% document class option name
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 
class 
option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2] 
{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}
\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file 
hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%Module pour dessiner des figures (draw figures)
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

% Début Module pour insérer les ornements des parties
\makeatletter
\def\H@old@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {%
     \begin{fullwidth}%
     \centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 10\p@
       \psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}\par
       \vskip 10\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
     \end{fullwidth}%
    }%
    \@endpart}

\makeatother
% Fin Module pour insérer les ornements des parties

%backmatter

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite} 
{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}

\addbibresource{sample-handout.bib}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Stylus phantasticus}
{
    name=Stylus phantasticus,
    description={\kant[11]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Exordium}
{
    name=Exordium,
    description={\kant[12]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Exorde}
{
    name=Exorde,
    description={\kant[13]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narratio}
{
    name=Narratio,
    description={\kant[14]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narration}
{
    name=Narration,
    description={\kant[15]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Propositio}
{
    name=Propositio,
    description={\kant[16]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Climax}
{
    name=Climax,
description={\kant[17]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmatio}
{
    name=Confirmatio,
    description={\kant[18]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmation}
{
    name=Confirmation,
    description={\kant[19]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confutatio}
{
    name=Confutatio,
description={\kant[20]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Gradatio}
{
    name=Gradatio,
description={\kant[21]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Péroraison}
{
    name=Péroraison,
description={\kant[22]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Peroratio}
{
    name=Peroratio,
    description={\kant[23]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Pathos}
{
    name=Pathos,
    description={\kant[24]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Tirata}
{
    name=Tirata,
    description={\kant[25]}
}

\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

% Generates the index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{adjmulticol,tikz}
\makeindex[name=piece,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]
\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2]


\newcommand{\full}[1]{\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth- 
\marginparsep\relax}
#1
\end{adjmulticols}}


\begin{document}
\frenchspacing


% Front matter
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{fullwidth}%
    \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vspace{3pc}%
  \fontsize{23}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  \cleardoublepage
\end{titlepage}

% r.1 blank page
\blankpage

\Mainmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{Title of the first Part}
\chapter{Kant}  
\kant[1-7]

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   A \gls{Stylus phantasticus}.    
        \item   A \gls{Exorde}.     
        \item   A \gls{Exordium}.
        \item   A \gls{Narratio}.
        \item   A \gls{Peroratio}.
        \item   A \gls{Propositio}.
        \item   A \gls{Tirata}.
    \end{enumerate}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{Title of the second Part}
\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check 
odd page, 
toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle 
enlargement=evenpage]
\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources 
bibliographiques]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title= Sources internet]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{fullwidth}
\printglossaries
\end{fullwidth}

\begin{fullwidth}
\printindex
\printindex[piece]
\tableofcontents
\end{fullwidth}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: To tell the true I am unable to compile your new MWE, It works in your system ? Copy and paste the code you posted, back and try it. Meanwhile try the new code I put in my answer. I did not know that you were using xelatex!

Comment: There were some errors indeed, which are corrected. I am using XelateX to insert special characters into tikz (see: \ newcommand \ directFermata {{\ emmentaler {} \ symbol {"E132}}})

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: The page number of the last entry of the glossary is not longer an issue using the last version of the environment `fullwidth` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587185/16101. Please see the figures include in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out the margins of the `fullwidth` environment are wrong when using even pages.

**UPDATE**

This update takes into account the main changes introduced by your new MWE:

(1) xelatex,

(2) the new geometry of the page.

I collected from your MWE the relevant parts for the subject at hand: the glossary design. I also left some harmless packages.

The class already loads and configures several packages: `fontspec`, `bidi`, `fancyhdr`, `multicol`, `hyperref`, `geometry` and others.
Do not reload them. In particular, use `natbib` for bibliography, NOT `biblatex`.

To fit the glossary using the full page,  use the macro `\full` that is able enlarges a single column using the outer margin, using `adjmulticol` (the macro was already in your MWE).

[image: ww]

[image: toc]

[image: ztoc]

Please try this code and in you system. Then add packages and new commands as needed, testing that they do not produce errors or are incompatible with the previous configuration.

```
% !TeX TS-program =xelatex

\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter] {tufte-book}

\geometry{papersize={17.0cm,24.0cm}}

\geometry{left={1.7cm},right={1.8cm},top={1.5cm},bottom={2.2cm},marginparsep={0.5cm},marginparwidth={3.68cm},includemp,includehead}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}%  colored hyperlinks (e.g., for onscreen viewing)

%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202142/problems-compiling-tufte-title-page-in-xelatex  ******
% Set up the spacing using fontspec features
\renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}#1}}
\renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}#1}}
%% ******************************************
    %% *************************************
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjmulticol} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed
\newlength{\rmarginW}
\setlength{\rmarginW}{\marginparwidth +\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{%
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-\rmarginW}
        #1
\end{adjmulticols}}
%% **

    
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}


% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
  \ifcase\month\or janvier\or f\'{e}vrier\or mars\or avril\or mai\or juin\or
  juillet\or ao\^{u}t\or septembre\or octobre\or novembre\or
  d\'{e}cembre\fi\space\number\year
}
    
% Inserts a blank page
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}



\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Stylus phantasticus}
{   name={Stylus phantasticus}, %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< name ={xxxx},
    description={\kant[11]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Exordium}
{    name={Exordium},
    description={\kant[12]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Exorde}
{    name={Exorde},
    description={\kant[13]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narratio}
{    name={Narratio},
    description={\kant[14]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narration}
{    name={Narration},
    description={\kant[15]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Propositio}
{    name={Propositio},
    description={\kant[16]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Climax}
{    name={Climax},
description={\kant[17]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmatio}
{    name={Confirmatio},
    description={\kant[18]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmation}
{    name={Confirmation},
    description={\kant[19]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confutatio}
{    name={Confutatio},
description={\kant[20]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Gradatio}
{    name={Gradatio},
description={\kant[21]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Péroraison}
{    name={Péroraison},
description={\kant[22]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Peroratio}
{    name={Peroratio},
    description={\kant[23]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Pathos}
{    name={Pathos},
    description={\kant[24]}
}

\newglossaryentry{Tirata}
{    name={Tirata},
    description={\kant[25]}
}

\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\title{This is the title of my book} 
\newcommand{\subtitle}{This is the subtitle of my book: music}
\author{Me}  
\publisher{Various \'{e}ditions}  

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
    
% Front matter
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{fullwidth}%
        \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
        \vspace{11.5pc}%
        \fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
        \vspace{3pc}%
        \fontsize{23}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\subtitle}}%
        \vfill%
        \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
    \cleardoublepage
\end{titlepage}
    
\mainmatter %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\part{Title of the first Part}

\chapter{Kant I. Pure logic depends on the transcendental unity of apperception}  
1. \kant[1-7]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item   A \gls{Stylus phantasticus}.    
    \item   A \gls{Exorde}.     
    \item   A \gls{Exordium}.
    \item   A \gls{Narratio}.
    \item   A \gls{Peroratio}.
    \item   A \gls{Propositio}.
    \item   A \gls{Pathos}.
    \item   A \gls{Tirata}.
\end{enumerate}

\part{Title of the second Part}
    \chapter{Kant II. The Transcendental Deduction would thereby be made to contradict our faculties}  
8. \kant[8-10]  

\backmatter

\full{\printglossaries}

\tableofcontents    

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that the proposed changes are not the solution to my problem. It changes the even page of the glossary (the text is less to the right), but the insertion of the code changes the layout of the book a lot. I have the impression that all the odd pages in "Fullwidth" mode are shifted to the right...

Comment: I will make an update with a full book. I used your MWE as it is. I know more changes are needed. Would you please post a MWE of a book with the complete preamble you are using?

Comment: Yes I will complete my MWE with my entire preambule (I will create an answer below with the full preamble). I try your code and it works! I think there is an another problem in my preambule...

Comment: Do not add a new answer!! Edit your question adding the new code at the end.

Comment: It works, thanks very much!! On the other hand, the commands \full{\printindex[piece]} and \full{\tableofcontents} (and maybe \full{\printindex}) would not work ... is this normal? And when I use natbib instead of biblatex, my document cannot be compiled. I will try to understand why...

Comment: `\tableofcontents` works without using `\full`. Use longer titles to test. Clean all auxiliary files before compile. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's OK in the MWE but not in my document because of the use of \usepackage{tocstyle} and \usetocstyle{allwithdot}. Since I'm not very happy with the formatting of the table of contents with these packages, I'll create a new specific question to its formatting. Another remark: why the last page reference (Tirata) does not appear in the glossary? I observed the same phenomenon on my document.

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files and regenerate the glossary again. It works fine. If you are changing the geometry,  the TOC,  and want to use `biblatex`, etc.. why use `tufte-book` at all? You are swimming against the current.

Comment: What do you mean by auxiliary files? For biblatex, I do not change nothing, as it was in the template that I got and allows to insert page number of references in margin notes.

Comment: To make Tirata appear you have to regenerate the glossary again. Probably  you are using an older one. Please see the picture I just added.

Comment: I just understood your previous comments thanks to your last comment. I work on Overleaf so normally I have the latest version of the Glossary ...? I have the full definition of Tirata, but as in your example I do not have the corresponding page numbers like the other definitions.

Comment: Try to save your main document with another name like `main_v2.tex` and compile again. `Tirata` appears in two places, as a name of the entry and as an `\item` of the list as  `A \gls{Tirata}.`

Comment: Sorry, now I see the page number does not appear for the last entry. To be done.

Comment: do you find how to do to have the corresponding page number of the last entry of the glossary?

Comment: @Phil8544 The page number of the last entry of the glossary is not longer an issue using the last version of the environment `fullwidth` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587185/161015

Comment: Thank you, indeed I took the wrong page to correct my document!