# layout problem with \full{\printindex} in Tufte documentclass

Tags: etoc, fullwidth, tufte-book

I want to edit two indexes (index and index [piece]) across the full page width in a Tufte documentclass. I am using the code as described in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\ifx\ifxetex\ifluatex\else
%\ifxetex
  \newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
  }
  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1] {\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
  \fi
 \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % The fancyvrb package lets us customize the formatting of verbatim
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize{7}{8}}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize{8}{10}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny{7}{8}}
\renewcommand\small{\@setfontsize\small{10}{12}}
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{14}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{10.95}{15}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12}{16}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{14.4}{18}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{20.74}{30}}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge{24}{36}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{papersize={17.0cm,24.0cm}}

\geometry{left={1.7cm},right={1.8cm},top={1.5cm},bottom={2.2cm},marginparsep={0.5cm},marginparwidth={3.68cm},includemp,includehead}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}


\newcommand{\plainsubtitle}{}%     plain-text-only subtitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\@subtitle{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}% use provided plain-text title
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}%
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing
    {\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle: \plainsubtitle{}}}}% set the PDF metadata title
}


\title{This is the title of the book} 
\subtitle{This is the subtitle of the book}
\author{Me}  
\publisher{Name of the editor}  

\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newfontfamily\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase] %other fonts: emmentaler-11.otf emmentaler-13.otf emmentaler-14.otf emmentaler-16.otf emmentaler-18.otf emmentaler-20.otf emmentaler-23.otf emmentaler-26.otf
\newcommand\directFermata{{\emmentaler{}\symbol{"E132}}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text added
\usepackage[french]{babel}%.................. Language setup
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \oldchapter
}

\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
  \ifcase\month\or janvier\or f\'{e}vrier\or mars\or avril\or mai\or juin\or
  juillet\or ao\^{u}t\or septembre\or octobre\or novembre\or
  d\'{e}cembre\fi\space\number\year
}

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage{adjmulticol} 
\newlength{\rmarginW}
\setlength{\rmarginW}{\marginparwidth +\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{%    
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-\rmarginW}
        #1
\end{adjmulticols}}
\usepackage{units}
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}}
\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}% prints in red
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}}% hair space
\newcommand{\hquad}{\hskip0.5em\relax}% half quad space
\newcommand{\TODO}{\textcolor{red}{\bf TODO!}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace}
\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}
\newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}}
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}}% a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1
\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically (and doesn't add cmd to the index)
\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{%
  \hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% command name
    }%
    {% add the command and package to the index
  \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
  \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
}%
}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{%
  \texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% command name
    }%
    {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
    }%
}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1] 
{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
 \newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
 \newenvironment{docspec} 
{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces} 
{\end{quotation}}% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% document class option name
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}% document class option name defined
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

% Début Module pour insérer les ornements des parties
\makeatletter
\def\H@old@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {%
     \begin{fullwidth}%
     \centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 10\p@
       \psvectorian[height=0.2cm]{88}\par
       \vskip 10\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
     \end{fullwidth}%
    }%
    \@endpart}

\makeatother
% Fin Module pour insérer les ornements des parties

%backmatter
\usepackage{csquotes}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite} 
{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}
\addbibresource{sample-handout.bib}
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}


\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Exorde}
{
    name=Exorde,
    description={Début du discours, qui vise à rendre l'auditoire docile, attentif et bienveillant}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narration}
{
    name=Narration,
    description={Exposé des faits, qui constitue la seconde partie du discours judiciaire après l'exorde. La narration était le premier exercice de rhétorique}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmation}
{
    name=Confirmation,
    description={Partie argumentative du discours judiciaire, accompagné en général d'un réfutation (\textit{Confutatio})}
}

\newglossaryentry{Péroraison}
{
    name=Péroraison,
    description={La fin du discours judiciaire, qui le résume et en accentue le \textit{pathos}, par l'appel à la colère ou la pitié}
}

\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2,intoc]
\makeindex[name=piece,intoc,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{fullwidth}%
    \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vspace{3pc}%
  \fontsize{23}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  \cleardoublepage
\end{titlepage}

\blankpage

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{fullwidth}%
    \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vspace{3pc}%
  \fontsize{23}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
\end{titlepage}

% v.4 copyright page
\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
Copyright \the\year\ Me

\par\smallcaps{\'{E}dité par \thanklesspublisher}

\par\smallcaps{tufte-latex.googlecode.com}

\par Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the ``License''); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \smallcaps{``AS IS'' BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

\par\textit{Premi\`{e}re \'{e}dition, \monthyear}
\end{fullwidth}


% r.7 dedication
\cleardoublepage
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\fontsize{13}{14}\selectfont\itshape
\nohyphenation
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\
\dedication{Text of dedication}
\end{flushright}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{doublespace}
\vfill
\vfill

% r.5 Remerciements et Préface
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill
\chapter{Avant-Propos}

\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill
\chapter{Pr\'{e}face}

% r.9 introduction
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Introduction}

The introduction remains to be written.

%%
% Start the main matter (normal chapters)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{First Part of the book}

\mainmatter

\begin{fullwidth}
\sloppy
\newthought{This is the} paragraph dedicated to the preamble of the presentation of the part of this book.
\
\end{fullwidth}

\chapter{The Seven Toccatas}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\sloppy
\newthought{The Toccatas for} Keyboard, BWV 910–916, are seven pieces for clavier written by Johann Sebastian Bach. Although the pieces were not originally organized into a collection by Bach himself (as were most of his other keyboard works, such as the Well Tempered Clavier and the English Suites etc.), the pieces share many similarities, and are frequently grouped and performed together under a collective title. \footnote{From Wikipedia:  Toccatas fo Keyboard(Bach))}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Toccata in F-sharp minor \index{Toccata in F-sharp minor, BWV 910}
\item Toccata in C-minor \index{Toccata in C-minor, BWV 911}
\item Toccata in D-major \index{Toccata in D-major, BWV 912}
\item Toccata in D-minor \index{Toccata in D-minor, BWV 913}
\item Toccata in E-minor \index{Toccata in E-minor, BWV 914}
\item Toccata in G-minor \index{Toccata in G-minor, BWV 915}
\item Toccata in G-major \index{Toccata in G-major, BWV 916}
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{The other keyboard works}

\section{Des \oe uvres}

In this example, several keywords\index[piece]{keywords2} will be used which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index[piece]{Index2}.


Chorale No. 3 in A minor \index{Chorale No. 3 in A minor}
Symphony No. 3 "Organ" -- Finale \index{Symphony No. 3 "Organ" -- Finale}
Symphony for Organ No. 5 in F Major -- Toccata \index{Symphony for Organ No. 5 in F Major -- Toccata}
La Nativité du Seigneur \index{La Nativité du Seigneur}
Crown Imperial March \index{Crown Imperial March (arranged for organ by Herbert Murrill)}

\index{Concerto for Organ, Timpani and Strings in G minor}

\index{Land of Hope and Glory Pomp and Circumstance Military March No. 1}

Organ Symphony No. 1 in D minor, Op. 14, VI. \index{Organ Symphony No. 1 in D minor, Op. 14, VI. Finale}

\index{Organ Concerto HWV 306 - Op. 7 No. 1 in B flat major}

Fugue in G minor BWV 578 \index[piece]{Fugue in G minor BWV 578}
\index[piece]{Edvard Grieg – Peer Gynt Suite No. 1 Op. 46: Morning Mood}
\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Symphony No. 5 in C minor, Op. 67, "Fate": I. Allegro Con Brio }

The Four Seasons, Op. 8 \index[piece]{Antonio Vivaldi – The Four Seasons, Op. 8, "Spring": Allegro}

\index[piece]{Samuel Barber – Adagio for Strings}

The Valkyrie: Ride of the Valkyries \index[piece]{Richard Wagner – The Valkyrie: Ride of the Valkyries }

Nocturne No. 2 in E-Flat major, Op. 9 \index[piece]{Frédéric Chopin – Nocturne No. 2 in E-Flat major, Op. 9 }

\index[piece]{Johann Pachelbel – Canon in D major }

\index[piece]{Carl Orff – Carmina Burana: O Fortuna }
\index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – Orchestral Suite No. 3 in D major, BWV 1068: Air }
\index[piece]{Gustav Holst – The Planets, Op. 32: Jupiter, the Bringer of Jollity }

\index[piece]{Claude Debussy – Suite bergamasque, L 75: Clair de Lune }

\index[piece]{Giuseppe Verdi – Nabucco: Chorus of the Hebrew Slaves (Va', Pensiero, Sull'ali Dorate) }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Piano Concerto No. 21 in C major, K. 467: II. Andante }

Brandenburg Concerto No. 3 in G major \index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – 
Brandenburg Concerto No. 3 in G major, BWV 1048: Allegro }

   Thaïs: Meditation \index[piece]{Jules Massenet – Thaïs: Meditation }

\index[piece]{Antonín Dvořák – Symphony No. 9 in E minor, Op. 95, "From the New World": II. Largo }

\index[piece]{Johann Strauss II – On the Beautiful Blue Danube, Op. 314 }

\index[piece]{Johannes Brahms – Hungarian Dance No. 5 in G minor }

\index[piece]{Pyotr Ilyich Tchaikovsky – Swan Lake Suite, Op. 20: Scene }

\index[piece]{Erik Satie – Gymnopédie No. 1 } 

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Requiem, K. 626: Lacrimosa Dies Illa }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Bagatelle in A minor, Wo Op. 59, "Für Elise" }

\index[piece]{Edward Elgar – Pomp and Circumstance, Op. 39: Land of Hope and Glory }

\index[piece]{Georges Bizet – Carmen Suite No. 2: Habanera }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125, "Choral": Ode an Die Freude }

\index[piece]{Jacques Offenbach – The Tales of Hoffmann: Barcarolle }

\index[piece]{Remo Giazotto – Adagio in G minor for Strings and Organ (after T. Albinoni) }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Serenade No. 13 in G major, K. 525, "Eine Kleine Nachtmusik": I. Allegro }

\index[piece]{Gioachino Rossini – The Barber of Seville: Overture }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Piano Sonata No. 14 in C-sharp minor, Op. 27:2, "Moonlight Sonata": Adagio Sostenuto }

\index[piece]{Bedřich Smetana – Má Vlast (My Fatherland): Vltava (The Moldau River) }

\index[piece]{Luigi Boccherini – String Quintet in E major, Op. 13: Minuet }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Symphony No. 40 in G minor, K. 550: I. Allegro Molto }

\index[piece]{Antonín Dvořák – Slavonic Dance No. 2, Op. 72 }

\index[piece]{Charles Gounod – Ave Maria (after J.S. Bach) }

\index[piece]{Jean Sibelius – Finlandia, Op. 26 }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Piano Sonata No. 11 in A major, K. 331: Rondo: Alla Turca }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – The Magic Flute, K. 620: Overture }

\index[piece]{George Frideric Handel – The Messiah, HWV 56: Hallelujah Chorus }

\index[piece]{Edvard Grieg – Peer Gynt Suite No. 1, Op. 46: In the Hall of the Mountain King }

\index[piece]{Gabriel Fauré – Pavane }

\index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – Double Concerto in D minor for Two Violins, BWV 1043: Vivace }

\index[piece]{Georges Bizet – L'Arlésienne Suite No. 1: Prelude }

\index[piece]{Johann Strauss I – Radetzky March, Op. 228 }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Egmont, Op. 84: Overture }

\index[piece]{Stanley Myers – Cavatina }

\index[piece]{Arcangelo Corelli – Concerto G rosso No. 8 in G minor, Op. 6: "Christmas Concerto": Allegro }

\index[piece]{Sergei Rachmaninoff – Vocalise, Op. 34 }

\index[piece]{Giuseppe Verdi – Messa Da Requiem: Dies Irae – Tuba Mirum }

\index[piece]{Gustav Mahler – Symphony No. 5: Adagietto }

\kant[1-4]

\part{This is the second part of the book}

\chapter{First chapter of the second part}
\textit{\Gls{Exorde}}, \textit{\Gls{Narration}}, \textit{\Gls{Confirmation}}, 
\textit{\Gls{Péroraison}}.

\section{Section}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}

\newthought{The continuation of} the book is still to be written...

\part{This is the third part of the book}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\backmatter %<= I want a Full page environment from here.

\chapter{Bibliographie}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources bibliographiques]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title= Sources internet]
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage
\full{\printglossaries}
\clearpage

    \full{\printindex}
    \clearpage
    \Full{\printindex[piece]}
    \clearpage
    \newcommand*{\DotsAndPage}
    {\nobreak\leaders\hbox{\bfseries\normalsize\hbox to .75ex {\hss.\hss}}%
             \hfill\nobreak
             \makebox[\rightskip][r]{\bfseries\normalsize\etocpage}\par}
     
    \etocsetstyle {part}
    {\parindent 0pt
    \nobreak
    \etocskipfirstprefix}
    {\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
    {\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\centering
    \etocifnumbered{Partie \etocnumber{} - }{}\etocname\par}
    {}

    \etocsetstyle {chapter}
    {\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \nobreak\medskip
    \etocskipfirstprefix}
    {\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \pagebreak[1]\smallskip}
    {\normalsize\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape
    \etocnumber. \etocname\DotsAndPage }
    {\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax }

    \etocsetstyle {section}
    {\leftskip1cm\rightskip .75cm \parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax
    \nobreak\smallskip}
    {}
    {\footnotesize\sffamily\mdseries\itshape
    \etocname{} (p. \etocpage). }
    {\par\medskip}
    \etocsettagdepth {preamble} {none}
    \etocsettagdepth {linestyles} {section}
    \etocsettagdepth {globalcmds} {section}
    \etocsettagdepth {custom} {none}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

    \full{\tableofcontents}
    \end{document}
```

The result is shown in the image below. How do I get the index to respect the margins and go to the next page when a page is full to resolve the issue ? I don't understand either why the "index des oeuvres" (index[piece]) starts on the even page...
[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: (1) Does the new answer, without any changes, works in your system? If so accept the answer and ask another question, There are no figures in your last MWE (2) Add one package/element at the time. The tufte class predefine many defaults and commands, and might have conflicts with packages loaded later. (3) Some packages you intended to load need lualatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expanded answer** on request.

The answer was updated after the request to have the above material and some other parts of a `tufte book` using the entire width of the page.

While the class provides a full-width environment, in this case the book is a non-standard size and will be printed centered on A4 paper. This task will be done by the package `geometry`. (No need to use `crop`).

Under these circumstances, it is necessary to redefine the `fullwidth` environment taking into account the new geometry required for a smaller page.

Only the packages required for this task were kept from the MWE code. The `tufte-book` class loads a lot of packages (see the list in the log file), so it is better to add them one by one and test their compatibility with each other and `xelatex`.

A chapter of a `tufte book`

[image: p]

References full width

[image: b]

Glossary full width

[image: z]

Index two columns, two pages,  full width

[image: i]

TOC full width (done with `etoc` by the OP, not part of the answer)

[image: tx]

This is the code.

```
\listfiles % list used files in log

% !TeX TS-program = xelatex  

%%%% + makeglossary & two compiles

\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter, notoc]{tufte-book}

\PrintTufteSettings % see log

\geometry{% normal pages 
    paperheight  =297mm, paperwidth  = 210mm,  %layout=a4paper
    layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    left=15mm, % right will be the same because of symmetric
    bindingoffset= 5mm, % add space for binding
    textwidth=90mm,
    top=14mm,
    marginparsep=6mm,   marginparwidth=40mm,
    includehead,
    layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,  % 297-240 = 57mm   210-170 = 40mm ->> to center smaller layout in a4
    showframe=true,
    showcrop=true }

\renewenvironment{fullwidth}
{\newgeometry{% full width pages
        layoutheight =240mm,layoutwidth  =170mm,
        textheight=38\baselineskip,
        headheight=\baselineskip,
        left=15mm, % right will be the same because of symmetric
        bindingoffset= 5mm, % add space for binding 
        textwidth=136mm, % 90+ 6+ 40
        top=14mm,
        marginparsep=0mm,   marginparwidth=0mm, %changed to full width <<<<<<<<<<
        includehead,
        layoutvoffset= 28.5mm,layouthoffset= 20mm,  % 297-240 = 57mm   210-170 = 40mm ->> to center smaller layout in a4
        showframe=true,
        showcrop=true }
    
    % \TufteRecalculate
    \fancyhfoffset[LE]{0pt}
    \fancyhfoffset[RO]{0pt}
}   
{\restoregeometry}%

\RequirePackage{showframe} % margin line <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.1pt}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
}

\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1] {\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plainsubtitle}{}%     plain-text-only subtitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \gdef\@subtitle{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}% use provided plain-text title
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}%
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing
    {\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle: \plainsubtitle{}}}}% set the PDF metadata title
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{musicography}
%%\usepackage{lilyglyphs} %<<<< needs lualatex !

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text added

%%%%*********************************************** TOC
\usepackage{etoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \newcommand*{\DotsAndPage}
{\nobreak\leaders\hbox{\bfseries\normalsize\hbox to .75ex {\hss.\hss}}%
    \hfill\nobreak
    \makebox[\rightskip][r]{\bfseries\normalsize\etocpage}\par}

\etocsetstyle {part}
{\parindent 0pt
    \nobreak
    \etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\centering
    \etocifnumbered{Partie \etocnumber{} - }{}\etocname\par}
{}

\etocsetstyle {chapter}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \nobreak\medskip
    \etocskipfirstprefix}
{\leftskip 0pt \rightskip .75cm \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \pagebreak[1]\smallskip}
{\normalsize\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape
    \etocnumber \etocname\DotsAndPage } % chapters are unnnumbered in tufte book <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax }

\etocsetstyle {section}
{\leftskip1cm\rightskip .75cm \parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax
    \nobreak\smallskip}
{}
{\footnotesize\sffamily\mdseries\itshape
    \etocname{} (p. \etocpage). }
{\par\medskip}
\etocsettagdepth {preamble} {none}
\etocsettagdepth {linestyles} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {globalcmds} {section}
\etocsettagdepth {custom} {none}
%%%%***********************************************


\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
    \ifcase\month\or janvier\or f\'{e}vrier\or mars\or avril\or mai\or juin\or
    juillet\or ao\^{u}t\or septembre\or octobre\or novembre\or
    d\'{e}cembre\fi\space\number\year
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}

\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
language=auto,
style=apa,
natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< examples from biblatex instalation

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Exorde}
{
    name={Exorde},
    description={Début du discours, qui vise à rendre l'auditoire docile, attentif et bienveillant}
}

\newglossaryentry{Narration}
{
    name={Narration},
    description={Exposé des faits, qui constitue la seconde partie du discours judiciaire après l'exorde. La narration était le premier exercice de rhétorique}
}

\newglossaryentry{Confirmation}
{
    name={Confirmation},
    description={Partie argumentative du discours judiciaire, accompagné en général d'un réfutation (\textit{Confutatio})}
}

\newglossaryentry{Péroraison}
{
    name={Péroraison},
    description={La fin du discours judiciaire, qui le résume et en accentue le \textit{pathos}, par l'appel à la colère ou la pitié}
}

\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2,intoc]
\makeindex[name=piece,intoc,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]

\title{This is the title of my book} 
\renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{This is the subtitle of my book: music}
\author{Me}  
\publisher{Various \'{e}ditions}  

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{fullwidth}%
        \fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
        \vspace{11.5pc}%
        
        \centering
        \fontsize{32}{45}\selectfont\noindent{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
        \vspace{3pc}%
        
        \fontsize{23}{30}\selectfont\noindent{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}%
        \vfill%
        
        \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\noindent\raggedright\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
\end{titlepage}

% v.4 copyright page
\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
    ~\vfill
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    Copyright \the\year\ Me
    
    \smallcaps{\'{E}dité par \thanklesspublisher}
    
    \smallcaps{tufte-latex.googlecode.com}
    
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the ``License''); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \smallcaps{``AS IS'' BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
    
    \textit{Premi\`{e}re \'{e}dition, \monthyear}
\end{fullwidth}
\cleardoublepage

% r.7 dedication
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{fullwidth}   
    %\begin{doublespace} % not needed, use \fontsize
    \noindent\fontsize{13}{22}\selectfont\itshape %space the baselines to 22pt
    \nohyphenation
    \begin{flushright}
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        Text of dedication
        
        11. \kant[11]
    \end{flushright}
    %\end{doublespace}
\end{fullwidth}

% r.5 Remerciements et Préface  
\chapter{Avant-Propos}
11. \kant[11-15]

\chapter{Pr\'{e}face}

12. \kant[12-16]

% r.9 introduction
\chapter{Introduction}

The introduction remains to be written.

15. \kant[15-20]

%%
% Start the main matter (normal chapters)
\mainmatter

\part{First Part of the book}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \sloppy
    \newthought{This is the} paragraph dedicated to the preamble of the presentation of the part of this book.
    
    21. \kant[21]
    
\end{fullwidth}

\chapter{The Seven Toccatas}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\sloppy
\newthought{The Toccatas for} Keyboard, BWV 910–916, are seven pieces for clavier written by Johann Sebastian Bach. Although the pieces were not originally organized into a collection by Bach himself (as were most of his other keyboard works, such as the Well Tempered Clavier and the English Suites etc.), the pieces share many similarities, and are frequently grouped and performed together under a collective title. \footnote{From Wikipedia:  Toccatas fo Keyboard(Bach))}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Toccata in F-sharp minor \index{Toccata in F-sharp minor, BWV 910}
    \item Toccata in C-minor \index{Toccata in C-minor, BWV 911}
    \item Toccata in D-major \index{Toccata in D-major, BWV 912}
    \item Toccata in D-minor \index{Toccata in D-minor, BWV 913}
    \item Toccata in E-minor \index{Toccata in E-minor, BWV 914}
    \item Toccata in G-minor \index{Toccata in G-minor, BWV 915}
    \item Toccata in G-major \index{Toccata in G-major, BWV 916}
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{The other keyboard works}

\section{Des \oe uvres}

In this example, several keywords\index[piece]{keywords2} will be used which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index[piece]{Index2}.

Chorale No. 3 in A minor \index{Chorale No. 3 in A minor}

Symphony No. 3 "Organ" -- Finale \index{Symphony No. 3 "Organ" -- Finale}

Symphony for Organ No. 5 in F Major -- Toccata \index{Symphony for Organ No. 5 in F Major -- Toccata}

La Nativité du Seigneur \index{La Nativité du Seigneur}

Crown Imperial March \index{Crown Imperial March (arranged for organ by Herbert Murrill)}

\index{Concerto for Organ, Timpani and Strings in G minor}

\index{Land of Hope and Glory Pomp and Circumstance Military March No. 1}

Organ Symphony No. 1 in D minor, Op. 14, VI. \index{Organ Symphony No. 1 in D minor, Op. 14, VI.}

\index{Organ Concerto HWV 306 - Op. 7 No. 1 in B flat major}

Fugue in G minor BWV 578 \index[piece]{Fugue in G minor BWV 578}

\index[piece]{Edvard Grieg – Peer Gynt Suite No. 1 Op. 46: Morning Mood}

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Symphony No. 5 in C minor, Op. 67, "Fate": I. Allegro Con Brio }

The Four Seasons, Op. 8 \index[piece]{Antonio Vivaldi – The Four Seasons, Op. 8, "Spring": Allegro}

\index[piece]{Samuel Barber – Adagio for Strings}

The Valkyrie: Ride of the Valkyries \index[piece]{Richard Wagner – The Valkyrie: Ride of the Valkyries }

Nocturne No. 2 in E-Flat major, Op. 9 \index[piece]{Frédéric Chopin – Nocturne No. 2 in E-Flat major, Op. 9 }

\index[piece]{Johann Pachelbel – Canon in D major }

\index[piece]{Carl Orff – Carmina Burana: O Fortuna }

\index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – Orchestral Suite No. 3 in D major, BWV 1068: Air }

\index[piece]{Gustav Holst – The Planets, Op. 32: Jupiter, the Bringer of Jollity }

\index[piece]{Claude Debussy – Suite bergamasque, L 75: Clair de Lune }

\index[piece]{Giuseppe Verdi – Nabucco: Chorus of the Hebrew Slaves (Va', Pensiero, Sull'ali Dorate) }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Piano Concerto No. 21 in C major, K. 467: II. Andante }

Brandenburg Concerto No. 3 in G major \index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – Brandenburg Concerto No. 3 in G major, BWV 1048: Allegro }

Thaïs: Meditation \index[piece]{Jules Massenet – Thaïs: Meditation }

\index[piece]{Antonín Dvořák – Symphony No. 9 in E minor, Op. 95, "From the New World": II. Largo }

\index[piece]{Johann Strauss II – On the Beautiful Blue Danube, Op. 314 }

\index[piece]{Johannes Brahms – Hungarian Dance No. 5 in G minor }

\index[piece]{Pyotr Ilyich Tchaikovsky – Swan Lake Suite, Op. 20: Scene }

\index[piece]{Erik Satie – Gymnopédie No. 1 } 

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Requiem, K. 626: Lacrimosa Dies Illa }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Bagatelle in A minor, Wo Op. 59, "Für Elise" }

\index[piece]{Edward Elgar – Pomp and Circumstance, Op. 39: Land of Hope and Glory }

\index[piece]{Georges Bizet – Carmen Suite No. 2: Habanera }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125, "Choral": Ode an Die Freude }

\index[piece]{Jacques Offenbach – The Tales of Hoffmann: Barcarolle }

\index[piece]{Remo Giazotto – Adagio in G minor for Strings and Organ (after T. Albinoni) }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Serenade No. 13 in G major, K. 525, "Eine Kleine Nachtmusik": I. Allegro }

\index[piece]{Gioachino Rossini – The Barber of Seville: Overture }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Piano Sonata No. 14 in C-sharp minor, Op. 27:2, "Moonlight Sonata": Adagio Sostenuto }

\index[piece]{Bedřich Smetana – Má Vlast (My Fatherland): Vltava (The Moldau River) }

\index[piece]{Luigi Boccherini – String Quintet in E major, Op. 13: Minuet }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Symphony No. 40 in G minor, K. 550: I. Allegro Molto }

\index[piece]{Antonín Dvořák – Slavonic Dance No. 2, Op. 72 }

\index[piece]{Charles Gounod – Ave Maria (after J.S. Bach) }

\index[piece]{Jean Sibelius – Finlandia, Op. 26 }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – Piano Sonata No. 11 in A major, K. 331: Rondo: Alla Turca }

\index[piece]{Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart – The Magic Flute, K. 620: Overture }

\index[piece]{George Frideric Handel – The Messiah, HWV 56: Hallelujah Chorus }

\index[piece]{Edvard Grieg – Peer Gynt Suite No. 1, Op. 46: In the Hall of the Mountain King }

\index[piece]{Gabriel Fauré – Pavane }

\index[piece]{Johann Sebastian Bach – Double Concerto in D minor for Two Violins, BWV 1043: Vivace }

\index[piece]{Georges Bizet – L'Arlésienne Suite No. 1: Prelude }

\index[piece]{Johann Strauss I – Radetzky March, Op. 228 }

\index[piece]{Ludwig van Beethoven – Egmont, Op. 84: Overture }

\index[piece]{Stanley Myers – Cavatina }

\index[piece]{Arcangelo Corelli – Concerto G rosso No. 8 in G minor, Op. 6: "Christmas Concerto": Allegro }

\index[piece]{Sergei Rachmaninoff – Vocalise, Op. 34 }

\index[piece]{Giuseppe Verdi – Messa Da Requiem: Dies Irae – Tuba Mirum }

\index[piece]{Gustav Mahler – Symphony No. 5: Adagietto }

\kant[1-14]

\part{This is the second part of the book}

\chapter{II First chapter of the second part}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\textit{\Gls{Exorde}}, 
    \item\textit{\Gls{Narration}}, 
    \item\textit{\Gls{Confirmation}}, 
    \item\textit{\Gls{Péroraison}}.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section not named}
11. \kant[11]

\chapter{II This is the second chapter}

\newthought{The continuation of} the book is still to be written...

15. \kant[15-25]

\part{This is the third part of the book}

\chapter{III First chapter}
1. \kant[1-5]
\section{Section to be found}
2. \kant[2-9]
\chapter{III Second chapter}
3. \kant[3-10]

\chapter[III Coda]{III Coda \musHalf \, \musQuarter \, \musEighth\,  \musSixteenth}

9. \kant[9]

See \citealp{bertram}. See \parencite{bertram}.

Plus \autocite{companion,ctan,markey,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}.

Also \citep{doody} and \cite{maron} and \citet{maron}

Standard biblatex command names: not use natbib=true

%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557292/citations-in-two-different-languages-for-the-same-latex-document
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcite{kowalik}  OK
    \item \parencite{vangennep} OK
    \item \citet{nussbaum} NO
    \item \cite{ moraux} ) OK
    \item  \autocite{companion} OK
\end{itemize}   

\selectlanguage{english}
Written in English  using textcite: \textcite{kowalik}

\selectlanguage{french}
Écrit en français en utilisant textcite: \textcite{kowalik}

19. \kant[19-29]

\vfill  
\emph{\Huge want a Full page environment from here.}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \cleardoublepage        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}   
    \printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]   
    
    \printglossaries
    
    \printindex
    
    \printindex[piece]      

    \tableofcontents
\end{fullwidth}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I apply your suggestion, I find the header problem as presented in a previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546275/header-problems-in-fullwidth-environment-in-tufte-book

Comment: This is the problem with over simplified MWEs. Please update your MWE with all the elements of your complete document: preamble and real sample of the content to fill several pages.

Comment: I would like to update my question with the actual preamble and content but it is very long ... No problem for you?

Comment: @Phil8544  Not at all. Use representative parts of your content to cover all circumstances. Also clarify where you want to  change to full page: just at the end of the book, the backmatter?

Comment: There are ways using internet to share large or complex files, e.g. overleaf.

Comment: Sorry for the delay of my update. I Want all the backmatter to be in a fullwidth environment. I insert the comment in the code of my question.

Comment: @Phil8544 Thank you!  I will take a look to the update very soon.

Comment: I encounter many layout changes with this code (the figures of the main text are sent at the end of the chapter for example) and the whole document is disorganized. I need some time to understand why there are all these changes.

Comment: There are no figures in your last MWE., Your question was related with achieving full with in the backmatter. The answer works in that sense?

Comment: Yes it seems to work for the backmatter (but I have to solve new problems with figures and tables, I am trying to find out where the problem could come from...)

Comment: Do you see this question (it's the last problem that I encountered with the code you proposed): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627378/fullwidth-figure-and-table-layout-on-even-page-in-tufte-book-documentclass? Thanks

Comment: @Phil8544 I added an answer.