# \maketitle Error,Tufte Book Class

Tags: tufte

I am getting the following error when using the Tufte book class:

```
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
./error.tex:47: Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra }

.47 \maketitle
```

Here's a minimum example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[b5paper]{tufte-book}


\title{The Book}
\author{The Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

x

 \end{document}
```

Sounds like there's an extra } somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: If I change the class to "book" it compiles without a problem.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a file and there's not enough room here in the comments, so I posted it on pastebin:  https://pastebin.com/NyBvtjcN

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561151/161015.  It has a workaround of this bug. And https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202189/161015

Comment: @user26732 sorry I did not notice your comment in the file saying xetex (you didn't mention that in the text) it runs without error with pdflatex but I see the error with xetex. I delted my first comment

Comment: I added a more minimal example (cutting out packages not needed for the problem makes it a lot easier to trace)