# What is the state of tufte-latex?

Tags: packages, tufte, tufte-book

I tried to use `tufte-latex` for a longer document in 2012, but bailed out and switched to `memoir` for multiple reasons.

There are quite some recent questions on `tufte-latex` here. Its [GitHub](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) shows the latest change to this package in 2019. (This is not bad as such, there are a lot of old mature packages.) But seeing questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202142/problems-compiling-tufte-title-page-in-xelatex) raises some eyebrows.

**Is `tufte-latex` still alive?** Would you recommend to use it?

Would you recommend to use it for a 100+ pages document? (I definitely would recommend `memoir` and I would not recommend `tufte-latex` from 2012 for this sake. But, hey, a lot chould have changed since then.)

I am most interested in *not* replicating Tufte's style up to the last inch, but in wide margins, margin figures, full-width figures. Footnote / margin-note citations are also nice. I guess, one could fake all of them in `koma` or `memoir`, if one would want to.

(In fact, margin-note citations turned to be a mess in my literature review in 2012, so I switched to more conservative `memoir`, but a lot can be done in writing itself to fix this.)

Comment: If you already have a 100+ pages document, then you can just give it a try: change the documentclass, and see how much time it takes you to resolve errors (if any) and modify the output to your needs. If that takes more than 1-2 hours then that would point towards the class not being very suitable for your use case.

Comment: My interest was primarily for writing a new one. Ten years ago I resolved errors in the other direction and never looked back until today. That old project is long done.

Comment: Writing a new document would be easier, since you can avoid incompatibilities from the start. In that case just write a few pages and see if you like it. The class is mature, but the layout is not intended to be very flexible - some people like to work with it, others don't.

Comment: I am very new to LaTeX and my first stab using it is with the Tufte-Book class.  It has been a steep  learning curve for me since I am not a developer, but with this very supportive community I am slowly making progress. I have made several modifications to my particular .tex file using code snippets that have arisen not only from my questions but the questions of others as well.  So far, so good.