# `tufte-book` class and `IEEEtran` bibliography style erroring with "Paragraph ended before \BR@c@bibitem was complete."

Tags: bibliographies, errors, natbib, tufte

I am getting the following error:

```
(build/proposal-tufte-mwe.bbl
Runaway argument?
\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing S.~Koenig and M.~Likhachev, ``Fast repla\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \BR@c@bibitem was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.30

?
```

Search results indicate this can be caused by `%` characters in URLs, but that's not the case for me.

Here is a minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square, numbers}  % `\documentclass{tufte-book}' uses `natbib` too. Avoid option clash

\begin{filecontents}{minimal-references.bib}
@article{koenigFastReplanningNavigation2005,
  title = {Fast Replanning for Navigation in Unknown Terrain},
  author = {Koenig, S. and Likhachev, M.},
  date = {2005-06},
  journaltitle = {IEEE Transactions on Robotics},
  doi = {10.1109/TRO.2004.838026},
  url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1435479/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\section{Related Work}
Such is the case in the heuristic incremental search for a navigation algorithm~\cite{koenigFastReplanningNavigation2005}.

% \backmatter

% debug bib
% \show\bibitem
% \show\BR@c@bibitem

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{minimal-references}

\end{document}
```

When I hit enter to "ignore" the `Runaway argument?` error, I see the following:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

which surprises me, given the line `\setcitestyle{square, numbers}`.

I am not sure if this is helpful, but I did try to debug:

```
$ latexdef --class tufte-book  --find \BR@b@bibitem
\BR@b@bibitem first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/bibentry.sty".

\BR@b@bibitem:
macro:->\@protected@testopt \BR@b@bibitem \\BR@b@bibitem {}

\\BR@b@bibitem first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/bibentry.sty".

\\BR@b@bibitem:
\long macro:[#1]#2->\ifthenelse {\isempty {#1}}{\BR@bibitem {#2}}{\BR@bibitem [#1]{#2}}\BR@c@bibitem {#2}
```

I am not tied to using `natbib`, and perhaps I should use [the `nobib` option to disable it in `tufte-book`](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/efb8c8e836890bad71fb5834acdd316ebde6db12/tufte-common.def#L873-L885).

I would like an explanation for the error, and a recommendation for a working configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will save a lot of time dealing with `tufte-book` if you use `biber` (and the option `nobib`).

I added examples from `biblatex-examples.bib` included in the distribution.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
language=auto,
style=ieee,
natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{minimal-references.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{minimal-references.bib}
    @article{koenigFastReplanningNavigation2005,
        title = {Fast Replanning for Navigation in Unknown Terrain},
        author = {Koenig, S. and Likhachev, M.},
        date = {2005-06},
        journaltitle = {IEEE Transactions on Robotics}, 
        url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1435479/},
         doi = {10.1109/TRO.2004.838026},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    
    \section{Related Work}
    Such is the case in the heuristic incremental search for a navigation algorithm~\cite{koenigFastReplanningNavigation2005}.
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cite{kastenholz}
        \item \cite{sigfridsson}
        \item \cite{ctan}
        \item \cite{markey} 
    \end{itemize}   
    
%   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%   \bibliography{minimal-references}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

If running `xelatex` or `lualatex`  start as follows to avoid  letter spacing errors.

```
\documentclass[nobib,nofonts]{tufte-book}   
    
%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200722/xetex-seems-to-break-headers-in-tufte-handout  
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\newcommand{\textls}[2][5]{%
    \begingroup\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=#1}#2\endgroup
}
\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[15]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[10]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\textls[15]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
%%************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why biber is less problematic than natbib?

Comment: @Gus Because biblatex + biber works! while while natbib keeps throwing errors and wasting your time. In general terms both are good but I use biblatex because is updated with the APA style I need.