# Cyrillic hyphenation with lualatex using luainputenc

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, cyrillic

It seems the `Cyrillic` hyphenation with `lualatex` using `\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}` does not work. Is any solution of this?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA
% !BIB program = bibtex8

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}

    Матеріали конференції присвячені сучасним проблемам фізики та фізичних технологій,
        перспективним напрямкам фізики енергетичних систем,
        теорії безпеки, криптографічного захисту інформації та криптоаналізу, захисту
        інформації в комп’ютерних мережах та комунікаціях, забезпеченню цілісності баз даних,
        захисту від витоку інформації по каналах побічного електромагнітного випромінювання,
        локальним мережам різної струк\-тури, технічного захисту об’єктів, а також науковим
        дослідженням фундаментального та прикладного характеру у сфері інформаційних наук.

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using luainputenc? It has some uses in some very special cases, but isn't normally needed and by default causes problems with hyphenation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use luainputenc because I time to time compile my document with pdflatex, the declaration of fonts with fontspec so cumbersome.

Comment: The problem though as you found is that by default luatex and xetex set up hyphenation for unicode fonts, that's fixable in luatex as you can load patterns into a normal tex not just initex but it's tricky (and I'm not sure of the exact detail after recent babel changes)

Comment: The real problem is not `luainputenc` but `fontenc`. I presume with the new `babel` you can create a local `language.dat` loading the T2A patterns, but like David I'm not sure of the details. I'll investigate.

Comment: Before sending a complete answer, could you please post a few Ukrainian words with their hyphenation points (just to be sure).

Comment: @JavierBezos In my MWE above pdflatex was made a hyphenation in (first string of text) проблемам фізи\-ки and for the second string from below --  фундамен\-тального

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some tests, the following works for me with TeXLive15 and the latest `babel` (3.9q, required, because it's the version with the new loader for `luatex`). Create a local `language.dat` file with:

```
english     hyphen.tex  % do not change!
=usenglish
=USenglish
=american
nohyphenation   zerohyph.tex
russian   hyph-ru.t2a.tex
ukrainian   hyph-uk.t2a.tex
```

By ‘local’ I mean in the same directory (or another place where your documents could find it without interfering with the the global `language.dat`). There is still a little issue, because Unicode engines don't fully comply with the lccodes expected by standard LaTeX. Add to the `tex` document:

```
\lccode"F7="F7
```

I've only tested Ukrainian (not Russian).

Comment: Tnx. It is work for me too. But what is the reason to create som additional file? Is it a bug of luainputenc?

Comment: This is the way `babel` loads hyphenation patterns. Other engines (`pdftex`, `xetex`) load this file and the patterns when the format is built, but with `luatex` they can be loaded when the document is being typeset. If this file is placed in the directory of the document, then it takes precedence.

Comment: does not work to me (texlive 2019 on Debian 10) with lualatex.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use solution without luainputenc that will work in all three compilers (somewhat cumbersome font setting for (xe|lua)latex though):

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA
% !BIB program = bibtex8
%%% Defining function to check compiler %%%
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex % new if operator (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47579)
\ifXeTeX
    \xetexorluatextrue
\else
    \ifLuaTeX
        \xetexorluatextrue
    \else
        \xetexorluatexfalse
    \fi
\fi

%%% Main class setting %%%
\documentclass{article} % If papersize not set explicitly, each compiler can use whatever default has.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Big block of settings for three compilers %%
\ifxetexorluatex
%%% Language setting for (xe|lua)latex %%%
    \usepackage{polyglossia} % Loads fontspec also.
    \setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
    \setotherlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
    \setotherlanguage{english}

%%% Font setting for (xe|lua)latex %%%
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
%    \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif} % Uncomment if asked to define cyrillic fonts.
%    \newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{CMU Sans Serif} % Uncomment if asked to define cyrillic fonts.
%    \newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{CMU Typewriter Text} % Uncomment if asked to define cyrillic fonts.
\else
    \RequirePDFTeX % Tests for PDFTEX use and throws an error if a different engine is being used.

%%% For proper copypasting of text from pdf %%%
    \usepackage{cmap} % Better search and copypasting of cyrillic text from pdf-file. Can cause errors if used together with pdfx package.
    \defaulthyphenchar=127 % Better hyphenation for copypasting. Must be set just before fontenc.

%%% Language setting for pdflatex %%%
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english,russian, ukrainian]{babel}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    Матеріали конференції присвячені сучасним проблемам фізики та фізичних технологій,
        перспективним напрямкам фізики енергетичних систем,
        теорії безпеки, криптографічного захисту інформації та криптоаналізу, захисту
        інформації в комп’ютерних мережах та комунікаціях, забезпеченню цілісності баз даних,
        захисту від витоку інформації по каналах побічного електромагнітного випромінювання,
        локальним мережам різної струк\-тури, технічного захисту об’єктів, а також науковим
        дослідженням фундаментального та прикладного характеру у сфері інформаційних наук.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this. That is because in lua/xelatex language settings so cumbersome I focused on luainputenc, because it is work both with pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: the other solution does not work to me (texlive 2019 on Debian 10), but this one does (I didn't check the pdflatex, as there is too much maths unicode in my texts)