# E-mail, phone, website, twitter symbols outside of moderncv

Tags: symbols, cv

I am using the amazing CV template by Tyler Ransom: https://tyleransom.github.io/code.html
See the copy of the template below. However, I would still like to use the nice symbols that moderncv offers. Any ideas how to approach this?

Template:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}{\usepackage{lmodern}}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
% Uncomment any of the following four lines to get different fonts
%\usepackage[garamondx,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{garamondx}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newcent}

% Colors: see  http://www.math.umbc.edu/~rouben/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-25.html
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{oucrimson}   {RGB}{132.,22. ,23. }
\definecolor{byublue}     {RGB}{0.  ,30. ,76. }
\definecolor{navyblue}    {RGB}{0.  ,0.  ,128.}
\definecolor{darkblue}    {RGB}{0.  ,0.  ,139.}
\definecolor{dukeblue}    {RGB}{0.  ,0.  ,156.}

% Layout
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace} %singlespacing; onehalfspacing; doublespacing; setstretch{1.1}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[verbose,margin=1in]{geometry} % Margins
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % Sufficent room for headers
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Forces footnotes on bottom

% Headers/Footers
%\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{}
\lfoot{\today} \cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \,of \pageref{LastPage}}

% Useful Packages
%\usepackage{bookmark} % For speedier bookmarks
%\usepackage{amsthm}   % For detailed theorems
%\usepackage{amssymb}  % For fancy math symbols
%\usepackage{amsmath}  % For awesome equations/equation arrays
\usepackage{array}    % For tubular tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}% For long tables
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % For three-part tables
\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column cells
\usepackage{graphicx} % For shiny pictures
\usepackage{subfig}   % For sub-shiny pictures
\usepackage{enumerate}% For cusomtizable lists
%\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,pst-plot} % For trees

% Bib
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % Bibliography
\usepackage{url}                % Allows urls in bib

% TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Links
\usepackage{hyperref}    % Always add hyperref (almost) last
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=oucrimson,urlcolor=oucrimson}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Links point to top of image, builds on hyperref
\usepackage{breakurl}    % Allows urls to wrap, including hyperref

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\makeheading}[2]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth\marginparwidth\marginparsep}%
         {\LARGE\bfseries #1} \hfill  {\LARGE\bfseries #2 \hspace*{-2.3\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}}\\[-0.2\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\rule{\marginparsep}{1.5pt}\rule{\marginparwidth}{1.5pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{
        \pagebreak[3]%
        \vspace{1.0\baselineskip}%
        \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
        \hspace{0in}%
        %\marginpar{\raggedright \scshape #1}#2}
        %\rule[3.5pt]{0.9in}{1.5pt} ~~
        {\raggedright \scshape \large \textbf{#1}}%
        \vspace{0.25\baselineskip}#2
}


\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeheading{NAME}{Curriculum Vitae}


% ADDRESS/CONTACT HEADER
% ==================================================================================
\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{flushleft}
Department of XXXX

University of XXX

Address 1

Address 2

\end{flushleft}
        

\begin{flushright}
\textit{Phone:} (XXX) XXX-XXXX

\textit{E-mail:} \href{mailto:address@host.edu}{address@host.edu}

\textit{Homepage:} \href{https://www.aeaweb.org}{aeaweb.org}

\textit{Citizenship:} [Country] 

\end{flushright}

\end{multicols}
% ==================================================================================



\setstretch{1.2}
\vspace{-.25in}



\section{Education}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year & Ph.D. in Economics, Institution \\
     & \small{Dissertation: \href{link}{Title}} \\
     & \small{Committee: \href{link}{chair name (chair)},...,} \\
Year & M.A. in Economics, Institution \\
Year & B.A. in Economics (Awards), Institution \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Employment \& Affiliations}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year- & Position 2, University 2 \\
Year- & Other affiliation, \href{link}{Affiliate} \\
Year-Year & Position 1, University 1 \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Research Fields}\\
% ==================================================================================
\vspace{-1mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Primary:   & field 1, field 2\\
Secondary: & field 3, field 4\\
\end{tabular}



\section{Published \& Forthcoming Papers}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year &  \href{link}{``Title''} (with Coauthors), \textit{Journal}, vol. XX, n. No., pages pppp--pppp. \\
Year &  \href{link}{``Title''} (with Coauthors), \textit{Journal}, vol. XX, n. No., pages pppp--pppp. \\
Year &  \href{link}{``Title''} (with Coauthors), \textit{Journal}, vol. XX, n. No., pages pppp--pppp. \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Working Papers}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year &  \href{link}{``Title''} (with Coauthors), \textit{Status} \\
\end{tabular}


\pagebreak{}
\section{Works in Progress}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year & ``Title'' (with Coauthors) \\
\end{tabular}


\section{Policy Writings}\\
% % ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year & ``Title'' (with Coauthors), Outlet, Date \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Invited Conference \& Seminar Presentations}\\ %\vspace{-7.5mm}
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year1-Year2 & List of outlets \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Paper Discussions}\\ %\vspace{-7.5mm}
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year & ``Title'' by Authors,(Conference, Location) \\
\end{tabular}



\section{Fellowships \& Awards}\\%\vspace{-7.5mm}
% ==================================================================================
%\begin{itemize} % Use \item[] to prevent a bullet from appearing
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year1-Year2 & Award, Institution\\
\end{tabular}



\section{Teaching Experience}\\
% ==================================================================================
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Instituiton & \href{link}{Course title} (Level)\\
\end{tabular}


\section{Media Appearances}\\
% ==================================================================================
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year & \href{Link}{``Title''} by Author, \emph{Outlet}, Date \\
\end{tabular}



%\pagebreak{}
\section{Skills}\\
%==================================================================================$
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Coding & \multirow{2}{*}{List of coding skills}\\
Skills:& \\
Other & \multirow{2}{*}{List of other skills}\\
Skills:& \\
Languages:&  Languages\\
\end{tabular}



\section{Professional Service}\\
%==================================================================================$
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Referee:&    \textit{Journal 1}, \textit{Journal 2}, \\
\end{tabular}

\pagebreak{}

\section{Departmental \& University Service}\\
%==================================================================================$
\begin{tabular}{p{.85in}>{\hangindent=1em}p{5.65in}<{\raggedright}}
Year- &   Role, Department, Committee name \\
\end{tabular}


%\pagebreak{}
\section{References}\\
%==================================================================================$
Available upon request

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: The moderncv icons are conveniently distributed as standalone packages, you can simply load them and use the commands they define. Cf. https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DG' points out, the icons are all defined in separate `.sty` files and then loaded by `moderncv`. However the problem is, there are commands defined inside the loaded files that require the class file or other `.sty` files to be loaded. So what you need to do is take the minimum code that is required and then load :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%%%%Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47579/156791
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
\xetexorluatextrue
\else
\ifluatex
\xetexorluatextrue
\else
\xetexorluatexfalse
\fi
\fi

%%%%Taken from moderncv.cls
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}           {\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\addresssymbol}            {}
\newcommand*{\bornsymbol}               {}
\newcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}        {}
\newcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}         {}
\newcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}           {}
\newcommand*{\emailsymbol}              {}
\newcommand*{\homepagesymbol}           {}
\newcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}     {}
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}         {}
\newcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol}      {}
\newcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}       {}
\newcommand*{\gitlabsocialsymbol}       {}
\newcommand*{\stackoverflowsocialsymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\bitbucketsocialsymbol}    {}
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}        {}
\newcommand*{\orcidsocialsymbol}        {}
\newcommand*{\researchgatesocialsymbol} {}
\newcommand*{\researcheridsocialsymbol} {}
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\telegramsocialsymbol}     {}
\newcommand*{\whatsappsocialsymbol}     {}
\newcommand*{\matrixsocialsymbol}       {}
\newcommand*{\signalsocialsymbol}       {}

\usepackage{moderncviconssymbols}
%%%%Taken from moderncv.cls
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
\emailsymbol
\mobilephonesymbol
\mobilephonesymbol

\linkedinsocialsymbol
\twittersocialsymbol
\githubsocialsymbol
\gitlabsocialsymbol
\skypesocialsymbol
\googlescholarsocialsymbol
\matrixsocialsymbol
\signalsocialsymbol
\end{document}
```

[image]

To reduce that effort, depending on the engine you are using, you can also have a look into `moderncviconssymbols.sty` and see, that most icons are from `fontawesome` and `marvosym`. So these two packages could be your answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, using fontawesome is the better way to go.