# How to generate PDF/A using XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdf, pdf-a

Title says it all. I need to generate PDF/A compliant documents, and I'm using XeTeX. I couldn't find anything about this; [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x) there's only info about pdfLaTeX (using pdfx) and ConTeXt.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: XeTeX has only the capabilities of pdfTeX in this regard; if you want more than pdfTeX offers, you have to use [LuaTeX and ConTeXt MkIV](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3286/5763).