# How to make a PDF/A document

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf-a

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x)

Are there any options that I could give to pdflatex and xelatex to make sure that all outputted documents adhere to the PDF/A standard? If there is no commandline options, how should I go about of making documents PDF/A compilant?

Comment: Did you try the `pdfx` package and the instructions in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x?rq=1?

Answer (score 3):

There is the `[pdfx][1]` package which provides assistance to create PDF/X-1a and PFD/A-1b compliant pdf documents:

> The package can be loaded with the command:
>
> `\usepackage[<option>]{pdfx}`
>
> where the options are: `x-1a` generates PDF/X-1a compliant PDF.
>   `a-1b` generates PDF/A-1b compliant PDF.

In addition to your `tex` file, you will need a file `\jobname.xmpdata` where you store the necessary [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) data.

Comment: While ``pdfx`` seems to help to get some aspects of pdf-a, I've never seen a fully compliant document produced with it.

Comment: @sebschub That's right, you still need to check compliancy yourself and troubleshoot if necessary. I mostly encounter problems with embedded PDF graphics which rely on external fonts.