# PDF/A with hyperref on TeX Live 2013

Tags: hyperref, pdf-a, hyperxmp

I am trying to make PDF/A from LaTeX (*not* from LuaTeX etc.) with TeX Live 2013 on Fedora Linux. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

What cat says? \label{meow}

See question on page \pageref{meow}.

\end{document}
```

With commands `latex`, `dvips` and last

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor
-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-sOutputFile=meow.pdf meow.ps
```

Now, when I add `\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}` I got validation errors like

```
dc:description :: Wrong value type. Expected type 'lang alt'.
The XMP property 'dc:title' is not synchronized with the document
information entry 'Title'.
A device-specific color space (Annotation C or IC) without an
appropriate output intent is used.
```

Documentation of hyperref says

> -- result is usually not in PDF/A, because many features aren't controlled by hyperref --

but how to control those?

Should I even try this path? There are alternatives like `pdfx`. Which path to use?

Comment: If you want a PDF why not using `pdflatex`? Using `pdflatex` I got no error.

Comment: Yes, you get PDF but not PDF/A with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Doesn't http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x?rq=1 help?

Comment: I have read that about `pdfx`, but didn't figure out how to make it work. Some kind on Hello world -example would be nice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Put the color profile [`eciRGB_v2.icc`](http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip) in the working directory.
2. Add the flowing code to your preamble:

```latex
    \usepackage{hyperxmp}
    \usepackage[pdfa, linktoc=none]{hyperref}

    % ===============================
    % Embedding the color profile.
    % Requires eciRGB_v2.icc in the working directory
    % http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip
    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{eciRGB_v2.icc}
    \pdfcatalog{%
        /OutputIntents [ <<
            /Type /OutputIntent
            /S/GTS_PDFA1
            /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
            /OutputConditionIdentifier (eciRGB v2)
            /Info(eciRGB v2)
        >> ]
    }
```

3. Add metadata with `hyperxmp` and `\hypersetup`:

   ```
   \title{Title}
   \author{First Author, Last Author}
   \hypersetup{%
                pdfauthortitle={Title of the Author},
                pdfcopyright={Copyright (C) 20xx, Copyrightholder},
                pdfsubject={Something},
                pdfkeywords={Keyword1, Keyword2},
                pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/},
                pdfcaptionwriter={Scott Pakin},
                pdfcontactaddress={Street},
                pdfcontactcity={City},
                pdfcontactpostcode={101},
                pdfcontactcountry={Country},
                pdfcontactemail={email@institute.edu},
                pdfcontacturl={http://www.institute.edu},
                pdflang={en},
                bookmarksopen=true,
                bookmarksopenlevel=3,
                hypertexnames=false,
                linktocpage=true,
                plainpages=false,
                breaklinks
            }
   ```

Everything put together results in a document like this:

```
    % ===============================
    % Filename: test.tex

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperxmp}
    \usepackage[pdfa, linktoc=none]{hyperref}

    % ===============================
    % Embedding the color profile.
    % Requires eciRGB_v2.icc in the working directory
    % http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip
    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{eciRGB_v2.icc}
    \pdfcatalog{%
        /OutputIntents [ <<
            /Type /OutputIntent
            /S/GTS_PDFA1
            /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
            /OutputConditionIdentifier (eciRGB v2)
            /Info(eciRGB v2)
        >> ]
    }

    % ----------------------------------------------
    % Add metadata
    \title{Title}
    \author{First Author, Last Author}
    \hypersetup{%
                 pdfauthortitle={Title of the Author},
                 pdfcopyright={Copyright (C) 20xx, Copyrightholder},
                 pdfsubject={Something},
                 pdfkeywords={Keyword1, Keyword2},
                 pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/},
                 pdfcaptionwriter={Scott Pakin},
                 pdfcontactaddress={Street},
                 pdfcontactcity={City},
                 pdfcontactpostcode={101},
                 pdfcontactcountry={Country},
                 pdfcontactemail={email@institute.edu},
                 pdfcontacturl={http://www.institute.edu},
                 pdflang={en},
                 bookmarksopen=true,
                 bookmarksopenlevel=3,
                 hypertexnames=false,
                 linktocpage=true,
                 plainpages=false,
                 breaklinks
             }

    \begin{document}
    What cat says? \label{meow}
    See question on page \pageref{meow}.
    \end{document}
```

Which is PDF/A-1b compliant:

[image: Result of online pdf-validation tool]

Update: Since the original answer, things have changed several times. For a while `luatex85` had to be loaded but today it would break compilation. But it's also not needed anymore. The packages have to be loaded *before* setting the OutputIntent today.

**This works only with `pdfLaTeX`, `LuaHBTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`.**

Comment: Thanks, now we are close to solution. However, I guess that you mean "compile with latex", not with pdflatex. Also, I still got complains like "The XMP property 'dc:description' is not synchronized with the document information entry 'Subject'."

Comment: Well, LaTeX + dvips won’t work with ghostscript (only Adobe Distiller), so you have to resort to Dvipdfm instead of dvips.

Comment: dvipdfm gives plenty of warnings, but produces .pdf anyway. But result file has no hyperlinks. gs on my system won't work if input and output files are same.

Comment: There is, as far as I can see, no good solution for working hyperlinks with your setup. You should really consider using `pdflatex` instead of plain latex.

Comment: If I start with your example, I get no hyperlinks at all. So, I remove `draft`-option, and get PDF with hyperlinks. And then, when I use `gs`-command to PDF, I got PDF that is almost PDF/A, but not exactly; see for example dc:description -error above.

Comment: LaTeX simply is not the right tool for this job, and you should either switch to `pdflatex` (which is the standard LaTeX-engine in TeXlive) or try to live without hyperlinks.

Comment: Sorry about confusing --- I used `pdflatex` and get PDF, but not exactly PDF/A.

Comment: Updated my answer. Should work now.

Comment: This is hard one... `/ICCProfile` must have absolute path as argument. Also `gs . . . PDFA_def.ps test.pdf` must be `gs . . . /absolute/path/PDFA_def.ps test.pdf`. But then, Evinces shows PDF but complains "Fontconfig warning: ignoring finnish: not a valid language tag". I had `LANG=finnish` on environment, but setting it to `C` didn't help. And also validator says "The value of the key N is 4 but must be 3." etc. In what operating system did you get this working?

Comment: I am on OSX. PDFA_def.ps should reside within the library directory of ghostscript, which varies (look it up in the documentation). The easy way would be to find the file and just change the  `/ICCProfile` entry to `/ICCProfile (eciRGB_v2.icc)` You can also delete all the metadata except for the title.

Comment: I marked this as accepted. At least I can now compile on mac, if I really must have good PDF/A. And I guess I will come back reading this example after TeXlive 2014 will be out.

Comment: What changes do we have to make to get it to output PDF/X-1a complaint PDF ?

Comment: --> http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242314/29873

Comment: Great solution. Better then configuring pdfx packagage including the *.xmp files. Thank you!