# pdfx package writes into pdf file

Tags: pdf-a, pdfx

I want to create a pdf/a-compatible file in LaTeX using the pdfx package. Unfortunately, instead of using the correctly created xmp file to convert the file into pdf/a, some lines of cryptic text are written directly into the pdf file. My minimal example (largely based on http://www.golatex.de/pdfx-bzw-pdf-a-oder-pdf-x-t4427.html) is

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Keywords{pdfTeX\sep PDF/X-1a\sep PDF/A-b}
    \Title{Sample LaTeX input file}
    \Author{Das war KOMA}
    \Org{goLaTeX}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

This produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`, although I have a `\begin{document}` in the file, and the following file:

[image]

Any ideas where the problem lies?

Comment: Your MWE throws no errors and compiles fine, BUT it does not produce a PDF/A-1b compliant pdf file. More on that [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130201/pdf-a-with-hyperref-on-tex-live-2013/136653#136653).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [eciRGB_v2.icc](http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip) in the working directory.

```
\documentclass{article}

% ===============================
% Embedding the color profile.
% Requires eciRGB_v2.icc in the working directory
% http://www.eci.org/_media/downloads/icc_profiles_from_eci/ecirgbv20.zip


\pdfminorversion 4
\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{eciRGB_v2.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
/OutputIntents [ <<
/Type /OutputIntent
/S/GTS_PDFA1
/DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
/OutputConditionIdentifier (eciRGB v2)
/Info(eciRGB v2)
>> ]
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[pdftex, pdfa, linktoc=none]{hyperref}

% ----------------------------------------------
% Add metadata

\hypersetup{%
       pdftitle={Sample LaTeX input file},
       pdfauthor={Das war KOMA},
       pdfsubject={Thema},
       pdfkeywords={pdfTeX, PDF/X-1a, PDF/A-b},
       pdflang={de},
       bookmarksopen=true,
       bookmarksopenlevel=3,
       hypertexnames=false,
       linktocpage=true,
       plainpages=false,
       breaklinks
     }

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

is triggered whenever something ends up in TeX's typesetting lists *before* the real `\begin{document}` command has been encountered. This can happen when bytes end up in the `.xmpdata` file, not contained as arguments of its special macros `\Title`, `\Author`, `\Subject`, etc. This can include invisible characters.

Have you, by any chance, copied a Byte-order marker (BOM) into the `filecontents*` environment, having produced its content in another editor?
Having just become acquainted with this kind of problem, the next version of `pdfx.sty` has coding to prevent any such extraneous bytes making it into TeX's lists.