# Switching to lualatex: How to translate font setups?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, fontspec

I am a long-term `pdflatex` user. Once in a while I want to give `lualatex` a try (e.g., to try the recent TikZ graph layout engine). A couple of good answers here at tex.se describe what to do in that case. For instance, the answer to [How is a TeX document written when using LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243376/how-is-a-tex-document-written-when-using-lualatex) gives the following recipe (itself cited from Manuel Pé­gourié-Gon­nard’s [Guide to LuaLaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf)):

> 1. Don’t load `inputenc`; just encode your source in UTF-8.
> 2. Don’t load `fontenc` or `textcomp`; load `fontspec`.
> 3. `babel` works with LuaLaTeX but you can load `polyglossia` instead.
> 4. Don’t use any package that changes the fonts; use `fontspec` commands instead.

I found all of that easy to follow advice, **with the exception of point 4**. The `fontspec` documentation is quite intimidating and gives no hint how to *translate* existing font setups to `fontspec`. For instance, last time I tried to switch I had the following font setup in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
```

This is just an example, I typically pick my font setups from the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), additionally load `microtype`, and that's it. Most font packages have reasonable setups with respect to all the fine details so the results are good enough for me.

However, with `fontspec`, I have the feeling I have to become a real font expert. In most cases I already failed to figure the font names to use, not speaking about all the other details.

So are there any translation tables for existing font packages?

Is there a technical reason that font packages not support `lualatex` out of the box, so one does not have to deal with intimidating `fontspec` commands?

Comment: You are confusing fontenc and fontspec in various places of your question. There are quite a number of font packages which also setup fonts for lualatex, e.g. libertine and other packages maintained by Bob Tennent. But as there exists so many fonts that you can't expect a package for everyone -- and when you get used to it you will see that calling the fonts with the fontspec commands is not so difficult.

Comment: Many fonts you find in the Font Catalogue are provided for pdflatex only ... `fd`files, `tfm` files etc. With LuaLaTeX, you can use open Type fonts. Some, *some*, font packages deal with the modern engines, check out the code for `libertine.sty`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Old habits... I think I have fixed all `fontenc`s now.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Sure. However, I am also sure that for most of them some OpenType version also exists, so it should be possible to describe a `fontspec` setup as well.

Comment: I don't think it's the task of the `fontspec` manual to "translate" `latex` font commands any more than it would be the task of packages like `fontenc` and `inputenc` to "translate" `fontspec`'s commands. I think more and more people start their `latex` lives directly with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, so it seems a bit anachronistic to me to include `latex` material into the `fontspec` manual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The user guide of the `fontspec` package is indeed quite lengthy. However, I would not go as far as calling it intimidating. There's a huge and wonderful world out there related to OpenType and TrueType fonts, and it's not surprising (to me at least) that the manual that explains how to explore this world isn't brief.

In what follows, I will assume that your tex document is encoded according to the UTF8 standard. Aside: If your document uses only ASCII, it's automatically UTF8-compliant.

I have an educated guess as to why the user guide of the `fontspec` package doesn't explain how one might "translate" directives such as `\usepackage{lmodern}`, `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}`, `\usepackage{charter}`, or `\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}` to LuaLaTeX. The putative reason is quite simple: *For the most part, no translation is necessary*. If you're going to use font packages with LuaLaTeX that were designed originally for use under pdfLaTeX, just keep using them under LuaLaTeX and you'll be fine. (Do see below, though, for same caveats and exceptions.) If you do so, though, don't load the `fontspec` package as well.

For instance, the program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\sffamily
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

produces the same output when run under either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

[image]

Likewise, the program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\sffamily
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

produces the same output when compiled with either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

[image]

The qualifier "for the most part" that was used above needs some explaining. As @UlrikeFischer points outs in a comment, an adjustment to the approach outlined above is necessary if the document contains "accented" characters which aren't included in the basic ASCII character set. (As noted above, I assume that the entire document is UTF-8 encoded.) If the document contains such characters, it is necessary to load the `luainputenc` package with the option `utf8`. With this adjustment made, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} % Not: "\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}"
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
Grüße äöüÄÖÜ, \em Grüße äöüÄÖÜ
\end{document}
```

once again produces identical results when compiled under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

[image]

Excerpting from the user guide of the `luainputenc` package:

> From the user point of view, adapting an old document for LuaTEX is really easy: replacing `inputenc` by `luainputenc` in the preamble is enough. Note that `luainputenc` automatically loads `inputenc` if called with an old engine, so you will still be able to compile your documents with pdfTEX without changing them

That said, as @UlrikeFischer has pointed out in comments to this answer, some issues related to hyphenation may remain if you're using the `luainputenc` package. For instance, words with accented characters (like *Grüße*) may no longer be hyphenated, and LuaLaTeX's output may therefore not be exactly the same as if using `pdflatex`. Hence, in the long run it may nevertheless be a good idea to switch to `fontspec` in order to obtain optimal results.

---

When working with OpenType fonts, there are no packages -- with only a few exceptions (eg., the Libertine font family) -- that allow them to be used under pdf(La)TeX. To use OpenType fonts, one thus has to use either Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX -- typically in conjunction with the `fontspec` package. Since these fonts can't be used under pdfLaTeX anyway, a translation of instructions wouldn't be meaningful, right?

Comment: No he will not be fine if he uses standard pdflatex packages with lualatex. Add `Grüße` to your example and you will see why.

Comment: Actually, I have tried that – but did not get UTF-8 characters to work, as mentioned by Ulrike.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. I've added a paragraph to note that if the input contains "accented" characters that aren't in the ASCII set (but which are UTF8-encoded), the user will have to change the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}`. With this adjustment made, the program should compile identically under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Daniel - what exactly did you try? Is the input utf8-encoded? Which version of LuaLaTeX do you use?

Comment: *"There's a huge and wonderful world related to OpenType and TrueType fonts out there"* Yes, I believe that and I am optimistic that one day I would be able to value it as well. However, my current setup is more like this: I have a lecture series with 500+ `beamer` slides with hand-optimized line breaks. I am totally happy with the current fonts and `pdflatex`, but for some cool package that requires lua I want to try `lualatex`. But, please, with as little change as possible to the fonts.

Comment: This isn't perfect either: The hyphenation patterns don't expect the ß at this position and so "Grüße" will no hyphenate in a german document. Using standard font packages is possible as a workaround but should not be recommended.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Isn't the matter of suboptimal hyphenation of certain words an entirely separate topic? The incorrect (or missing...) hyphenation of "Grüße"  -- when using `babel` with the option `ngerman`, along with `luainputenc` and, say, `lmodern`  -- occurs under both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Do observe that I am *not* advocating anywhere in my answer that one *shouldn't* use `fontspec` when using LuaLaTeX. All my answer says that if one's content with a font package designed for use under pdfLaTeX, one can continue to use it under LuaLaTeX, with the exception of the `luainputenc` matter.

Comment: @Daniel - Which fonts do you use in the pdfLaTeX version of  your `beamer`-based lecture notes?

Comment: With pdflatex Grüße will  hyphenate if you use T1-fencoding, with lualatex not. That's a side effect of the font setup, (O)T1-encoded fonts (or other standard encodings) and the utf8-orientated patterns of lualatex clash. In beamer slides this probably won't matter, but one should know that this side effect exists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Ummm, `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[textwidth=1mm]{geometry} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} \usepackage{lmodern} \begin{document} x Grüße hoffen \end{document}` does *not* hyphenate "Grüße" (but does hyphenate "hoffen") under either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Which font are you using to get a different outcome? (I currently use MacTeX2015 pre, which features version 0.80.0 of LuaTeX and version `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16` of pdfTEX.)

Comment: You are not loading the hypenation patterns. `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Comment: Mico, you are the man, `luainputenc` does indeed the trick! I wasn't aware of the existence of this package before. (Possible minor hyphenation issues are less of a problem in `beamer` slides, where I typically try hard to avoid any kind of hyphenation.)

Comment: @Daniel - I'm glad the switch to `luainputenc` is getting the job done for you. :-)

Comment: Mico, while there are not an issue for my particular use case, the answer would nevertheless profit from mentioning the hyphenation issues Ulrike brought up. Especially the quote from `luainputenc` can be somewhat misleading, as one would expect the same typographical output.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks. I've updated and expanded the text in several locations. Hope this meets your objective.

Comment: @Mico: Almost, I think some more details would be useful. I have edited them in; feel free to reject this edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks! I'm fine with your edits, and applied a few more touch-ups.

Comment: I've never cleaned it up, but I made small sample for LuaLaTeX with fontenc, unicode text and hyphenation: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/aa57f226dc78f841dbde

Comment: @michal.h21 - Thanks for this. Just to be sure I understand what the code in the link does: is it a way of fixing the residual hyphenation issues that Ulrike points out in her comments? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico yes, it fixes the hyphenation and enables the unicode input. it is just a proof of concept, as T1 font encoding is hardwired, it would need some support for other font encodings to be fully usable

Comment: @michal.h21 - This is great! It sure works, for both Czech and German -- at least on words such as "Straße" and "Grüße". (Maybe Ulrike has a longer list of German problem words...) Do you have plans to share this code with the maintainer(s) of the babel package?

Comment: @Mico the problem is how to detect font encoding for a given font - maybe we could polish it in a new question?

Comment: @michal.h21 - Would you like me to post such a question? :-)

Comment: @Mico it would be nice :)

Comment: too late for today (I'm in Singapore...); will post a question tomorrow, if that's OK.

Comment: @michal.h21 - Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Upon studying your code some more, I realize I don't understand what all the issues may be that should be fixed. May I therefore ask you to ask that query about how to auto-detect the font encoding that's in use?

Comment: @Mico OK, I will investigate it and will try to make a question

Comment: @Mico I've created Github project, I had some success, with some issues: https://github.com/michal-h21/luafontenc

Comment: @michal.h21 @Mico Nearly three years later, would you still consider "luafontenc" useful? I would like to have `newtxttt`in my documents and I did not find any replacement for it. So, I'd like to use that package if it is still "OK". - Would you mind polishing it and submit it to CTAN?

Comment: @koppor it would definitely need some polishing, I don't even remember that I wrote it :/ I am quite  busy lately, so I cannot promise anything. but I will look at it

Comment: This worked back then, but today, (with an updated Texlive), the `lmodern` example warns about "Font shape `TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined", the `charter` example warns about "Font shape `TU/bch/m/n' undefined". Should this be seen as bugs in some component, or is this answer no longer valid?

Answer (score 6):

The CMBright fonts are available in OpenType format as part of the `cm-unicode` project.

Granted that your file is UTF-8 encoded, you should get comparable results by doing

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{XCharter}
  \setsansfont{CMU Bright}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase
  ]
  \setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}[ % or other monospaced font
    Scale=MatchUppercase
  ]
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{charter}
  \usepackage{cmbright}
  \usepackage{beramono}
\fi

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

\kant[1]

\texttt{Some text in monospaced font}

\section{Font list}

\begin{itemize}
\item Roman font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}

\item {\sffamily Sans font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}

\item {\ttfamily TT font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

There's no OpenType free version of the BeraMono fonts, as far as I know.

### Output with `pdflatex`

[image]

### Output with `pdflatex` after adding `\usepackage{microtype}`

[image]

### Output with `lualatex`

[image]